# Shortest infinite loop producing no output

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to create the shortest infinite loop!

The point of this challenge is to create an infinite loop producing no output, unlike its possible duplicate. The reason to this is because the code might be shorter if no output is given.

### Rules

- Each submission must be a full program.
- You must create the shortest infinite loop.
- Even if your program runs out of memory eventually, it is still accepted as long as it is running the whole time from the start to when it runs out of memory. Also when it runs out of memory, it should still not print anything to STDERR.
- The program must take no input (however, reading from a file is allowed), and should not print anything to STDOUT. Output to a file is also forbidden.
- The program must not write anything to STDERR.
- Feel free to use a language (or language version) even if it's newer than this challenge.
  -Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed (and even encouraged) to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language. **:D**
- Submissions are scored in bytes, in an appropriate (pre-existing) encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8. Some languages, like Folders, are a bit tricky to score - if in doubt, please ask on Meta.
- This is not about finding the language with the shortest infinite loop program. This is about finding the shortest infinite loop program in every language. Therefore, I will not accept an answer.
- If your language of choice is a trivial variant of another (potentially more popular) language which already has an answer (think BASIC or SQL dialects, Unix shells or trivial Brainf**k-derivatives like Alphuck), consider adding a note to the existing answer that the same or a very similar solution is also the shortest in the other language.
- There should be a website such as Wikipedia, Esolangs, or GitHub for the language. For example, if the language is CJam, then one could link to the site in the header like `#[CJam](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), X bytes`.
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.

(I have taken some of these rules from Martin Büttner's "Hello World" challenge)

Please feel free to post in the comments to tell me how this challenge could be  improved.

### Catalogue

This is a Stack Snippet which generates both an alphabetical catalogue of the used languages, and an overall leaderboard. To make sure your answer shows up, please start it with this Markdown header:

```
# Language name, X bytes
```

Obviously replacing `Language name` and `X bytes` with the proper items. If you want to link to the languages' website, use this template, as posted above:

```
#[Language name](http://link.to/the/language), X bytes
```

Now, finally, here's the snippet: (Try pressing "Full page" for a better view.)

```js
var QUESTION_ID=59347;var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";var COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";var OVERRIDE_USER=41805;var answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=true,comment_page;function answersUrl(index){return"//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+index+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(index,answers){return"//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+answers.join(';')+"/comments?page="+index+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(data){answers.push.apply(answers,data.items);answers_hash=[];answer_ids=[];data.items.forEach(function(a){a.comments=[];var id=+a.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(id);answers_hash[id]=a});if(!data.has_more)more_answers=false;comment_page=1;getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(data){data.items.forEach(function(c){if(c.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER)answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c)});if(data.has_more)getComments();else if(more_answers)getAnswers();else process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;var OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(a){return a.owner.display_name}function process(){var valid=[];answers.forEach(function(a){var body=a.body;a.comments.forEach(function(c){if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))body='<h1>'+c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,'')+'</h1>'});var match=body.match(SCORE_REG);if(match)valid.push({user:getAuthorName(a),size:+match[2],language:match[1],link:a.share_link,});else console.log(body)});valid.sort(function(a,b){var aB=a.size,bB=b.size;return aB-bB});var languages={};var place=1;var lastSize=null;var lastPlace=1;valid.forEach(function(a){if(a.size!=lastSize)lastPlace=place;lastSize=a.size;++place;var answer=jQuery("#answer-template").html();answer=answer.replace("{{PLACE}}",lastPlace+".").replace("{{NAME}}",a.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",a.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",a.size).replace("{{LINK}}",a.link);answer=jQuery(answer);jQuery("#answers").append(answer);var lang=a.language;lang=jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();languages[lang]=languages[lang]||{lang:a.language,lang_raw:lang,user:a.user,size:a.size,link:a.link}});var langs=[];for(var lang in languages)if(languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))langs.push(languages[lang]);langs.sort(function(a,b){if(a.lang_raw.toLowerCase()>b.lang_raw.toLowerCase())return 1;if(a.lang_raw.toLowerCase()<b.lang_raw.toLowerCase())return-1;return 0});for(var i=0;i<langs.length;++i){var language=jQuery("#language-template").html();var lang=langs[i];language=language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",lang.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",lang.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",lang.size).replace("{{LINK}}",lang.link);language=jQuery(language);jQuery("#languages").append(language)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;width:500px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;padding-right:40px;width:500px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I've got to start posting programs with a negative byte count to beat all these empty files!

Comment: This challenge is interesting because it brings out lots of 0 byte languages (some of which are NOT esolangs). FWIW, most declarative languages have an implicit infinite loop because declarative languages don't have loops in their syntax (they assume they're running in an infinite loop). Ladder diagrams are perhaps among the oldest such languages. Then you have the Instruction Language (IL), a sort of assembly for PLCs that also assume an infinite loop. ILs, like assembly are different between manufacturers

Comment: Are programs that read and execute their own source code allowed, or does file I/O break the "must take no input" rule?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, file input is allowed.

Comment: Can you print `""`, an empty string?

Comment: Most C compilers create a temporary file to avoid torturing the memory when resolving preprocessor directives. Does it make [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80920/53917) non-competing because it throws the compiler itself in an infinite loop using a recursive #inclusion?

Comment: Btw, here's a general note: Open the links on the leaderboard on a new tab/window.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 No, you can't

Comment: @KritixiLithos Do you mean, no trailing newline, right? Because just printing an empty string without a trailing newline is no output at all.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer As weird as it sounds, not even an empty string `""` should be outputted.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I mean, without the quotes and trailing newlines. Of course `"` can't be in the output.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer I also mean without the quotes and without trailing newlines.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Oh... gosh. So, let's say that you can't use `print(end='')` in Python 3, for example. I think this is really weird, but I'll adhere to the rule.

Comment: @CJDennis Use a language with half a character.

Answer (score 230):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 0 bytes

Yup. A Befunge program exists in a two-dimensional *playfield* with fixed size which wraps around the edges. With nothing in that space to interfere, the *program counter* runs in an infinite loop by default :)

Comment: Aw, I was gonna post this. :/

Comment: @daniero It may have some relation to [this standard loophole...](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5337/9498). I personally don't agree with the standard loophole.

Comment: @Justin That loophole only applies to certain types of challenges.

Comment: You can use `<pre>&nbsp;</pre>` for an empty-looking code block.

Comment: First thing I looked for

Answer (score 164):

## [L00P](http://esolangs.org/wiki/L00P), 0 bytes

This lang was made for looping, and that's just what it'll do...

Comment: LOL. +1 for choice of language.

Comment: ... one of these days this lang is gonna loop all over you

Comment: +1 for the musical reference, and congrats on another gold badge!

Comment: The best reference I have seen

Answer (score 146):

## [C64 Machine Code](http://www.commodore.ca/manuals/c64_programmers_reference/c64-programmers_reference_guide-05-basic_to_machine_language.pdf), 2 Bytes

```
D0 FE
```

Branches to itself if the zero flag is not set.

Branches are single-byte offsets from the next instruction location, and 254 is -2 in two's complement... the BNE instruction (D0)  takes one byte of memory, and the offset takes a second byte, so branching two bytes back branches back to itself.  The zero flag is always cleared when code is loaded into memory.

Note that this is not a recursive subroutine call, so you will never run out of memory.  Also note that there is no header, compiler, or executable overhead... it is truly a two-byte program :)

Comment: Or EB FE for the unconditional jump

Comment: Shouldn't this work on any machine with a 6502 / 6510 family processor, not just a C64? Also, what you've written is machine code. The assembly would be `BNE -2`

Comment: +1 for making an actual program that is small, instead of trying to find the most obscure language that just so happens to have the least characters to represent the structure.

Comment: @user45891 EB FE is x86. 6502/6510 doesn't have an unconditional short jump instruction.

Comment: Ya, what Random832 said... I had thought there might be an unconditional branch, but when I checked my (old, old, cracked-plastic-binder) reference manual, there was not.  EB was "reserved for future expansion", though, so maybe that was added in to a later version of the chip.

Comment: Steveverrill, touché, it is machine code, indeed.  And yes, I thought more people would recognize the Commodore 64 than the 65xx family in general :)  The VIC-20 used the 6502 and would have been able to run this.  So, technically, would my 1541 floppy drive... I vaguely recall being able to reprogram the controller on that.  Ah, I still miss my C64 :)

Comment: It wasn't showing up, thought maybe I misunderstood what I was supposed to do with that snippet :)  Already removed, and I'm showing up now... though the format of the results is terrible in both fx and ie

Comment: It takes a minute after it's submitted to show up/update. I've changed the formatting slightly; hopefully it's better now. Also, if you want to have an actual strikethrough through the word "Assembly", you can just use `<s>Assembly</s>`.

Comment: @Random832: Actually some of the later 6502 descendants did have an unconditional branch instruction (BRA, 0x80) - see for example [this page](http://6502.org/tutorials/65c02opcodes.html) (search for "BRA").

Comment: @steveverrill This is machine code for any 6502 machine that guarantees carry is clear at program start. The C64 OS specifies this, but machines that leave this unspecified need an additional CLC opcode ($18) at start for a 1-byte penalty.

Comment: Back in the day, a particularly nasty "trick" (imho vandalism) that customers would play on unsuspecting computer store owners was to place two bytes akin to this but for the X86, at the beginning of the bootloader, using DOS' `debug`. This would effectively brick the machine, and most shop staff lacked the nous to know it wasn't just a dead drive.

Answer (score 122):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 3 bytes

```
+[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fOzr2/38A)

Never decrement: never end.

Comment: It's funny when BF beats most other answers.

Comment: I had to think of this when I saw the question on SE's start page.

Comment: My first thought was BF! :D It ended shorter than I thought.

Comment: Alternative, still same bytes: `-[]`

Comment: I bet there's an interpreter somewhere where `]` would work

Comment: @12Me21 The most recent one I wrote, I just realized.

Answer (score 116):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 3 bytes

```
///
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19f//9/AA)

Any bonus points for using the language's name as source code?

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that the link actually works, seeing as how it ends with `///` ;)

Comment: @ETHproductions That is rather surprising, but if one thinks about it a bit more, it makes some sense; it's just the URL `esolangs.org` `wiki` `_` `_` `_` `_`

Comment: @AlexL. Not entirely. The web server sees a GET request to `/wiki////`. While that *intended* to be a path, the server can do with that information whatever it wants.

Answer (score 81):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 53 bytes

```java
class A{public static void main(String[]a){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z85J7G4WMGxuqA0KSczWaG4JLEESJXlZ6Yo5CZm5mkElxRl5qVHxyZqVqflF2lYW2ta19b@/w8A)

Yay full program requirement!

Comment: God is that verbose...

Comment: Aah, I when I received a notification saying that someone posted a Java answer, I guessed the person to be you!

Comment: @minxomat Yep, 45 bytes for an empty `main` :(

Comment: @minxomat gotta love that OOP

Comment: There was a time you could abuse an enum for that - the complaint about the missing main method would occur only *after* instantiation - but Java 8 checks this now beforehand. That's very sad for code golf.

Comment: @Landei Java 7 won't let you either; I think 6 was the last. Either way, I believe that prints to stderr when run, so it wouldn't be valid here.

Comment: @Geobits: It would write the error after the loop - so in our case never...

Comment: That ain't OO. Putting code in a class doesn't make it OO any more than putting a rock in the microwave makes it food.

Comment: @imallett [Who says rocks aren't food?](http://theneverendingstory.wikia.com/wiki/Rock_Biter/Pyornkrachzark)

Comment: @Geobits that guy died tragically, remember?

Comment: Why not using a static block? Works normally...

Comment: Replace `class` with `interface` and drop the `public`. Also, call `main` recursively instead of making a loop.

Comment: @Phoenix `main(a);` == `for(;;);`

Comment: Wouldn't calling it recursively overflow itself and write to STDERR anyway? I assumed this was not allowed. I haven't tried, so maybe it optimizes it away, but if it's no shorter I won't bother.

Comment: @mınxomaτ: Complaining Java is verbose for code-golding is like complaining Jelly is useless for business applications...

Answer (score 60):

## Prolog, 5 bytes

```
a:-a.
```

In order to know if predicate `a` is true, you only need to check if predicate `a` is true.

<sub>You need to load the file and execute `a`, both with a command-line arguments, eg. `swipl -g a a.pl` with Swi-Prolog. Note that the recursion is likely to be optimized as an infinite loop and shouldn't blow the stack.</sub>

Also, this looks like a smiley, but I am not sure how to call it. The dot looks like saliva, so maybe "vegetative state", or "Infiurated programmer with curly hair". Suggestions are welcome.

---

Edit: I look at the rules again and for a full program and no command line arguments you need to add this, as user @radrow pointed out, for a total of **10 bytes**.

```
a:-a.
:-a.
```

Alternatively, for **14** bytes you can have something more poetic:

```
:-repeat,fail.
```

Comment: Check if `a` is true by checking if `a` is true by checking if `a` is true by checking...yay recursion!

Comment: You miss :-a. in your file, it won't magically execute itself

Comment: @radrow with swi-prolog for example you start the program with `swipl -g a a.pl`

Comment: Oh, didn't know that

Comment: @radrow I still edited the answer because using command line arguments might be not alright with the rule, I am not sure, thank you

Comment: Is the newline important though?

Comment: @radrow I tested to be sure, it's either a newline or a space

Answer (score 52):

### Python, 9 bytes

Works in both 2 and 3.

```py
while 1:0
```

Shortened by @FryAmTheEggman

Comment: note, this does produce output when ran in the Python interpreter

Comment: @Chris_Rands Only in the REPL.

Answer (score 52):

## [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29), 9 bytes

Infinite recursion of the main function. Should get compiled to a loop due to tail recursion optimization.

```
main=main
```

Comment: It compiles, but if run the runtime system detects the loop and throws the `<<loop>>` exception - at least with `ghc`. Maybe some other compiler behaves differently.

Comment: Doing `runhaskell Loop.hs` happily executed it for several minutes on my machine. So, it's at least runnable by an interpreter. I think the `<<loop>>` runtime exception that `ghc` throws is purely an implementation detail of the runtime and not part of the Haskell language as specified in any of the Haskell Reports.

Comment: It's an edge case. `runhaskell` happily accepts the code but it doesn't loop. It does nothing. However, the challange only requires to create the loop, not to execute it, so I guess it's fine. Have a +1.

Comment: @GrantS: the Haskell language has no such notion as a “loop”; definitions like `main = main` are semantically in the same bucket as `undefined` or `error "<<loop>>"`: bottom values ⟂.

Comment: I think the shortest working haskell loop would be: `main=main>>main`

Comment: @nimi, what do you mean by "it doesn't loop"? It'll run forever with no output.

Comment: @dfeuer: if you start the program with `runhaskell`, yes, it does not terminate but it also uses no cpu time, so it does nothing. Running through a (empty) loop would require at least some cpu activity.

Comment: @nimi, ah, I see what you mean. I wonder what Hugs does with it.

Answer (score 48):

## x86 ELF executable, 45 bytes

Unlike the vast majority of these answers, this is a truly complete program, as in a free-standing executable program.

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 0300 2000 0100 2000 0100 0400 0000  .... ... .......
00000020: ebfe 31c0 40cd 8000 3400 2000 01         ..1.@...4. ..
```

The guts of the program are at byte 0x20 `ebfe`, which is featured in another answer as the smallest NASM program.  If you assemble that with NASM however, you get an executable with thousands of un-needed bytes.  We can get rid of most of them using the technique outlined [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).  You may note that this program isn't even as big as the ELF header!  This bit of executable golfing malforms the ELF header and program header so they can occupy the same bytes in the file and inserts our program into some unused bytes within the header.  Linux will still happily read the header and start execution at offset `0x20` where it spins forever.

Comment: [`.com`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) on DOS would be much shorter :)

Comment: You only get "thousands" of bytes if you let gcc include the startup files.  `yasm && ld` makes executables only about 1k.

Answer (score 42):

## INTERCAL, <s>42</s> 18 bytes

```
(1)DO COME FROM(1)
```

Idea taken from @flawr's comment.

**EDIT:** Holy crap, INTERCAL is actually shorter than C#. I don't know if that's ever happened before...

### 42-byte version

```
DO(1)NEXT
(1)DO FORGET #1
PLEASE DO(1)NEXT
```

Comment: How dare you do a intercal program without `comefrom`

Comment: @flawr Fixed. ;)

Comment: Np, I think we need more Intercal in golfing contests here=)

Comment: Did you say `PLEASE`?

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/1/DUNPF39nf19UtyN9X2fD/fwA "INTERCAL – Try It Online"). Also works for CLC-INTERCAL.

Answer (score 37):

## [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), 6 bytes

```
perl -e '{redo}'
```

From [`perldoc -f redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html):

> The redo command restarts the loop block without evaluating the conditional again...Note that a block by itself is semantically identical to a loop that executes once. Thus redo inside such a block will effectively turn it into a looping construct.

I don't see `redo` too often in production code, but it's great for golf! Compare the above to the shortest equivalents with `for`, `while`, and `goto`:

```
for(;;){} # 9 bytes
1while 1  # 8 bytes
X:goto X  # 8 bytes
```

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59553/30206 suggests the 4-byte `do$0`, which doesn't work as a `perl -e` one-liner.

Comment: @PeterCordes Neat, although I think that breaks the "must take no input" rule. [`do EXPR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) reads from a file.

Comment: @PeterCordes [The OP has ruled that file I/O is acceptable.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output?noredirect=1#comment143907_59347) All hail the [king of infinite loops in Perl!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59553/31388)

Comment: `perl -pe 'redo'` for 4 bytes.

Answer (score 36):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 1 byte

A single space will cause ><> to go into an infinite loop of NOPs

Other valid single character programs (with no memory requirements) are as follows:

```
>^v</\|_#x!"'{}r
```

In addition, the rules state that your program can run out of memory in which case we can add the following characters to the list of valid 1-byte programs:

```
01234567890abcdefli
```

Comment: Try `\` \`` for the code block.

Comment: Why not just use `>`?

Comment: If this were Chem.SE, I would recommend putting the code in MathJax, too.

Comment: Are we sure an empty program wouldn't be an infinite loop?

Comment: @AaronGOUZIT It's not empty if it has an instruction

Comment: @corsiKa sorry I wasn't very clear, I was suggesting that the empty program might be a valid loop in ><>

Comment: Get a runtime error trying to execute the empty program:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fish.py", line 493, in <module>
    instr = interpreter.move()
  File "fish.py", line 149, in move
    if self._position[1] > max(self._codebox.keys()):
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: Characters that would also work: `>^v</\|_#x!`

Answer (score 36):

## [Motorola MC14500B Machine Code](https://www.brouhaha.com/~eric/retrocomputing/motorola/mc14500b/), <s>0.5</s> 0 bytes

#### Explanation

According to the manual, the system is configured to have a looping control structure. The program counter counts up to its highest value, wraps back around to zero, and counts up again.

Comment: I believe you have found the ultimate golfing language, at least for small tasks...not even Pyth can get this short. +1

Comment: Be warned that this shows up as 5 bytes on the scoreboard.

Comment: C is Jump, but where to jump?

Comment: Wow, you really like this language, huh? :P

Comment: This will work in any machine language where 0 is a NOP, the instruction pointer wraps around, and the program memory doesn't hold any extra data.

Answer (score 35):

## [LOLCODE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/LOLCODE), 24 bytes

```
IM IN YR X
IM OUTTA YR X
```

Comment: In many LOLCODE interpreters, such as the one on repl.it, `HAI` and `KTHXBYE` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 34):

## C, 15 bytes

```
main(){main();}
```

Yes, it's possible to call `main()` recursively.  If you've got a compiler that does tail-call optimization (say, gcc with the `-O2` option), it doesn't even segfault: the compiler is smart enough to turn the function call into a `goto`.

Comment: Unless you can give me a compiler that does this by default, you would have to add 3 bytes for the `-O2` option.

Comment: @LegionMammal978, according to the rules in the challenge, running out of memory is acceptable.  That makes the `-O2` optimization a "nice-to-have" rather than a requirement.

Comment: If options to the compiler is allowed (and is not counted for the solution count), so why not change the code to `l(){l();}` and compile it with the options `-Dl=main -O2`

Comment: For comparison, the shortest non-recursive proper loop implementation is 16B: `main(){for(;;);}`.

Comment: @wendelbsilva you may nail it even more by changing the code to X (just one byte) and compiling with -DX=main(){main();}

Comment: Could you use compiler opts to rename main() to be something shorter? Further to Peter's comment, you could also use `main(){while(1);}`

Comment: @Mark However, it still prints the segfault message at the end.

Comment: Gives a segfault even with `-O2`. Using GCC 5.2.1

Answer (score 31):

## [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), 7 keystrokes

Open the editor, preferably without any loaded scripts, for instance like like this from the command line: `vim -u NONE`

```
qq@qq@q
```

## Vimscript, <del>15</del> 8 bytes

Add it in a script, or run it directly by punching the colon (`:`) key first while you're in normal mode

```
wh1|endw
```

Comment: Your vimscript is a little long `wh1|endw`

Comment: Could you explain how this works to someone who's not familiar with Vim?

Comment: @iFreilicht `qq` starts recording into the `q` buffer. `@q` replays what's in the `q` buffer (at this point, nothing). `q` stops recording, and then `@q` replays whats in the `q` buffer, which at this point is the keystrokes `@q`. So `@q` replays `@q` replays `@q`.... also, writing this many `q`'s makes my brain hurt.

Answer (score 26):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 1 byte

```
"
```

A labrinth program executes the same instruction over and over again if there are no neighbors. They also won't end until they execute the `@` instruction.

Answer (score 26):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 3 bytes

```
+`0
```

If given a single file, Retina uses a Count stage, replacing the input with the number of matches found for the given regex. Here, the regex is `0`. Now `+` loops the stage for as long as the result changes from the previous iteration. So what exactly is happening?

- `0` is matched against the empty input, giving zero matches, so the result is `0`. This is different from the input, so we run this again.
- `0` is matched against the previous output `0`, which now gives one match... so the result is `1`.
- `0` is matched against the previous output `1`, which fails... so the result is `0`.
- ... you get the idea.

The result of the loop iteration alternates between `0` and `1`, which a) ensures that the loop never terminates and b) ensures that we're not running out of memory because the string doesn't grow.

By default, Retina only outputs once the program terminates, so this doesn't print anything (you can change this behaviour by adding a `>` after the `+`, [which will then print the alternating zeroes and ones](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X9suweD/fwA)).

As of 1.0, Retina actually also has more traditional while-loops, which you could use with a simpler stage (which doesn't change the string all the time), but they actually require more bytes. One option would be:

```
//+`
```

Comment: Wow, I just answered [almost the exact thing in rs at the exact same time](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59388/21009).

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos They look very similar, but they actually work quite differently. :)

Comment: Nice job. I was going to try doing the shortest Retina program in Replace mode. I'm curious, can `+\`` match empty input repeatedly?

Comment: @mbomb007 I think that would terminate with a `2` after a few iterations.

Answer (score 26):

## [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) (QBasic 4.5), <s>10</s> <s>5</s> 3 bytes

*In the BASIC programming language, RUN is used to start program execution from direct mode, or to start a overlay program from a loader program.* - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command)

Edit: This works without a line number in QBasic 4.5, according to @steenbergh

```
RUN
```

Here's the first version I posted. Infinite GOTO loop. Also, it's 10 bytes, which is a nice coincidence!

```
10 GOTO 10
```

Comment: Why line number 10?  Why not 9?

Comment: or 8 for 8 bytes?:)

Comment: It's not going to win and it's funnier this way.

Comment: This could be shorted to: 1 RUN

Comment: @mbomb007 I would like it to be changed, it is code-golf, not code-funny, :)

Comment: Gagh. Beat me to it. ++

Comment: In C64's basic, you could write this as 1rU (3 bytes)

Comment: Using Sinclair basic this would use less bytes as the commands RUN and GO TO are both 1 byte  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinclair_BASIC

Comment: @davidjwest I think the different dialects of BASIC are often different enough to be separate. There are too many. Like how TI-BASIC is usually separate.

Comment: @davidjwest Shortest I can do in Sinclair BASIC is: `1 GOTO SIGNUM PI` - since constant ints are stored in memory twice, as shorts, so 1 would be 4 bytes, but SIGNUM and PI both use only one byte each. Ah, the old coding tricks we used to use :D Not sure how much memory line numbers take up, if any, so all I can say is it's 3+(line number storage) bytes.

Comment: In QBasic 4.5, just using `RUN` (without the line numbers) works just as well, so 3 bytes?

Comment: @DewiMorgan `1 RUN` also works in Sinclair BASIC for 6 bytes (2 bytes line number + 2 bytes line length + 1 byte for `RUN` token + 1 byte for newline).

Comment: @Neil RUN! Hah - nice. :D

Answer (score 25):

## TIS Node Type T21 Architecture, 6 bytes

[image: A single node with NOP written in it]

Tessellated Intelligence System nodes are classified as "processing" or "storage" nodes. Storage nodes simply store and retrieve information, and are irrelevant in this case. Remaining are the processing nodes. Node Type T21, or Basic Execution Node, is the most common and simple (as the name would suggest).

Technically, each node can be thought of as an independent computer. In the case of the T21, it is a computer that has two storage registers (one addressable, one not) and an instruction set of 15 commands. It has enough memory to be programmed with up to 15 instructions. All TIS nodes have four ports connecting them to the topologically adjacent nodes. Reading from a port causes that node to hang until the node on the other end writes to it, and writing to a port hangs until that node reads it.

You might be able to tell by now that TIS nodes were never meant to do much on their own. Together, though, they can be quite powerful... well, for their time. Because of these limitations, it's very rare to see someone use only a single node. In fact, a program that takes input and provides output based on it *must* use at least three nodes, as TIS systems feed input into the `UP` port of a node on the top row and take output from the `DOWN` port of a node on the bottom row. There are three rows, so data must pass through at least three nodes to get to the bottom.

Because of these limitations, TIS nodes are intended to *generally* be used somewhat like this:

1. Get input
2. Do something to it
3. Pass it on
4. Return to step 1

Because of this, the limited space for instructions and the fact that nodes simply wait quietly and don't cause trouble when trying to read input that isn't there, a decision was made in their design that makes them very good for this challenge. I'll quote from the TIS-100's reference manual:

> After executing the last instruction of the program, execution automatically continues to the first instruction.

Perfect! Infinite loops are default for TIS nodes.

I very nearly answered this question with a 0 byte answer, claiming that an empty node was an infinite loop. However, I researched further. First, the quote above states that the loop occurs *after executing the last instruction*. Additionally, I tested the implementation. Each node reports a "mode" at all times. It isn't accessible programmatically but it's intended to make debugging easier. Here are the possible modes:

```
 RUN‌ - I am executing an instruction.
READ - I am reading from a port, waiting for it to be written to.
WRTE - I am writing to a port, waiting for it to be read from.
IDLE - I am doing nothing.
```

It turns out that, since each node is an individual computer, they are capable of determining whether or not they have instructions to execute. If not, they remain in the `IDLE` state (likely to save power). As such, I couldn't in good conscience claim that it was "looping"; rather, each node sat quietly, assuming the others were doing something important.

This program that I've submitted is truly an infinite loop, as executing it sets the state of the node to `RUN`. It is as simple as you would expect, `NOP` performs `N`o `OP`eration. Once it's done doing nothing, execution returns to the top of the code: `NOP`.

If you find it unsatisfying that I'm abusing the T21 architecture to create a loop, I offer an alternate solution at the cost of 2 bytes: `JRO 0`. `JRO` means `J`ump `R`elative unc`O`nditionally. Or something, I guess. There's no agreed-upon expanded form of the instructions. Anyway, `JRO` takes a numeric argument and jumps execution by that amount relative to the current position. For example, `JRO 2` skips the instruction that follows it (useful if that instruction is jumped to from somewhere else). `JRO 1` jumps forward one instruction, making it a `NOP`. `JRO -1` jumps back one instruction, effectively performing the previous instruction once every two cycles until the program is halted. And, of course, `JRO 0` jumps to itself, executing itself forever.

At this point you may be thinking:

> Sure, monorail, this all makes sense, but your answer is simply `NOP`. Why is its score 6 bytes?

Good question, thanks for asking. One may naively think that TIS programs should be counted the same way we count programs in multiple files: the number of bytes in all nodes, plus 1 byte for each additional node after the first. However, the TIS golfing community decided this would be unfair for the simple reason that it ignores some of the information required to recreate solutions. A node's neighbours are very important, and that scoring method gives you positional information for free. Instead, we've adopted the format used by the most common TIS emulator, the confusingly-named [TIS-100](http://store.steampowered.com/app/370360/). (Side note: Please don't name emulators after the system they emulate. It's not clever, it's just annoying and makes everyone have to constantly clarify what they're talking about.) It's very simple: The 12 nodes of a TIS-100 device are numbered, left to right and top to bottom, skipping any storage nodes the emulated system has installed. A node numbered `N` containing `# CODE\n# CODE\n CODE` is saved like so:

```
@N
# CODE
# CODE
# CODE
```

And so, a node numbered 0 containing `NOP` is scored according to its representation in this format:

```
@0
NOP
```

Six bytes.

As I often include in my answers in visually-interesting languages, you can [watch the TIS-100 emulator execute this program on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKceAYqt5Vg). Though, considering what this challenge is, I don't know what you expect to see...

Comment: Wow-ee. That was amazing.

Comment: I always assumed `JRO` stood for **J**ump to **R**elative **O**ffset.

Comment: @BHustus i think you're right but i wrote this before i had experience with any other assembly language and i didn't know the lingo

Comment: I wish I could +10 this answer. I love TIS-100

Comment: I wrote a TIS emulator of my own, so you can now [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K8ks/v/fwYDLzz/g/38A). Don't expect much other than a timeout, though.

Comment: Are you *sure* the emulator included in the game [*TIS-100*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/370360/) is called *TIS-100*? I didn't realize it had a name...

Comment: Hmm, so I guess the reason you need to write code is that if you don't, *all* of the nodes will just be `IDLE` forever?

Comment: Hmm, I see you leave out a lot of stuff that the game's emulator would include, such as entries for empty nodes (including the blank lines between nodes AND at least a blank of code for each node) and the newline at the end of the last line of code, **but** the game's emulator is perfectly happy to load such a file, so: good thinking!

Answer (score 24):

## Perl, 4 bytes

```
do$0
```

[Executes itself](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) repeatedly.

Comment: Very cool. At first I thought this violated the "must take no input" rule since `do EXPR` reads from a file, which would technically be input, but the OP clarified that file I/O is acceptable. The really cool thing is that unlike the equivalent in Bash, say, this doesn't fork any new processes, so it will continue indefinitely without hitting any memory or process limits.

Answer (score 23):

## [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)), <strike>38</strike> <strike>37</strike> 36 bytes

```c#
class B{static int Main(){for(;;);}}
```

For loop with no stopping condition.

The return of main should be an int, but since it'll never reach the end this should compile.  (Tested in VS 2015 and 2013, also works in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/HUWzB4)).  Thanks [Geobits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14215/geobits) and [MichaelS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45728/michaels).

A shorter version, **35** bytes, can be achieved, but prints `Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException` which I believe violates the third point of not printing anything to stderr. Credit to [MichaelB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/23300/michael-b)

```
class B{static int Main()=>Main();}
```

Comment: Can you save one by using `;` instead of `{}`? I'd test, but online services don't like infinite loops much.

Comment: @Geobits Ah, yes.  How such simple things slip by.

Comment: It may depend on compiler, but I saved another character by declaring it as int main and it ran without a return statement. I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2013 Community Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4.  "class A{static int Main(){for(;;);}}"

Comment: @MichaelS Thanks! Worked in 2015 VS for me.

Comment: In vs 15, this might be shorter (barely). 35
`class B{static int Main()=>Main();}`

Comment: @MichaelB That would be infinite (given infinite memory), but does it violate the third point since something is printed? I am testing using visual studio 2015 as a console application.

Comment: Try compiling in X64. It should do tail optimization and hopefully eliminate that inf loop?

Answer (score 22):

## Foo, 3 bytes

```
(1)
```

Everyone's favorite programming language! :D

Answer (score 21):

## [Hexagony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony), 1 byte

```
.
```

I don't know much about this awesome language created by @MartinBüttner, but from what I've seen, this should loop infinitely, as there is no `@` to halt the program. `.` is simply a no-op.

Comment: Why don't you test it, :D

Comment: I can confirm that this is correct. :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Because I couldn't find an online interpreter, and I don't prefer to download the interpreter for every language I ever want to test. ;)

Comment: @ETHproductions [You don't? Huh.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XIchk.png)

Comment: @Martin Ender: ls as an alias for dir? OMG.

Comment: @MegaMan I believe that works out of the box in PowerShell.

Comment: @MartinEnder: Hm. I don't use it, I don't like MS

Comment: TIO shows that [an empty program works](https://tio.run/#hexagony).

Answer (score 20):

## bash + BSD coreutils, <s>23 22 14 6 5</s> 6 bytes

```
yes>&-
```

`yes` outputs "y" forever; `>&-` closes STDOUT.

Thanks @Dennis and @ThisSuitIsBlackNot for help getting the size down!

Comment: With bash you can just do `$0` in a shellscript and run it, it will invoke itself forever.

Comment: This keeps creating more processes until the system runs out of memory though, no? - it's not really an infinite loop.

Comment: Creative, but boring old `while :;do :;done` is only 17 bytes.

Comment: @Ben so get a computer with infinite memory. ;) We're already assuming computers with eternal power supplies, hardware which is infinitely reliable, and an environment which can dissipate infinite heat; it seems a bit silly to draw a line at infinite memory and say *that's* a step too far.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot good point! But I was determined to find a sillier answer, and I did.

Comment: `ping>&- 0` works on Linux, where `0` is mapped to localhost.

Comment: `yes`! (I thought about using `yes` but it didn't occur to me to discard the output.) You can save one byte with `yes>/dev/null`

Comment: Of course, since the rules only say you can't write to stdout or stderr, `yes>-` would also work :)

Comment: `yes>&-` will exit immediately, complaining about a bad file descriptor

Comment: @Dennis `yes>&-` works for me with BSD yes but not GNU yes, but I'll change it to `yes>-` since that's shorter anyway.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot what does >- do exactly? Google isn't being very helpful.

Comment: `yes>-` is just a slightly-obfuscated version of `yes>a`. It writes to a file called `-`. From my reading of the rules, this is acceptable, although Dennis has since commented on the question asking for clarification, and it does seem like kind of a loophole.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. If it works with BSD yes, great, but I don't think writing to a file complies with *producing no output*.

Comment: Is the title considered part of the rules? The body of the challenge only specifies not outputting to stdout or stderr. Though on second thought, this program will stop when the disk fills up, so...

Comment: I just checked, and it turns out ping isn't part of coreutils. What a drag.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:  shorter: define and call a recursive function: `f(){ f;};f`.  Or even shorter than that, but each recursive call creates a subprocess: `f()(f);f`.   (i.e. something like a forkbomb, but my computer did manage to process my ^c and stop it, while the OOM killer was killing firefox, or after.  I do have some swap space).  See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41201/30206 for more about () function defs on the bash-golfing FAQ.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can't test right now, but won't those segfault eventually, printing something to stderr?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: oh, yeah good point.  I guess a recursive C program can get away with it, because it's not the C program itself that prints the error message.  IDK if bash would catch its own segfault and print an error message, or simply exit and leave it to a parent process to get the exit status.  `{}` version isn't tail-call optimized in bash4.3; memory usage does keep growing.

Comment: I put in a suggested-edit for `yes|wc`, which is also 6 chars, but portable to any `yes` implementation.

Comment: `\`yes\`` for 5 bytes

Answer (score 18):

### Pyth, 2 bytes

```
#
```

Pyth expects tokens after the forever operator. (That's a space.)

Answer (score 18):

## [Gammaplex](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gammaplex), 0 bytes

In Gammaplex, it isn't possible to write a program that isn't an infinite loop. So I just write a program that doesn't use input/output.

Comment: Well the rules state that there needs to be an infinite loop to qualify.

Comment: @arodebaugh There is. In other words, there is an infinite loop in every Gammaplex program.

Answer (score 17):

### Common Lisp, 6 characters

```
(loop)
```

Comment: Is there something such as **Rare Lisp**?

Comment: @flawr I'll assume it was just a humorous comment, but Common Lisp is the result of a standardization process that unified a bunch of mostly-but-not-quite compatible languages in the Lisp family.  Languages in the Lisp-family that aren't Common Lisp include Scheme, Racket, Emacs Lisp, and Clojure.

Comment: Also (a bit longer, but if we didn't have to count parens, it'd be just two bytes): `(do()(()))`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I thought about `do` too, and about making the reader goes on infinite loop but I don't see how to do it shortly. It seems that nothing beats `(loop)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor if you didn't count parens lisp would be the golfiest language of them all

Comment: @flawr Yeth, it'th when you can't properly pronounth the letter "eth" or "the."

Answer (score 14):

## [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission), 1 byte

There are exactly 4 one-byte solutions:

```
R
```

```
L
```

```
U
```

```
D
```

These four letters indicate that an atom starts there (in the corresponding direction). One of them is required because without an atom the program terminates immediately. Since the source code is only one character in size, the atom will wrap around immediately, and execute the same cell again. However, after the beginning of the program `UDLR` simply act to deflect an incoming atom in the corresponding direction, so they become no-ops in this case.

Answer (score 13):

## PowerShell, 7 bytes

```powershell
for(){}
```

...

Comment: Heh. Beat my own attempt by three bytes. Learned a couple of things from this challenge!

Comment: Quickly writes code. Starts scrolling to post...oh... ```for(){}``` same

Answer (score 13):

## Microchip PIC Machine Code, 0 bytes

An unprogrammed/erased PIC will by default have the program memory (flash) contain all NOP instructions. NOP does nothing.

Now, NOPs by themselves don't implement infinite loop. But the PIC program counter by design wraps around back to zero. Therefore, an unprogrammed/erased PIC executes an infinite loop.

Note: This is true for a lot of CPU architectures. Especially microcontrollers.

Comment: Interesting.  For reference, on x86: `00 00` is `add  [eax], al`.  (or rax for 64bit code.)  So it will segfault unless eax happens to hold a valid pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Depending on the CPU family, erased EEPROM can have values of either 0xfff or 0xffff (PICs have weird word length for program memory - like 12 bits or 10 bits etc.). But it is always interpreted as NOP. A segfault triggers an interrupt right? So if the interrupt handler for segfault is also null it would continuously re-segfault. Isn't that a loop?

Comment: Oh right, so EEPROMs are like NAND flash, and erase to one, not zero.  Neither 0F FF nor FF FF are valid instructions in x86 machine code, in 16, 32, or 64bit mode.  In Unix, a segfault results in a SIGSEGV signal being delivered to the process by the OS.  An illegal instruction results in a SIGILL.  The default action is to terminate the process.  If the process had earlier installed a signal handler (with the `sigaction(2)` system call), it could catch SIGSEGV or SIGILL.  It's a much better design to default to killing processes that run bad code, vs. inf loop!

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm talking about a bare x86 CPU with all the data pins soldered to ground - it won't be able to load any OS but it should permanently segfault. Though I wonder, if you need to add 1 byte for every command line flag passed to the interpreter how many points do you need to add if you solder the pins on the CPU?

Comment: Oh right, of course you wouldn't have an OS on unprogrammed memory.  But it's only a "segfault" if you're running under a Unix-like OS.  You're talking about a #GP(0) general-protection fault or #UD undefined insn fault.  The only way a bare CPU will actually "stop" is if you run some kind of halt-until-next-interrupt instruction.  The default behaviour is to keep running, even if it's a loop of illegal-instructions in the illegal-instruction-handler.  I'd consider a fault to be the hardware running your program again, rather that the prog being a loop, and thus less interesting.

Comment: So I think it's an interesting answer for CPUs where 0F FF or FF FF encodes a NOP and the instruction pointer loops, but not for CPUs that only loop by faulting on either that insn encoding or when they get to the end of memory (e.g. if they have some unmapped address space that isn't backed by EEPROM, and reading that faults instead of also being a NOP).

Answer (score 12):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 3 bytes

```
1do
```

For obvious reasons, this does not work in the online interpreters.

Comment: Shame this has got only 2 upvotes after over a year, it deserves more...

Answer (score 12):

## [Funciton](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Funciton), 72 bytes

Encoded in UTF-16.

I cannot think of a smaller Funciton program that would run forever. It consists of a declaration of a function that calls itself and a main program that calls said function on STDIN. Is it possible to do shorter?...

```
┌─╖╓─╖┌─╖╔╗
┤∞╟╢∞║┤∞╟╢║
╘═╝╙─╜╘═╝╚╝
```

Comment: Well, it looks like this only takes 35 bytes in `cp437`, and [according to Python](https://repl.it/@SamB1/LawfulDigitalMegabyte) it actually round-trips. Does that count as shorter?

Comment: @samb The interpreter doesn't accept cp437-encoded files.

Answer (score 11):

### C, 11 bytes (on old x86)

```
main=65259;
```

`65259` or `0xfeeb` is the machine code `eb fe` or `jmp -2`. Jumps are relative to the next instruction, so this loops.

This compiles (with a warnings) and works on my Linux 2.4.9.
Newer Linux will usually put `main` in a non-executable section. Adding `const` will fix it, but at an unbearable price.

Just noticed [kirbyfan64sos's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59397/3544) that uses the same machine code. But it's not in C.

Comment: Could you use `-277` instead of 65259?

Comment: @anatolyg, yes, it indeed saves a character.

Answer (score 10):

## Matlab/Octave, 11 bytes

```
while 1;end
```

(tested)

Comment: It works. You can remove the untested warning. +1.

Comment: Did you test it in Matlab *and* Octave? (Oh and I just noticed: *Tested* says nothing about the outcome of the test=))

Comment: Yes they both work... Well... It halts :) if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
()$
```

This is just a simple "while true do nothing."

Saved 2 bytes thanks to cat.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that Cat took two bytes out of Mouse, but didn't eat the whole thing?

Comment: @SteveEckert Haha. :D

Answer (score 10):

### A POSIX OS's program loader, 14 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: How do you run this?

Comment: The space isn't necessary.

Comment: @AlexA. Save as `t`, make executable (`chmod +x t`) and execute (`./t`).

Comment: Why does this loop?

Comment: @xebtl: With this in `/tmp/foo`, the execve(/tmp/foo) -> OS invokes `/usr/bin/env` as the interpreter, with `argv[0]` = `/tmp/foo`.  This causes env to `execve(/tmp/foo)`.  Try it with `strace -f -eexecve /tmp/foo`.  The Linux man page for `env(1)` doesn't seem to mention the case where env is invoked with it's 0th arg being something other than env, but it's standard behaviour.  I guess env figures out when it's being used as an interpreter for stuff like `#!/usr/bin/env perl` to use `$PATH` to find perl.  So in that case, it processes anything on the line as env args, then appends $0.

Comment: Putting `#!/tmp/f` in `/tmp/f` results in execve returning an error: `ELOOP`.  Even if that did work, you'd have to count the string twice: once in the file, and once as the required filename.  (although `/f` would work, and maybe even a single-char relative path).  But anyway, not viable.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, I realize now I did not actually know how `#!/usr/bin/env python` works before.

Answer (score 10):

### [Mornington Crescent](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent), <strike>117</strike> 106 Bytes

```
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Angel
```

There appear to be some bugs in the Python interpreter, but the language's creator has a C# interpreter that works for this code.

*Inspired by @ETHproductions

EDIT: Since it doesn't ever terminate, can remove required return to Mornington Crescent

Thanks Martin Büttner for 8 bytes, and Timwi for 3 bytes.

Comment: Using `Bank` instead of `Moorgate` saves 8 bytes. ([My prime tester answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58257/8478) has a CJam script that helps when finding the shortest path between two stations.)

Comment: Esoteric IDE does not require Windows EOL. I saved your program with UNIX line endings and the IDE opens and interprets it fine. :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, should have looked at the actual code, instead of the London tube map :P

Comment: I love the fact that ^that comment was able to happen. "I would have been able to make this code shorter but I was looking at the London tube map."

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Username checks out ;)

Answer (score 9):

## [Recall](http://www.minxomat.eu/introducing-recall), 2 bytes

```
Yy
```

Since there is no break operator, it will loop forever. You can try it [here](http://minxomat.github.io/Recall/index.html?code=Yy). Of course it will freeze the tab.

Comment: Your links seem to be broken for me

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

I think the only solutions are `'# '`, which has already been posted, and the `f` based solutions:

```
f0
fk
fH
fY
fZ
f"
f[
f(
f{
f]
```

`f` followed by anything falsy.

Answer (score 8):

## Turing Machine Code, 9 bytes

As usual, I'm using the rule table syntax defined [here.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html)

```
0 _ _ * 0
```

"When in state `0`, upon reading an empty cell, replace it with an empty cell, don't move, and transition to state `0`."

Answer (score 8):

### [Macaroni 0.0.2](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/macaroni-lang/releases/tag/v0.0.2-alpha), 14 chars

```
label a goto a
```

Fairly self-explanatory...

Comment: -1 because you wrote Macaroni in Rust, and I don't have Rust right now, so I can't use it. :( (jk, I actually upvoted.)

Answer (score 8):

## Malbolge, 1 byte

A single-space program causes Ben Olmstead's [reference implementation](http://esoteric.sange.fi/orphaned/malbolge/malbolge.c) to loop forever. Can you find out why?

Comment: Wouldn't this be UF, looking for indices -1 and -2 of `mem`?

Answer (score 8):

## [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), 2 Codels

2 Codels is as small as a loopy Piet program gets.
With only 1 codel the 8 waits needed for a finish would be immediatly met.

[image: 2 codel loopy Piet]

In the example (10 pixel codelsize) the difference between the 2 colours are +2/-2 Hue delta and +2/-2 Light delta.  So it keeps on repeating a *"roll" "not"*.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, 6 bytes

Pretty self explanatory. Ok, my post is long enough now.

```
loop{}
```

Comment: And I came here thinking I could win with `(1..1.0/0).all?`.

Comment: same for rust lol

Answer (score 7):

## X86/X64 Machine Code, 2 bytes

Hex dump:

```
0xEB 0xFE
```

Disassembled source code:

```
f:jmp f
```

Basically, because the entry point `_start` isn't defined, `ld` defaults to the address that is coincidentally the location of `f`.

Comment: In some dialects of assembly you can write this as `jmp .` or `jmp $` without a label.

Comment: @Random832 The *exact* same machine code is generated, though, so it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I stuck these 2 bytes into a malformed ELF header to produce a 45 byte executable program http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59479/19694

Comment: On DOS, you could put just those two bytes in a `.COM` file.

Comment: @casey: If you're interested in ASM source size, I posted [a 4-byte x86 YASM/NASM answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59896/30206), which works on Linux: `ja $`.  I included an explanation of how it works as a complete program.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 8 bytes

**NOTE:** This is the same as the existing Processing answer; just posting it for the sake of catalogue completeness.

```js
for(;;);
```

**Bonus:** Here's a 12-byte ES6 alternative, using recursion instead:

```js
a=_=>a();a()
```

Comment: For the JavaScript version you can drop the final semicolon to save a byte ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe No, you can't. Just paste `for(;;)` into your browser console if you don't believe me. (The reason is that a for loop must execute at least one statement, even if it's an empty one.)

Comment: @scunliffe Yes, I actually tried that, but as user2428118 pointed out, it doesn't work.

Comment: isnt this a standart loop?

Comment: @Alex Um, yes, it's a standard JS loop. Is there something wrong with that? Or did you mean [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)?

Comment: @ETHproductions yep, I mixed those up :) sorry

Comment: alt way for the 12-byte ES6 way: `(a=_=>a())()`, looks even scarier xD

Answer (score 7):

### VBA (immediate pane), 14 bytes

This will freeze up the VBE and its host app:

```
do:loop
```

Comment: `1:goto 1` beat me by one...

Comment: I think this is only 7 bytes, why did you say 14?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 I wasn't sure if *the IDE itself* was like that, but VBA strings are 2 byte per character, ..I went for the worst-case figure :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [Chef](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Acme-Chef/), <s>75</s> <s>52</s> 46 bytes

*Saved 23 bytes thanks to @Sp3000*

```
L.

Ingredients.
1 i

Method.
X i.M until xed.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ITfv/30ePi8szL70oNSUzNa@kWI/LUCGTi8s3tSQjP0WPK0IhU89XoTSvJDNHoSI1Re//fwA) (if you dare)

Basically, this program repeatedly checks that `i` (always 1) is greater than zero, and while it is, `M`s the empty mixing bowl. <s>I tried to stick to the [original spec](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/chef.html) as much as possible, so it may be able to golf this even more.</s> Thanks to TIO, I can now verify my changes with a copy of the interpreter!

Comment: The `add` actually breaks it because you never put anything into the bowl. Note that `verb the ingredient` checks the ingredient itself, rather than the mixing bowl, so you can just drop the `add` altogether. Other golfs 1) Drop `g` from `1 g i` 2) Replace `Mix` like you say, e.g. `X the i.Mix until xed` 3) `Serves` is optional

Comment: @Sp3000 O great Resident Chef Master, thanks for your input! It's now down to 52 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## x86 Assembly, 3 Bytes

Inspired by [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24866/46231)

```
E8 FD FF
```

is the same as

```
label: call label
```

even better, write it to your boot sector to make your computer <s>unbootable</s> faster!

Comment: This is actually more nefarious than it seems at first since it's actually self-modifying code.  Yes, it will *eventually* create a stack overflow situation and (in at least an unprivileged OS like DOS) replace the entire contents of memory with the return address of the `CALL` (`label` + 3 bytes).  If say that value is `103H` then technically you've just filled the entirety of memory with the instruction `ADD AX,[BX+DI]` (or `ADD [BX+DI],AX`) which will then in fact execute infinitely. Cute.

Answer (score 7):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 1 byte

```
{
```

Lowkey unsure if this is a parsing bug or a feature, but it works and now I can't close the repl help please I have two unclosable tabs now Radvylf why would you do this.

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](http://php.net), 8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

When running from command line (-r argument) you don't need php openning/closing tags.

Ex.:
php -r "for(;;);"

Comment: This produces an error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1` or `Parse error: parse error in Command line code on line 1` depending on the PHP version used and when run like `php -r "for(;;)"`. You need at least one additional `;` at the end.

Comment: Rule 1: Each submission must be a full program, in this case `<?for(;;);`.

Comment: @primo this is a full program

Answer (score 6):

## APL, <s>8</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
-⍣=1
```

This repeats negation until the result is equal to the previous input (beginning at 1) which can't happen, so it loops indefinitely.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Dennis and 1 thanks to jimmy23013!

Comment: `s/forever/until the stack overflows`

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Hah, good point.

Comment: Or `-⍣=1` **.**

Comment: @jimmy23013 I don't understand that code. What does it do?

Comment: Repeat negation until the result is the same as the input.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Oh awesome, thanks! That saves another byte.

Comment: And the input is the previous output, while it is 1 in the first iteration.

Comment: Wonder if `⊢⍣≢` is valid as it constitutes a function...

Answer (score 6):

## C, 17 bytes

```c
main(){l:goto l;}
```

Why not for(;;);? Because `goto` are cool.. and `17` is a nice number

Comment: -1, intentionally not as short as possible.  `main(){for(;;);}` is one byte shorter, at 16B.

Comment: @PeterCordes Why not main(){main();}?

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes. For it to work, I needs to pass an option to the compiler.. so I decide to go pure C. Check Mark's solution at the first page of this codegold, where he proposes `main(){main();}`.

Answer (score 6):

## Java6 : 25 Bytes

In Java 6 and previous versions you can execute `static` initialization block without having `main` in your class file.

```
class A{static{for(;;);}}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `for(;;);` work just as well as `for(int i=1;i>0;);`, or is there some restriction in Java 6?

Comment: `while(true)` is shorter than and as valid as `for(int i=1;i>0;)`.

Comment: Why is `System.exit(0);` needed?

Comment: @OskarSkog It's not needed, just added to terminate the loop. Let me correct.

Answer (score 6):

## Unlambda, 7 bytes

```
``ci`ci
```

Try it [here](http://inazz.jp/unlambda/). It uses `c` (`call-cc`) which is a little magical.

Comment: *A little* magical? :-)

Answer (score 6):

### [Starry](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 9 bytes

```
`      +'
```

Loops in Starry are written with `` ` `` (which marks the current location in the code as label `n`, where `n` is the number of spaces in front of it) and `'` (which pops a value from the stack and jumps to label `n` if that value was non-zero). So we use these two `n = 0`. But that leaves the question how to get a non-zero value onto the stack. I believe the shortest way to do is simply to push a `1`, which requires 6 spaces and a `+`.

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), 8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

Since the expression to evaluate is omitted, it will always evaluate to `true` (i.e. your classic `while(true){}` loop in "disguise").

Comment: You don't need the ; at then end.

Comment: @GrantDavis Yes you do. The for loop still expects a statement, and the semicolon tells that there is no statement.

Comment: Although much longer, my personal favorite is `eval(s="eval(s)")`., because it consumes a LOT of memory

Answer (score 6):

## [MarioLANG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 3 bytes

```
!
=
```

I found several other solutions, but they seem to be bugs in the Ruby interpreter rather than features of the language (e.g. replacing `!` with `@`). This one actually seems to work intentionally. `=` is just a ground cell for Mario to stand on, and `!` instructs him to stop walking. So he just stands there, waiting for something to happen, which of course doesn't. (The usual purpose of `!` is to use it on elevators, such that Mario remains in place while the elevator moves to its target position.)

Comment: This doesn't work on [tryitonline](http://mariolang.tryitonline.net/#code=IQo9Cg&input=) i guess that it consider the program finished since mario is not moving at all, the next intuitive solution ' ^=' (marioLANG ain't easy to do in comment :/) doesn't work either

Comment: @EtherFrog I think TIO uses a different interpreter than the Ruby interpreter I tested this with.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ß
```

Recursively calls the main link. Thanks to tail call optimization, this results in an actual infinite loop.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w58&input=)

Comment: `01¿`, without recursion.

Answer (score 6):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 0 bytes

Alternatively, *any* single character does exactly the same.

**[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=)**

Cubix is a stack-based 2D language, created by me in March 2016. Cubix differs from ordinary 2D languages in that it's not strictly 2D: the code is wrapped around a cube. Any one-byte program wraps to this cube net:

```
   ?
>. . . .
   .
```

where `?` represents the character, and the IP (instruction pointer) starts at the arrow. `.` is simply a no-op, and when the IP reaches the right side of the cube net, it simply wraps back around to the left. Thus, any 1-byte program does nothing forever, no matter what the character is (as long as it's not whitespace).

Thanks to [@ErikGolferエリックゴルファー](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erikgolfer%e3%82%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b4%e3%83%ab%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%83%bc) for reminding me that the empty program does the same. When Cubix was originally created, this didn't work, because the interpreter created a cube of size 0 and threw an error when it tried to run. This was fixed a while ago, and it is now impossible to cause an error in Cubix.

Answer (score 5):

## [Processing](https://processing.org/), 8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

This is based on Geobit's answer in Java

Although the code below is not the shortest, it is one of Processing's specialties.

```
void draw(){}
```

This `draw` statement repeats itself over and over again. It is one of the differences between Processing and Java.

Comment: You can also add JavaScript to your title, code stays the same=)

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), 4 bytes

```
1{}h
```

Put a 1 on the stack, and loop until 1 is no longer truthy. Using `h` means that the number is never popped.

Comment: Alternatively, `{1}g`.

Answer (score 5):

## C++ 11 template metaprogramming, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```cpp
template<int>struct I{int v=I<1>{}.v;};int a=I<1>{}.v;
```

C++ helpfully comes packaged with 2 other turing complete languages: the C preprocessor, and template metaprogramming. Note that this does reach a max recursion depth at some point, but the OP clarified that this is okay.

[Example run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8fd53d5c126112b):

> ```
> g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
> Please submit a full bug report,
> with preprocessed source if appropriate.
> See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
> ```

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faa392813262d8f3) is even shorter (41 bytes):
`template<int I>class A{A<I+1> a;};A<0> a;`

But unfortunately, it requires the `-ftemplate-depth` option to be set to something rather high, I used 999999 in this example.

Comment: And a Preprocessor answer might be impossible unless there's a compiler that allows to set the maximum inclusion recursion depth or number of replacement sweeps per file.

Comment: @user75200 Next time please add a comment instead of editing someone else's answer when you have a suggestion to golf it further. @user75200 suggested you can remove both `int`, so it becomes `template<int>struct I{v=I<1>{}.v;};a=I<1>{}.v;` (**46 bytes**)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen/user75200 That doesn't work; types aren't assumed to be int in C++

Comment: @Justin Ah ok. I only programmed in C++ once during college, so I barely know anything about it. Simply rejected the edit and placed this comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Beam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beam), 2 bytes

There is a few ways of doing this from the very basic

```
><
```

to the very basic

```
>?
```

and

```
>|
```

Comment: I just came over here to post this, but then I noticed it in the catalogue snippet. +1

Answer (score 5):

## Commodore Basic, 3 bytes

```
1R╭
```

PETSCII substitution: `╭` = `SHIFT+U`, ungolfs to `1 RUN`.

Taking advantage of Commodore Basic's shortcut forms and the fact that any immediate-mode command can also be used in a program, this code simply runs itself, forever.

Alternatively, a more thoroughly infinite loop is the immediate-mode command

```
S|7
```

(PETSCII: `|` = `SHIFT+Y`, ungolfs to `SYS 7`).

This transfers execution to memory location 0x0007.  The BASIC interpreter stores the current search character here; when running the above code, this character is the double-quotation mark with byte value 0x22.  Opcode `0x22` is an [undocumented `HALT` opcode](http://www.pagetable.com/?p=39), which works by putting the 6510's micro-operation interpreter into an infinite loop.  The only way out of this loop is to reset the computer.

Comment: How about a note on what `R` and `Shift+U` respectively `S`and  `Shift+Y` will expand to? And You could submit a 6510 assembler program.

Comment: On the Commodore 64 and VIC-20 you can also use `0 GOTO` - if you do not specify a number then `GOTO` assumes that you mean `GOTO 0`. As Commodore BASIC on the C64 and VIC are recycled from earlier CBM/PET machines, this may also work on those computers. It does not work on the C128 in native mode though.

Answer (score 5):

## TI-BASIC, 2 bytes

If recursion is allowed (is it a loop?)

```
prgmA
```

Runs a program named 'A', hence the program must be named the same. Some research revealed that `prgm` is 1 byte, plus 1 byte for `A`

Runs out of memory pretty quickly, but that doesn't seem to be addressed above.

Comment: `:` is the mandatory beginning of each line, and I believe that isn't counted. Also, the title shouldn't be counted. Do you count a .js file name into the byte count? I'll look into the `prgm` token, though it's a single command.

Comment: In this case, however, the actual title is irrelevant as long as it matches the command.

Comment: However, the program would have to be lengthened for longer titles. A valid program would somehow have to find its own name.

Comment: This is indeed valid and two bytes long.

Comment: Isn't it three bytes: 1 for the `A` in the program name

Comment: Why do people always add `:` to the start of each line? It's just a part of the editor, not the actual code.

Comment: I believe this entry is invalid, because with this approach that calculator will run out of memory trying to remember how to 'return' from the program every time it is called.

It will output an error message, which is not allowed.
For a slightly longer, but valid example, see this answer:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59383/70583

Comment: @raddish0 "Even if your program runs out of memory eventually, it is still accepted as long as it is running the whole time from the start to when it runs out of memory"

Answer (score 5):

## COBOL, 51 bytes

```
ID DIVISION.PROGRAM-ID.A.PROCEDURE DIVISION.B.GO B.
```

Comment: `procedure division. a. go to a.` That's with `cobc -frelax-syntax -free -x *filename*` but probably counts towards bytes. What COBOL are you using that allows yours to compile with no flags/options? Same for your other COBOL answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Tcl/Tk, 0 bytes

Execute any empty file with the `wish` interpreter instead of `tclsh`.

Answer (score 5):

## Rust, 17 bytes

Didn't see one in rust so:

```
fn main(){loop{}}
```

real original and interesting and so different from all the other entries.

Comment: When I try this on the playground, it prints to stderr.

Comment: @BHustus What is it printing to stderr? I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Besides the standard compilation details, running results in `/root/entrypoint.sh: line 7:     6 Killed                  timeout --signal=KILL ${timeout} "$@"` via this link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=79c6d9d28f5c35bd8a4d163880882296&version=stable  That -might- just be the playground and not the actual compiled product though, I didn't have the chance to test a compiled version.

Comment: @BHustus It's an infinite loop and so the playground kills it after a timeout because they don't want to waste time running my code endlessly. If you run this on a desktop that shouldn't happen.

Comment: In that case, disregard what I said.

Answer (score 5):

## [Half-Broken Car in Heavy Traffic](http://metanohi.name/projects/hbcht/#heading1.2.3), <del>5</del> 4 bytes

```
^ov#
```

also in 4 bytes:

```
o
 #
```

Comment: I just took the interpreter for a spin, and somehow I get the feeling the looping is not in the actual code execution, but in the interpreter checking for infinite loops. Can't confirm until I manage to understand this code properly though (I don't think that affects the validity of the answer, but it's interesting...)

Comment: @Sp3000 Took it for a spin. Nice pun!

Answer (score 5):

## [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), 3 bytes

Before I dive into the explanation, let's start with the program itself.

```
F†€
```

Trust me, it's pure luck that they're all printable, and I'll get to why it is 2 1/4 bytes instead of 3 after the explanation. I'll explain this by walking through the process I took to create this program.

To start, BLC programs are just lambda calculus programs encoded in a special way. With this in mind, let's begin with the lambda calculus program that enters an infinite loop, known as omega.

```
(λx.xx)(λx.xx)
```

This results in an infinite loop because, according to Wikipedia, it reduces to itself after a single beta-reduction. To convert this into BLC, we must first convert it to [De Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_indices). It converts into the following:

```
.λ.11λ.11 (The dots after the λs are necessary for BLC but not part of De Bruijn indices)
```

Okay, now that it's in De Bruijin indices we can now convert it into BLC where `λ` translates to `00`, function application or `.` translates to `01`, and numbers are represented as `1^n0` where `n` is the number. Knowing this, it translates into the following binary:

```
01 00 01 10 10 00 01 10 10
```

This is why it's 2 1/4 bytes. As BLC instructions aren't full bytes (with the exception of 7), it is rare for programs to fit exactly into a certain byte count. To turn this into hex, we have to pad it in order to make it fit into 3 bytes. Doing this yields the following:

```
46 86 80
```

There we have the hex dump of our program! It runs in an infinite loop, doesn't run out of memory to my knowledge, doesn't output anything, and is a complete program that can be saved and run by piping the contents of the file to the official interpreter. You can also pipe the binary text to the interpreter and add the -b flag, to demonstrate that the non-padded version can be run.

Answer (score 5):

## x86-16 Assembly, IBM PC DOS, 2 bytes

There's quite a few machine code answers, but thought I'd contribute a few different takes.

```
56    PUSH SI    ; push 100H onto stack
C3    RET        ; pop stack and jump to address (PUSH SI)
```

On DOS when a program is started the `SI` register contains the starting address of the program (generally `100H`).  Push that onto the stack and execute a `RET` which will pop the stack and jump to that address.  Big ol' loop.

---

#### x86-16 Assembly, 1 byte

```
F4   HLT         ; halt the processor and wait for signal
```

Okay, so this may depend a little on your definition of infinite loop.  The `HLT` instruction (specifically in 8086 real mode) puts the processor in HALT state and awaits a signal in the form of `BINIT#`, `INIT#`, `RESET#` or interrupt ([ref](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/hlt)).  While it's not technically executing our code, it is in a microcode loop of sorts waiting for one of those signals.

---

#### Motorola 6800, 2 bytes

```
9D DD   HCF      ; halt and catch fire
```

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire#Motorola_6800):

> When this instruction is run the only way to see what it is doing is with an oscilloscope. From the user's point of view the machine halts and defies most attempts to get it restarted. Those persons with indicator lamps on the address bus will see that the processor begins to read all of the memory, sequentially, very quickly. In effect, the address bus turns into a 16 bit counter. However, the processor takes no notice of what it is reading… it just reads.

Answer (score 4):

## GNU dc, 6 bytes

```
[dx]dx
```

Tail recursion FTW, which GNU dc supports.  Others might not.

Comment: That's my [length 6 dc snippet](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57145/4372) :) But on my machine it just crashes. Is that normal?

Comment: Which machine do you have? (and which dc?).  I'm running GNU dc on Linux, which supports infinite tail recursion.  I think possibly other `dc`s don't support any kind of tail recursion, and end up crashing with a stack overflow.

Comment: A mac, using the pre-installed dc. It says `dc (GNU bc 1.06) 1.3`. I see that it works on a Linux box with the slightly newer version (1.3.95)

Answer (score 4):

## MUMPS, 1 byte

```
f
```

This is the equivalent of `for ( ; ; ) ;` in C-like languages. It runs from the prompt as is, though, and does not need to be wrapped in a function declaration or any such thing.

Answer (score 4):

## [MSM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MSM), 2 bytes

```
ee
```

Almost all 2 character strings will work, even two spaces, just don't use any of the following 6 commands `:,/.?'`.

Answer (score 4):

## AT&T (PDP-11) Syntax Assembly: 4 bytes

```
br .
```

## PDP-11 UNIX A.OUT binary output: <s>24</s> 18 bytes

```
0000000  000407 000002 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
0000020  000777 000000 000000 000004
0000030
```

This is the output produced by the assembler. As the sizes in the header show, the last three words are not necessary, it can be cut down to the first 18 bytes.

Some modern assemblers do not support the br instruction, so it would be **five bytes** for `jmp .`. And executable headers are generally much bigger these days.

## Linux x86-64 binary output, after strip: 336 bytes

Now, OSX's assembler is much more strict. You must have a symbol (by default `start`, but here I use `f`) for the entry point, which balloons the size of the source. It also requires a newline at the end of the file.

## Mac OS X x86-64 Assembly: 17 bytes

```
.globl f
f:jmp f
```

## Mac OS Mach-O Binary Output: 4200 bytes

Comment: You can get smaller  binary output if you golf the ELF header in Linux:  see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59479/19694

Comment: What machine is `br .` for?  x86?  Which assembler?  GNU as rejects it for x86-64.  In any case, I posted [a 4-byte x86 YASM source](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59896/30206), which assembles and links into a complete working infinite loop program on Linux: `ja $`.  GNU ld defaults to 0x0400080 if it can't find a `_start` symbol, so this really is a complete program.

Comment: @PeterCordes PDP-11 - and I assume also VAX, though I haven't had a chance to test it. It's common for older assemblers to use separate mnemonics for short jump instructions. The PDP-11 instruction contains the offset within the instruction word, with a range of even values from -64 to +62.

Comment: @Random832: could you update your answer, then?  "AT&T syntax" doesn't specify a machine.  For example, there is an i386/amd64 flavour of "AT&T syntax", used by the GNU tools by default.  `add $16, %rsp`, for example.

Comment: My answer goes into detail on the source required to make a usable x86-64 program on GNU/Linux and Mac OSX. By "AT&T" I meant the actual original assembler produced _by_ AT&T, whose syntax is imitated by these other assemblers.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
0~Do~∞
```

Comment: Alternatives with the same byte count: `For[,1>0,]` and `While@True`. Unfortunately `#0[]&[]` hits the iteration limit pretty quickly and exits with an error.

Comment: @MartinBüttner In fact, I was about to use your third suggestion before remembering about `$IterationLimit`...

Comment: 2 bytes shorter: `0~Do~∞`

Comment: @shrx Remember that `∞` is 3 bytes long in UTF-8.

Comment: @shrx Now that I think about it, are you sure that it works? It gives me an error on v10.1.

Comment: Yeah it works in 10.3.1 and 10.4.0 for me.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (8 bytes)

```
for(;;);
```

Edit courtody of @KritixiLithos

## Javascript (<strike>10 bytes</strike>)

```
while(1){}
```

Comment: Try `for(;;);` It has 8 bytes.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I forgot that javascript for loops are basically infinite if used wrong. I'm way too used to languages like python which eventually stop for loops. Very clever :)

Comment: Although, one can make an infinite for loop in python.

Answer (score 4):

## z80 Machine Code, 1 byte

```
c7       ; RST 00h
```

Or if assuming the code starts at `0000h` is cheating, two bytes:

```
18 fe    ; JR -2
```

These solutions make no assumptions about the rest of the environment's RAM. If it's filled with zero bytes, we are just spinning through `NOP`s forever, so we could have a 0-byte solution. (Thanks to Thomas Kwa for pointing this out.)

Comment: Good point; I've written a note about it.

Comment: For special fun, fill RAM with 0xDD (or 0xFD). Or maybe this isn't an infinite loop, because it's just one infinitely long opcode.

Comment: 1Byte = 76 ; Halt https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166100/80745

Answer (score 4):

## Scheme, 12 bytes

A tail-recursive infinite loop seems most appropriate for scheme `:-)`

```
(let l()(l))
```

even though `(do(())())` (the CL variant of which is due to [@JoshuaTaylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/59378#comment143074_59375)) would be 2 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Fortran, 11 bytes

It is not very creative, but here is the shortest I found:

```
1goto 1
end
```

I am pretty sure this is not standards compliant, but it compiles with `ifort`.

Answer (score 4):

## [3var](http://esolangs.org/wiki/3var), 2 bytes

```
{}
```

To quote the docs:

```
{   Starts a loop which repeats forever
}   Ends a loop which repeats forever
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)), 8 bytes

```
repeat{}
```

I believe this is the shortest way to make a loop that won't stop.  We would need an infinite length list to use a for loop and `while(T)` is longer than `repeat`.

Comment: I thought I had, but it sure as hell doesn't work -- dunno what I did. Sorry about that.

Comment: +1 : This or equivalently `repeat 1` (or `repeat x` with x being any valid single character expression)

Comment: @digEmAll doesn’t `repeat 1` output something?

Comment: @JayCe: I also thought so, but actually it doesn't...

Answer (score 4):

## NASM/YASM x86 assembly, 4 bytes

```
ja $
```

`$` is the address of the current instruction, and `ja` jumps there if the carry and zero flags are both unset.  (i.e. the Above condition is true.)  This is the case in x86-64 Linux at process startup.

`ja$` just defines a symbol, instead of being an instruction, so the space is not optional.  I did test that this works without a trailing newline, so it really is 4 bytes.

Assemble/link with

```
$ yasm -felf64 foo.asm && ld -o foo foo.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400080
```

The [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) used by Linux doesn't guarantee anything about the state of registers at process startup, but Linux's actual implementation zeroes all the registers other than RSP for a newly-`exec`ed process.  `EFLAGS=0x202    [ IF ]`, so `ja` (jump if Above) does jump, because the carry and zero flags aren't set.  `jg` (ZF=0 and SF=0) would also work.  Other OSes that initialize flags differently might be able to use one of the other one-letter conditions that require a flag bit to be set: `jz`, `jl`, `jc`, `jp`, `js`.

Using `ja` instead of `jmp` (unconditional jump) makes the source one byte shorter, but the binary is the same size (2 bytes: one opcode byte, one rel8 displacement, for a total size of 344 bytes for a stripped ELF64 binary.  See [casey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59479/30206) for a 45 byte ELF executable if you're interested in small binary size rather than small source size.)

Answer (score 4):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pb), 8 bytes

In pb, the shortest possible infinite loop is 8 bytes long. In fact, there are sixty 8 byte infinite loops, none of which produce output! (Unless you're running in watch mode, which is intended for debugging, no pb programs produce output until they halt. However, even if one of these did eventually halt, no output would have been produced.) Here are the sixty shortest infinite loops, in alphabetical order:

```
w[B!1]{}
w[B!2]{}
w[B!3]{}
w[B!4]{}
w[B!5]{}
w[B!6]{}
w[B!7]{}
w[B!8]{}
w[B!9]{}
w[B=0]{}
w[C!1]{}
w[C!2]{}
w[C!3]{}
w[C!4]{}
w[C!5]{}
w[C!6]{}
w[C!7]{}
w[C!8]{}
w[C!9]{}
w[C=0]{}
w[P!1]{}
w[P!2]{}
w[P!3]{}
w[P!4]{}
w[P!5]{}
w[P!6]{}
w[P!7]{}
w[P!8]{}
w[P!9]{}
w[P=0]{}
w[T!1]{}
w[T!2]{}
w[T!3]{}
w[T!4]{}
w[T!5]{}
w[T!6]{}
w[T!7]{}
w[T!8]{}
w[T!9]{}
w[T=0]{}
w[X!1]{}
w[X!2]{}
w[X!3]{}
w[X!4]{}
w[X!5]{}
w[X!6]{}
w[X!7]{}
w[X!8]{}
w[X!9]{}
w[X=0]{}
w[Y!1]{}
w[Y!2]{}
w[Y!3]{}
w[Y!4]{}
w[Y!5]{}
w[Y!6]{}
w[Y!7]{}
w[Y!8]{}
w[Y!9]{}
w[Y=0]{}
```

These all follow a simple pattern. `w` is a while loop, pb's only looping or branching instruction. Inside the square brackets is the condition, which is two expressions separated by `!` or `=`. To understand what this means, imagine an extra `=` just before the second expression. In the same way that you understand `2+2==4` to be true and `10!=5*2` to be false, `2+2=4` and `10!5*2` are true and false in pb. A while loop is executed until the condition becomes false. Finally, there is a pair of curly braces containing pb code. In this case, there's no code to be run, so they are empty.

The important thing here is the condition. pb has six variables, all for different purposes. They are:

```
B - The value of the character under the brush
C - The colour of the character under the brush (from a lookup table, the important thing being that white = 0)
P - The current colour that the brush is set to output in (same lookup table)
T - Set by the programmer, initialized to 0
X - X position of the brush
Y - Y position of the brush
```

The brush starts at (0, 0) on a canvas that is entirely initialized to white null bytes. This means that all of the variables start out being equal to 0.

These sixty programs fall into two categories: 10 loops that are executed until a variable (equivalent to 0) stops being zero, and 50 loops that are executed until a variable (equivalent to 0) becomes a specific non-zero number. An infinite number of programs can be written that fall into that second group, but only 50 are the same length as the 10 in the first one.

Answer (score 4):

## ArnoldC, 61 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
STICK AROUND 1
CHILL
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Ironic how the program never actually terminates, even though the last line says "YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED."

Answer (score 4):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 1 Byte

```
<
```

<s>Since Vitsy loops around the line, a single space is an infinite loop.</s> This functionality was removed in the latest version, but this applies as a special condition for looping around a line.

You could technically also do it like this:

```
[
```

But it throws an error after a little while:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.VTC.vitsy.OperativeHandler.doOperation(OperativeHandler.java:6)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:88)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.loopHandler(Vitsy.java:82)
    at com.VTC.vitsy.Vitsy.opHandle(Vitsy.java:195)
    ... (few hundred more lines)
```

It's a pretty staggeringly long error.

The 'correct' way to do an infinite loop in Vitsy, however, is this:

```
[1]
```

where `1` is any number `[1-f]`. `[` starts a while loop, `1` pushes 1 to the stack, and `]` pops the top item off the stack and tests if it is 0. If it isn't, go back to the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

### [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/mbuettner/brian-chuck), 7 bytes

```
#{?
#{?
```

The `#` could be replaced by any other characters except null-bytes or underscores.

The idea is fairly simple:

- Brian moves Chuck's instruction pointer to the start (`{`) and hands control 
  over to him (`?`).
- Chuck moves Brian's instruction pointer to the start (`{`) and hands control over to him (`?`).
- Repeat.

Answer (score 4):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), 2 bytes

```
0
```

*(note the trailing space character)*

Any seed program consists out of 2 instructions, seperated by a space; The length of the [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) program it will output and the seed which will generate that program.
Seeing how [we need a Befunge program of length 0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59357/41257), we can create a Seed program with an empty 2nd instruction.

The Seed program `0` will output an empty Befunge program, which will run forever.

Interesting to note is that the Python compiler on the [Seed esolang page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed) is erroneous.
To create a Befunge program of length 0, any seed will do. That includes an empty seed. To stick to the spec however, the space after `0` is not omitted.

That being said, this is the world's shortest Seed program, and also the easiest to reverse engineer :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Aubergine](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aubergine), 6 bytes

```
:aa=ia
```

`:aa` is a no-op. `=ia` sets the IP to its own location.

Comment: Likewise, `aaaiii` is the shortest for Purple BUT `-i3` is the shortest for UberGenes

Answer (score 4):

## Mumps, 1 byte

```
F
```

Mumps being a very old language, most of it's commands and operators can be truncated to 1 or 2 letters. The [F]or command with no parameters defaults to an infinite loop until interrupted by a {CTRL}{C}. The flavour of Mumps that I use is InterSystem Caché.

Answer (score 4):

## [Mmmm()](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Mmmm%28%29), 56 bytes

```
mm=m[m.m()].m;mm=mm(mm(m.m()));m[mm].m(mm);<m[mm].m(mm)>
```

No, I have no idea how it works either.

Answer (score 4):

## Linux shebang, 5 bytes

```
#!./a
```

Must be named as a.

Will run out of memory, but this is an infinite loop.

Comment: I can't believe nobody's thought of this! +1

Comment: Which system? On Ubuntu `exec` is a Bash built-in, so I can't specify it as script interpreter.

Comment: @manatwork oh, sorry, i forgot that it is built-in. fixed

Comment: Not runs out of memory: “bash: ./a: ./: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links”. (Though no actual symlink involved.) Well, infinite for 0.001 second.

Comment: @manatwork stack overflow auto-detect?

Comment: @username.ak https://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Not working *...bad interpreter...*  better put `./a` alone in the script. If you want to avoid out of memory use `./a&` . That's fun if you `ps` after. That last script will put your computer in a race of creating processes and managing dead processes

Comment: As PID is changing every time, only solution is to rename the  script to end the loop : `mv a z`

Answer (score 4):

### Bash, <s>10</s> 2 bytes

```
$0
```

Runs the file specified by `$0` (i.e. itself). Requires that the script is executable.

Comment: This is at least \$5\$ bytes, as the file name must be at least `.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), x86_64, 10 bytes

```c
main=-277;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z83MTPPVtfI3Nz6/38A)

#### How it works

This writes the *int* **-277** (`ebfeffff` in little endian) to the memory location of *main*.

`eb` is JMP and is to be followed by a signed 8-bit address indicating where to jump to. `fe` is **-2**, so we jump back to `eb` and start over.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvkPBAA)

Another 2D language with a zero byte answer. Funnily enough, the *minimum* byte count to terminate consistently is 5 bytes:

```
%@
//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X9WBS1//////uo6BAA)

Answer (score 4):

## Racket, 39 bytes

```
((λ(x)(x x))(λ(x)(x x)))
```

Comment: Nice answer! Was this inspired by the Y combinator?

Comment: @user Yeah, it was!

Answer (score 4):

## [StackLang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StackLang), 1 byte

```
2
```

### Explanation

2 is an opcode for infinite loop. When it reaches the bottom of the stack, it loops around.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 4):

### [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus), 47 bytes

```
G'DAY MATE!
THE HARD YAKKA FOR f IS()<f();>f();
```

Tested in commit 0a5de7e. The official syntax for this is:

```
G'DAY MATE!

I RECKON I'LL HAVE A WALKABOUT UNTIL (YEAH, NAH) <
>

CHEERS C***!
```

However, that `UNTIL` loop is so verbose it's shorter to use a recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 3 bytes

```
!{}
```

The control stack is initially empty, the `!` negates it to truthy, and `{}` is a loop-while-true which never ends.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 12 bytes

```
while(1>0){}
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 4 Bytes

```
While 1
End
```

Also:

```
Lbl A
Goto A
```

---

---

---

This last language isn't really an answer, as the language does not exist… yet. So, yeah, just some information, and how one might accomplish this task

**Simplex, 1 Byte**

```
O
```

*Simple* enough. Simplex has the `O` command, which goes to the _N_th character in the source code, with *N* being the current byte. Since, by default, a byte is `0`, this continues to go to the first character in the source code (zero-based).

Comment: TI-BASIC is 4 bytes. The 10-byte program header is counted in the MEM menu, but not here.

Comment: Why not simply, for a program named `W`, `:pgrmW`?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE because then (1) I would have to include the ten byte header, and/or (2) because the calculator will run out of resources.

Answer (score 3):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 3 bytes

```
+/1
```

Note that this will eventually run out of memory...

Answer (score 3):

### x86 Intel Assembly (NASM), 5 bytes

```
jmp $
```

Comment: I posted [a 4-byte improvement on this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59896/30206), which works on Linux: `ja $`.  I included an explanation of how it works as a complete program.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
while 1<2end
```

Yawn. I tried a map and a for loop, but to no avail...

EDIT: Someone pointed out that I could shorten the program by removing parentheses. Thanks!

Alternatively, if stack-overflowing infinite recursion counts as infinite (11 bytes):

```
i()=i();i()
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `1<2` (in fact it's rather "un-Julian" to have them there).

Comment: Why isn't `1` True, or why isn't `1<2` 1? (That is, why doesn't Juila implement `bool` as a "subclass" of `int`, like Python does, which is endlessly useful?)

Answer (score 3):

## [ZX Spectrum BASIC](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/sinclairbasic/), 2 bytes

```
1 RUN
```

The program will never run out of memory :-)

Explanation:

- There is no space between the line number and the command, it is just a visual clue displayed when LISTing the program
- The keyword RUN is one byte, in Sinclair BASIC the keywords were really just a single characters (with codepoints >=128), that just happened to look like multi-character words when displayed. In particular, you enter the keyword by pressing *one key*, [the one with the keyword on it](http://zxspectrum48.i-demo.pl/hardpics_pliki/sinclair_zx-spectrum_keyboard_hr.jpg), and it enters one byte.

The internal representation is a bit longer (line number is stored as two bytes), but isn't this true for almost all the languages? :-)

Comment: The internal representation also has one byte for the end of line character and one byte for the end of program character, so 5 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## k, 4 bytes

```
~:/1
```

### How it works

In k, `/` iterates the function on the left starting with the argument on the right until the result repeats.  The `~:` is a "not" function which turns 1 into 0 and 0 into 1 repeatedly in this code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)), 32 bytes

```
program l;begin while 1=1do;end.
```

A full program in just one line.

- `program l;`: Start a new Pascal program
- `begin`: Begin a code section
- `while 1=1do;`: Do nothing (`;` / `NOP`) as long as `1=1`, which shorter than `true`. Identifiers (`do` for instance) are not allowed to begin with a digit, so we can omit the space here and save one byte.
- `end.`: End the code section

Comment: There needs to be a token separator between `1` and `do`. The ISO standard 7185 states: “There shall be at least one separator between any pair of consecutive tokens made up of identifiers, word-symbols, labels or unsigned-numbers.” `do` is a “word-symbol” and `1` an “unsigned-number” so there must be a token separator. _Some_ compilers are sloppy in that regard though. I could compile your `program` with the [Free Pascal Compiler](https://www.FreePascal.org/), however for instance the [GNU Pascal Compiler](https://www.GNU-Pascal.de/) – rightfully so – refused to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

## Go, 31 Bytes

```
package main
func main(){for{}}
```

Nothing special, the for loop without header runs infinitely.

Answer (score 3):

## [Beatnik](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), 8 bytes

```
K A XX K
```

Push a number, 1 in this case.  Pop a number, if not zero skip back 4(crossed out 4) 5.  There seems to be an issue with the interpreter so we need to skip back 5 instructions rather than 4.

Of course the example on the esolangs page is better.

```
Ha, an interminable line!
```

or my version

```
Start a neverending tale?
```

Comment: It seems like you've been caught by an off-by-one error. Replace the `Y` with a `K` to fix. Also, you've got a leading space (not included in the bytecount nor necessary). You can also add a Try It Online link.

Comment: @NieDzejkob I have changed this, but I think the interpreter is bugged in this respect.  Going back 5 instructions when there is only 4 instructions seems a bit wrong.  I don't think an infinite loop on TIO is a good idea.

Comment: @MickyT TIO will self terminate code if it runs over 1 minute.

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](http://mroman.ch/burlesque/), 2 bytes

```
bc
```

The `BoxCycle` command. Essentially takes whatever string `s` is on STDIN and tries to evaluate the infinite list `[s, s, s...]`

Answer (score 3):

## Lazy K, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
SISSSII
```

Reduces to the lambda expression `(λx.x x) (λx.x x)` which has no normal form.

Comment: Tried to golf it: `SISSSII` (not tested).

Comment: That works! Really cool :)

Answer (score 3):

## SQL (SQL Server 2008+), 92 bytes

```sql
WITH R AS(SELECT 1N UNION ALL SELECT N*1FROM R)SELECT*FROM R WHERE N<1OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I feel <s>a little</s> dirty putting this up, but my original thought was that this wouldn't be possible with a SQL query.  With something like T-SQL or PL/SQL not a problem, as a query though?  The obvious answer was a recursive query with no recursion limit set.  But how to get it to run without outputting anything.  My initial tests using queries like

```sql
WITH R AS(SELECT 1N UNION ALL SELECT N FROM R)SELECT*FROM R WHERE N=0OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
WITH R AS(SELECT 1N UNION ALL SELECT N FROM R)SELECT*FROM R WHERE N<1OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

showed that the optimizer would cause the query to exit immediately with no rows returned.  Using `N+1` allowed it to loop, but I suspect that the integer would eventually overflow.  I used `N*1` in the query to avoid that and trick the optimizer into letting it run without short cutting out.  I've let it run for a few minutes on my machine and it didn't seem to start consuming memory, but I can't guarantee that wouldn't happen.

Comment: SQL has loop constructs too, even if it's slow to use them. Why not something like: `WHILE 1=1CONTINUE` ?

Comment: @Bridge SQL doesn't really have while loops.  The database systems have procedural languages that have loop constructs.  With this answer I was trying to keep to SQL rather than T-SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: Hey only trying to help, I don't have enough rep here to post my own answer. Doesn't your answer contain things that aren't ANSI SQL either, e.g. SQL Server specific extensions? The truth of the matter is, dump the code I wrote into SQL Server, and you have an infinite loop in a quarter of the code :)

Comment: @Bridge I understand and thanks for the help. You should be able to post an answer.  I think most RDMS's now support recursive CTEs and they were introduced in SQL:1999.  So while the syntax may differ slightly I could do this query in postgresql with no issues.

Comment: It was the `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` bit I was unsure about :)

Comment: Incidentally, OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) is MS specific and DB2 doesn't need it so you can shorten a few bytes.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for the pointer, I'll see if I can track down a DB2 instance to test it on.  The biggest issue was with tricking the optimizer into allowing it to happen.  DB2 may be a bit more sensible than SQL server.

Comment: Personally I think default infinite with no stupidity check is in worse taste but oh well.

Comment: @Joshua Yep ... no arguments here

Answer (score 3):

## [Rail](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail), 11 bytes

```
$'main'
@-@
```

Rail starts at the `$` of the `main` function, heading southeast. We hit `-`, which makes the train turn and move eastward. After that it's just bouncing all night long between two `@` reflectors.

Answer (score 3):

## [Insomnia](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Insomnia), 2 bytes

```
HY
```

It encodes the sequence of instructions: `7289`

Although it's not clear whether instruction 8 checks the content of the bit pointer or the group pointer, the code above works in either cases, since the content of the bit or the content of the group is always non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ziim](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ziim), 14 bytes

Encoded in UTF-16. (UTF-8 without BOM is 16 bytes...)

```
↘↙↙
↑↑
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Emmental](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Emmental), <s>18</s> 11 bytes

```
;#35#63#!#?
```

Emmental is a self-modifying, stack-based language. It has no built-in looping operator, so we have to make our own. Here's what the relevant commands mean (taken from the Esolangs wiki page):

- `;` - Push the symbol `;` onto the stack.
- `#` - Push `NUL` (ASCII 0) onto the stack.
- `0..9` - Pop a symbol, multiply its value by 10, add 0..9 respectively, and push the result.
- `!` - Pop a symbol and an Emmental program (a string of symbols terminated by `;`). Then redefine that symbol as having the same semantics as that Emmental program.
- `?` Pop a symbol and execute it. This is similar to `eval`.

So, what does this program (created by @Sp3000) actually do? Well, it redefines `NUL` to mean `#?` (push `NUL` and execute it), then executes `NUL`. This sets off a domino-like effect where `NUL` executes `NUL` executes `NUL` executes `NUL`...you get the picture.

I'm no expert on Emmental, but there may be an even shorter way to loop infinitely. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Since you put in the effort to write an explanation, here you go: `;#35#63#!#?`

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks, that's a clever way to do it! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 1 byte

A language inspired by space-time has to have at least SOME space! It's also worth noting that *this* particular 2D infinite loop is unique in that it's actually looping through time. That is, it's falling through the layers (of which there is only 1) of the program, which is toroidal.

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>14</s> 7 Bytes

```
for(){}
```

Previous version (14 bytes):

```
while($true){}
```

Comment: I didn't notice this until today because I got an upvote, but I posted this exact answer earlier in the same same month: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59429/30402

Answer (score 3):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 6 bytes

Directly from the esolangs page.

```
(:^):^
(:^)     Pushes :^ to the stack.
    :    Duplicates the top of the stack
     ^   Pops the top of the stack and includes it in the command
```

Try it [here](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/underload/underload.html) using the stepping option to see it working

Comment: Do you mean "top" instead "tope"?

Answer (score 3):

## [PoGo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/PoGo), 4 bytes

```
pogo
```

### Explanation:

- po - add current position in code to the top of the po stack
- go - pop the most recent po location off the stack and jump there

PoGo uses an explicit call stack for flow control, the "po" stack. This code unconditionally jumps back to the beginning, producing an infinite loop. Note that it will not cause a stack overflow, the call stack will never contain more than one element.

Answer (score 3):

### [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), 8 bytes

```
loop {
}
```

Previous answer posted in AHK was wrong and did not create a infinite loop.

Comment: You can remove the space to save a byte.

Answer (score 3):

### [Quipu](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Quipu), 5 bytes

```
0&
??
```

`0&` pushes `0` as the current strand's value and `??` is an unconditional jump to that strand (which is the strand we're already on).

Answer (score 3):

### [DC](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Dc), 6 bytes

```
[dx]dx
```

It puts the constant string `[dx]` on the stack, duplicates it (`d` command), pops and interprets string (`x` command).

Answer (score 3):

## [Subskin](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Subskin), 6 bytes

A series of six newlines. It contains two instructions, both of which set the IP to the second instruction.

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, 9 bytes.

```
a:
goto a
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Fuzzy Octo Guacamole](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole), 2 bytes

```
()
```

A empty infinite loop.

Comment: Can you include a link to the language in the header?

Comment: @Downgoat done.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/6.0.0), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

Quite simple really:

```
`T

`    # Do ... while
 T   # True
     # Implicit end, normally: ]
```

Try it [online here](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFRd&input=) (Please stop it after testing, don't keep it running).

Answer (score 3):

## [evil](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil), 2 bytes

```
mb
```

Nothing to see here, just another self-GOTO...

Answer (score 3):

## [GPRX 3000](http://esolangs.org/wiki/GPRX_3000), 1 byte

```
g
```

Sets the IP to the value of register A (which is initially 0).

Answer (score 3):

### Seed, 3 bytes

`0 0`

Equivalent to an empty Befunge program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Noobinary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Noobinary), 4 bytes

```
0000
```

`0000` is a single instruction that jumps to the last `00` (or start of program) if the top of stack is 0.

Answer (score 3):

## [Barely](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Barely), 0 bytes

That's right! If the Barely interpreter receives the empty program, then it just hangs. Normally, the code would be terminated with a `~` to separate it from input, so the interpreter keeps reading EOF and never runs anything. Tested on DOSBox v0.74 using input redirection.

Answer (score 3):

## BASIC, 8 bytes

```
1 GOTO 1
```

Goto self

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
=\
```

Takes no input and no output.

#### Explanation

`=` will label the input with an integer. `\` is always false and will therefore trigger backtracking. Since the input has no constraints, it will unify as following, through backtracking: `0`, then `1`, then `-1`, then `2`, etc. This will go on forever.

Answer (score 3):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 2 bytes

```
0000000: 080a                                              ..
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=bm9wCiAgICBhZGQgMQ&input=) Check *Debug* to see the generated binary code.

#### How it works

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

```lisp
nop       ; Set an entry marker.
    add 1 ; Increment the current cell.
          ; (implicit jnz)
          ;     If the integer in the current cell is non-zero,
          ;     jump to the previous instruction.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaot++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gaot%2B%2B), 27 bytes

```
bleeeet bleeeeeet bleeeeeet
```

`bleeeet` enters the loop, and `bleeeeeet bleeeeeet` switches IP direction repeatedly.

Comment: fun fact: if you're a goat and you say this program you will rotate in a circle forever

Answer (score 3):

## Bash or perl, 6 bytes

```
exec$0
```

I realize that are both bash solutions and perl solutions this length or shorter, but there are no dual-language solutions.  Yup, it runs with either language.

Comment: Bash answers are always nice to see! Welcome to PPCG.

Comment: Put an empty line above it, and it will be a solution for bash, perl and Befunge-93 (and possible several other languages as well)

Answer (score 3):

## Casio FX-7000G, 5 bytes

```
Lbl 0
Goto 0
```

Quite self-explanatory: `Goto 0` indefinitely jumps back to the beginning of the program. The calculator stores each token as a byte, so `Lbl` and `Goto` are 1 byte each.

Answer (score 3):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 13 bytes

```
((v(d f(q(L(f
```

Parenthesis autocompletion really helps!

We define a function `f` that calls itself using tail-call recursion. Functions in tinylisp are lists containing two elements: parameter list and expression. Here, our parameter list is `L` (which makes this a variadic function: `L` is bound to a list of all arguments) and our expression is `(f)` (calling the function with no arguments).

```
((v(d f(q(L(f))))))
         (L(f))      The function list
       (q      )     Quoted to prevent evaluation
   (d f         )    Define f to be that list
 (v              )   The d call returns the name f; evaluate it to get the function itself
(                 )  Call the function
```

Use Ctrl-C to halt execution.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 2 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

`→1` go to line 1 (this line)

Answer (score 3):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
[a]Switch to plan a.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0msyPz/PzoxNrg8syQ5Q6EkX6EgJzFPQSlRSe//fwA)

Not very exciting. TIO will only run it for 60 seconds before timing out.

Comment: [20 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K0msyPz/P9oxNrg8syQ5Q6EkX6EgJzFPwVHv/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 8 bytes

```
(()){()}

Explanation: 

(())   - Puts one on the top of the stack
{  }   - Runs until the top of the stack is zero
 ()    - Filler so that the above function runs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU7NaQ7P2/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Z80, 2 bytes [non competitive, late entry]

```
18 FE
```

Assembly

```
JR -2
```

or

```
LOOP JR LOOP
```

Note: `JR` is a relative jump (hex code 18), followed by a signed 8-bit number. It changes the program counter by that number; that happens after the whole command (2 bytes) has been red and program counter increased to point at the instruction immediately after. `JR 0` would then just have no effect (a 2 byte version of `NOP`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 1 byte

```
00000000: c3                                       .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSSjRWIA3r//wMA)

A jump opcode. Since memory is padded with zeroes, the argument is `$0000`, so that the PC forever jumps from `$0000` to `$0000`.

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 9 bytes

Here are all of the different ways (that I know of) to make an infinite loop in Lua, from shortest to longest:

Goto loop ([Lua 5.2.0 beta-rc1](https://www.lua.org/work/old/lua-5.2.0-alpha-rc1.tar.gz) only) at 9 bytes:

```
@a:goto a
```

This is no longer possible in the latest version of Lua since the syntax for goto has changed, so this is now the shortest infinite loop at 11 bytes:

```
::a::goto a
```

The best that you can do using a while loop is 13 bytes by using an empty string, which Lua considers to be truthy, as the conditional:

```
while""do end
```

Here is a 14 byte repeat until loop using an uninitialized variable, which is always nil, as the conditional:

```
repeat until a
```

Tied with the return until loop, as well as my personal favorite, a recursive function using `load()` at <s>16</s> 14 bytes: (-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan French)

```
f=load"f()"f()
```

An infinite for loop made by Jo King at 18 bytes:

```
for _=1,1,0 do end
```

Finally, the longest of the methods that I know of, a normal recursive function at 22 bytes:

```
function f()f()end f()
```

I'm curious to see if anyone can find some other methods.

Comment: I think `for _=1,1,1e-16 do end` (22 bytes) could work as an infinite for loop.

Comment: Could the outer parentheses in `f=load("f()")f()` not be omitted?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the load loop, that would work. However wouldn't the for loop that you suggested eventually end, given enough time?

Comment: Well now I feel dumb for not thinking of that myself. Added.

Comment: I based my loop on the fact that `1+1e-16 == 1`; I guess using an actual zero works too ...

Answer (score 3):

## [µ6](https://github.com/bforte/mu6), 1 byte

```
@+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy01@//fQfv/fwA)

#### Explanation

The µ-operator takes a function and returns the least \$n\$ that results in a \$0\$ and since there is no \$n\$ such that \$n+1 = 0\$ this program won't terminate:

```
@   -- µ-operator applied to
 +  -- | successor function
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 61 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax]Ajax:Let usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7ECSCaXKHha6QUnp@alghjRrhWppXklsdGueSWpRQogRbEgwsontUShtBisXO//fwA)

It's totally legal to only ever use one character in a play; just don't make him do anything other than loop the program forever, exiting and entering the stage constantly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) `-m`, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
{>}I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v@/2q7W8////7q5AA)

-1 byte thanks to negative seven

```
        Since there is no input, the stack starts with nothing but -1 on the top.
{       Remember the current value on top of the stack, and loop:
 >      Move the head right on the tape of stacks. (All of them are filled with zeroes.)
  }     Repeat while the top of the stack is not as it was remembered.
   I    Since the loop goes on forever, this is just to make the program legal.
```

Comment: Since the choice of central involution doesn't matter, the shortest corresponding program without a flag to mirror is `-(>)(<)-`, which is not a cat program on account of failing to terminate.

Comment: You can save a byte by using a `{}` loop, removing the need for `-`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was sure that was the right loop until I actually figured out what I was doing, and then I promptly forgot.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainetry](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry), 41 bytes

The 41-byter is a golf of this Brainetry program with 133 bytes:

```
This program is useless.
This program is useless because it runs forever.
This program is useless because it does absolutely nothing.
```

and the golfed version:

```
a b c d
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e f g h i
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry) `-nnn`, 10 bytes

```
(<>{}{}){}
```

[Try it online!](https://bubbler-4.github.io/Flurry/#!KAA8AD4AewB9AHsAfQApAHsAfQA=###bgBuAG4A#MgAwADAAMAAwAA==)

Don't be afraid to click Run; it will stop immediately, complaining the program didn't finish in 10000 steps. Change the step limit and you can see that it is reducing into the same expression over and over. Running in the original Haskell interpreter actually runs an infinite loop.

While Flurry looks like Brain-Flak, it lacks explicit looping support. Instead, because it is functional and primarily designed with combinators, we can implement the [Omega combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Undecidability_of_combinatorial_calculus) `S I I (S I I)`, which endlessly reduces to itself.

The nilad `<>` evaluates to `S` and `{}` pops an item from the stack. When the stack is empty, `I` is popped. The monad `(f g h...)` evaluates `f g h...` as function application, and pushes the result to the stack.

```
(<>{}{}){}  Full program
 <>         S
   {}       I
     {}     I
(      )    Evaluate to (S I I) and push it to stack
        {}  Pop (S I I)
            The entire program evaluates to (S I I)(S I I) = Omega
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 8 bytes

```
main:x=x
```

One byte shorter than the classic `main=main`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
{
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=%7B&inputs=Hello%20World&header=&footer=)

*-3 thanks to answering the right question*

### Explained

```
{      # Start an infinite while loop
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (GNU-EFI)](https://wiki.osdev.org/GNU-EFI), 0 bytes

Yes, a C GNU-EFI program won't exit. You need to return for it to exit. Will not say anything, just hang.
And yes, it works with a standart GNU-EFI Makefile.
I used this one:

```
ARCH            = $(shell uname -m | sed s,i[3456789]86,ia32,)

OBJS            = main.o
TARGET          = main.efi

EFIINC          = /usr/include/efi
EFIINCS         = -I$(EFIINC) -I$(EFIINC)/$(ARCH) -I$(EFIINC)/protocol
LIB             = /usr/lib
EFILIB          = /usr/lib/
EFI_CRT_OBJS    = $(EFILIB)/crt0-efi-$(ARCH).o
EFI_LDS         = $(EFILIB)/elf_$(ARCH)_efi.lds

CFLAGS          = $(EFIINCS) -fno-stack-protector -fpic \
          -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -Wall
ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
  CFLAGS += -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER
endif

LDFLAGS         = -nostdlib -znocombreloc -T $(EFI_LDS) -shared \
          -Bsymbolic -L $(EFILIB) -L $(LIB) $(EFI_CRT_OBJS)

all: $(TARGET)

main.so: $(OBJS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ -lefi -lgnuefi

%.efi: %.so
    objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic \
        -j .dynsym  -j .rel -j .rela -j .reloc \
        --target=efi-app-$(ARCH) $^ $@
```

Hope this counts. And yes I tested this on a virtual machine.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is interesting, although I'm not sure if it counts as a loop.

Comment: But does it loop?

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 10 bytes

```
[ t ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjYM3l6WelUJxclFiSnPE/WqFEIVYhJz@/4P9/AA)

[Factor is not necessarily verbose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75837/78410) :P

Given that we need *a quotation to repeat* and *a looping word*, I believe this is the very shortest we can get in Factor.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu), 23 bytes

A "forever" block still runs when it's empty.

```
when gf clicked
forever
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

### Arduino, 27 bytes

```
void setup(){}void loop(){}
```

This is also the shortest Arduino code that will actually compile. I'm surprised no-one has done this yet.

Answer (score 3):

## [RISC-V machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V), 2 bytes

For CPUs implementing RV32I/E-C or RV64I-C:

```
01 a0 — c.j .
```

For RV32I/E-C CPUs only:

```
01 20 — c.jal .
```

## RISC-V machine code (no extensions), 4 bytes

There are 4 sets of 32[1] instructions that work for this

```
6f 00 00 00 - j .
ef 00 00 00 - jal .
6f 01 00 00 - jal x2, .
...
ef 0f 00 00 - jal x31, .
```

The other 96 options are based on the conditional jump instructions `beq`, `bge` and `bgeu` with the same register as operands

[1]: 16 on RV32E

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pure CPython 3.10 Bytecode](https://t.pxeger.com/xs.html?v=%22pure%22+according+to+the+definition+I+made+up+%3Ca+href=%22https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236724%22%3Ehere%3C/a%3E;+see+%3Ca+href=%22https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html%22%3Ehere%3C/a%3E+for+details+on+bytecode+itself), 2 bytes

Hex:

```
71 00
```

Disassembly:

```
    >>    0 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            0 (to 0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU3_zNyC_KIShaTMvMTi5MxMneLKYp2SyoLUYq7UitRkDTBTzzk_JTUEyNIw0IFASyCGadFLNEqKz0it0EhSUlJaWlqSpmux1NxQwcAAwr7pCRTWK0otyElMTgWqiclT0gGq1EQSUoCIaOpowJCSEggZgIQhIpo61bWaEAMXLIDQAA)

Comment: I know all instructions are supposed to be 2 bytes long, but this still works if you remove the zero byte. Does the runner code somehow pads this or does `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` work without an argument?

Comment: @ovs that would mean the bytecode interpreter is reading one byte past the end of the bytes object's buffer, and the byte after the end happens to be a 0 byte. This probably works most of the time, but it's too far into undefined behaviour IMO

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 10 bytes

I'm pretty sure this can be made shorter.

```
0
+T`d`10
```

Comment: Can't you just do `+` followed by nothing?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos `+` loops until the input no longer changes.

Comment: I know. But, if you're replacing nothing with nothing, the input will never change, right?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I was thinking backwards.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Exactly; therefore it would only loop once.

Comment: While you guys were discussing this, [I posted a working solution based on a similar idea](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59387/8478).

Comment: @MartinBüttner the pessimist says the glass is half empty. The optimist says it's half full. While the two are arguing, the opportunist drinks it.

Comment: @Cyoce Does that mean I'm the pessimist :P

Comment: @TheNumberOne I'm afraid that yes, you are the pessimist!!

Answer (score 2):

## GNU sed, 3 bytes

```
:;b
```

Using [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5477/11259) as justification for the relaxation of the no-input rule.

`:` defines a (nameless) label, `;` is a line/command separator, `b` jumps to the label.

Nameless labels seems to be a GNU extension.

Comment: Nameless labels [seems to be a bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-sed/2015-08/msg00002.html).

Comment: @Ben From your link *"Not really a bug as such"* - I prefer "undocumented feature" ;-)  Fair game for codegolf, IMO...  Don't use it in production code though.

Answer (score 2):

## Spin, 13 Bytes

File `x.spin`:

```
pub x
 repeat
```

(without trailing newline)

Compile and download it to your P8x32a microcontroller or run it using `spinsim`.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
repeat 1
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to MickyT!

Comment: You can use `repeat 1` for 1 byte saving.

Comment: @MickyT Nice, I always forget about `repeat`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Ada, <strike>49</strike> 47 bytes

```
procedure L is begin loop null;end loop;end L;
```

I'm guessing there aren't many Ada entries on Code Golf!

Naturally it should look like

```
procedure L is 
begin 
   loop 
      null; 
   end loop; 
end L;
```

and do exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Can you remove the spaces after the semicolons?

Comment: Yes  ... 47 bytes. Thanks! (even though it's making me grind my teeth to look at :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [AutoIt3](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki), 12 bytes

```
While 1
WEnd
```

Simply loop indefinitely. Nothing much to say.

Answer (score 2):

## BBC Basic for Windows, 3 or 6

http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

`RUN`

3 ASCII characters. Note in this version of BBC basic line numbers are not required.

If you don't consider termination and self-execution a loop, then the shortest program is

`1GOTO1`

6 ASCII characters.

One might expect these to be shorter in the tokenized version (1 byte per keyword), but it seems they are not, due to the way line numbers / internal ID's are stored.

Comment: Why not `1G.1`?

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 8 bytes

```groovy
for(;;);
```

Shortened from the original thanks to suggestions.  The trailing semicolon is still required, unfortunately.

```groovy
while(1){}
```

Comment: Can you not just do while(1); do you have to use {} ?

Comment: for(;;); <--what about that, I'm not familiar with Groovy

Answer (score 2):

## [Math++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 3 bytes

```
1>$
```

Basically a `GOTO 1` statement- on line 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Microscript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript), 2 bytes

```
1{
```

Essentially just `n=1;while(n!=0){}`. The interpreter autocloses any loops, etc. that are left open.

The Microscript II program `1[` is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

## OCaml, 17 bytes

```
while 1<2do()done
```

1 byte removed thanks to @Mauris.

Another one bytes the dust thanks to @feersum.

Comment: Try `1<2` instead of `true`.

Comment: @Mauris Nice catch, thanks

Comment: You can drop the space after `2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 3 bytes

Same effect as in regular BF. Increment the cell and loop forever. `-[]` is the same.

```
+[]
```

Since the source code in placed on the tape, this is also acceptable, and only works in SMBF:

```
<[]
```

If the tape were actually infinite, `[` or `]` would work, since the interpreter would search for the matching bracket forever. Unfortunately (fortunately?), you just get an "index out of bounds" error.

Answer (score 2):

### [Snowman 1.0.2](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/releases/tag/v1.0.2-beta), 6 chars

```
~:1;bD
```

`~` sets all the variables to active, `:...;bD` is a "do" loop (i.e. continues looping while the block returns a truthy value), and `1` is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth](http://esolangs.org/wiki/forth), 21 bytes

Unfortunately, you can't make a word that calls itself without using the keyword `recursive`, so I use a standard infinite loop instead.

```
: f begin 0 until ; f
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKSSlpmfmKRgolOaVZOYoWCuk/f8PAA)

Comment: Errors with stack overflow on gforth. What did you test this on?

Answer (score 2):

## [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com), 10 bytes

```
Do
Until 0
```

Lame.

Comment: AutoIt was my first programming language and this solution is good as well... So Plus One! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [ferNANDo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fernando), 7 bytes

```
1 1
1
1
```

Line 1 initializes `1` to 1, line 2 marks the beginning of the loop, and line 3 marks the end (a single variable statement loops back to the previous occurrence, if any, for as long as the variable is true).

Answer (score 2):

## Objective-C, <s>17</s>16

```
-(id)a{for(;;);}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [StackStream](https://github.com/puckipedia/StackStream), 21 bytes

```
{ dup exec } dup exec
```

Kind-of explanation thingy:

```
{ dup exec } # Push this piece of code onto the data stack.
dup # Duplicate it (stack: { dup exec } { dup exec })
exec # Execute it (stack: { dup exec })
```

Comment: Oh, someone else made a badly-parsed stack-based language? Yay!

Answer (score 2):

## gs2, 2 bytes

CP437: `►3`

Hex dump: `10 33`

Tries to split whatever is on STDIN into chunks of length 0. We never actually split off any chunks, not even from an empty string, so this takes forever.

Note that gs2 doesn't have any traditional looping constructs.

(Mitch Schwartz found this and told me about it, and I thought it was a really cute feature.)

Comment: What GS2 version is this? It immediately stops on the current version for me

Answer (score 2):

## Whitespace, 9 bytes

```
;
...; create label [space]
;
.;
.    goto label [space]
```

. represents a space and ; represents a newline character.

Comment: I know it's been almost three years, but you're currently code is actually 10 bytes, because it needs a trailing new-line for the "Goto Label". But you can golf it to 8 bytes by using an empty label instead of a Space-label: `NSSN` and `NSNN`. [Try it online raw](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBgYsLiP7/BwA) or [try it online with highlighting an explanation](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/P9qPK1ghWMGPK965KDWxJDXeJzEpNSfex98/IBYs58cFlPMqzS2IL8lHlvz/HwA).

Answer (score 2):

## [RoboTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboWar), 5 bytes

```
0 rti
```

RoboTalk has three "goto" instructions: `jump`, `return`, and `rti`.  `Jump` and `return` are plain "go to the address on the top of the stack" instructions, while `rti` has the side effect of (re-)enabling interrupts, as it's intended to be used to exit interrupt handlers.  In a robot without any interrupt handlers defined, however, it is functionally equivalent to the other two instructions while being one byte shorter than `jump`.

Answer (score 2):

## FlogScript, 2 bytes

```
F<
```

The `F<` (`flow-control-restart`) command repeatedly restarts the program.

Answer (score 2):

## 8085 Intel Microprocessor ,<strike>4</strike> 1 byte

```
0000h: pchl
```

whose machine code is:

```
E9
```

Just reset the microprocessor. And load E9 at 0000h.

p.s: its almost impossible in some kit to load program at ROM memory(which is basically the start memory) So, it works on simulator and some special kits only.

```
C000H: lxi h,C000h
C003H: pchl
```

whose machine code will be

```
21 00 0C E9
```

loaded in memory from C000H

Answer (score 2):

## Factor, 14 bytes

```
: a ( -- ) a ;
```

and nicely symmetrical looking (almost)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
W1
```

Note that there is a space after `W1`.

Answer (score 2):

### Burlesque, 5 bytes

```
0bc<-
```

Trying to reverse an infinite list is guaranteed to loop forever and since it loops forever no output will be produced ever.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6, <s>7</s> 5 bytes

The standard boring one is just an empty `loop (;;){}` construct.
( spelled `for(;;){}` in other languages )

```perl6
loop {} # 7 bytes
```

There are also exotic ones as well

- infinite sequence of the Any type object ( default value in $_ )

  ```perl6
  .roll(*) # 8 bytes
  ```
- unterminated sequence generator (0,1,2,3,4 ... Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf)

  ```perl6
  0...* # 5 bytes
  ```

Answer (score 2):

## [Roadrunner](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Roadrunner), 14 bytes

```
mEEp mEEP MEEp
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Seriously 0.1](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

`1W`

`1` pushes a 1 on the stack, `W` executes the code between it and the next `W` (or EOF) while the value on the top of the stack is a truthy value. Since the value on top of the stack stays 1, it NOPs forever.

Answer (score 2):

## [BotEngine](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BotEngine), 2 bytes

```
><
```

Fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: do bots loop around? if so, you could just do `>`

Comment: @anOKsquirrel No, they unfortunately do not. As stated in the specs, bots are destroyed upon exiting the grid.

Comment: ah, I see. better read more

Answer (score 2):

### Marbelous, 7 bytes

```
00
\\//
```

One marble bounces between the two deflectors forever.

Alternate version:

```
00
/\/\
```

Comment: What about simply `MB` ?

Comment: @overactor I've been meaning to change the language spec so zero-input boards don't proc every tick and instead wait for one input which they discard. That's a much more useful construct.
Regardless, even with the old spec, `MB` would infinitely recurse, not loop.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 8 bytes

```
while();
```

This almost crashed my computer once :o

Comment: Wait... this works? How?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: Where does it work?

Comment: @Qwertiy chrome

Comment: Nope: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )(…)`

Comment: Huh... it worked before...

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c), 2 bytes

```
()
```

`(` begins a loop; `)` ends it; there's no `^` so it never breaks.

Comment: Lol, cat and mouse :)

Comment: I think it's pretty great that I have the nickname `cat`, and am working on rebooting a language called `mouse` :)

Answer (score 2):

## QBasic, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
DO:LOOP
```

Even shorter than the GOTO one!

---

V1.0

```
1:GOTO 1
```

Classical Goto.

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](http://gamegiver.blogspot.nl/2015/12/introducing-qbic-qbasics-belated-entry.html), 2 bytes

```
{}
```

This compiles into QBasic as `DO: LOOP`.

---

Note that not long after answering this challenge, the workings of QBIC has been altered. We now see IF, DO and FOR as 'language constructs': an opening statement, `<code goes here>` and a closing statement. Note that WHILE/WEND, functions and subs could also be supported as language constructs in the future.

Those currently supported by QBIC (IF, FOR and DO) are opened using `~, [ and {` respectively. Closing them can be done with either a `]` or a `}`: these mean 'Close the last language construct' and 'Close all constructs'.

QBIC has had the ability to auto-close language constructs for some time now. The above code could be one byte only: `{`. The final statement that QBIC adds to its own source is a `}` to close all constructs.

Answer (score 2):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), 3 or 4 bytes

**A real loop (4 byte solution)**

```
*PFJ
```

Explanation:

```
* Generate IP, moving to the right.                      [0,0,0]•
P Increment top local stack value.                       [0,0,1]•
F Set all local stack values to top local stack value.   [1,1,1]•
J Jump to [row,column] = [top,2nd] local stack values.   [1,1,1]•
  IP jumps back to to the *
```

**Shorter 3 byte solution**

I am not sure if reflecting IPs back and forth counts as loop, but here it is:

```
j*j
```

Explanation:

```
j Mirror IP in horizontal direction
* Create IP
```

So, this program creates two IPs moving to the right and the left, which are reflected back between both `j`’s indefinitely.

Comment: I suggest you use the 3 byte solution.

Answer (score 2):

### [Spiral](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Spiral), 1 byte

```
0
```

All programs start at the label `0`. All programs halt at the command `!`. Self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse16](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16), 2 bytes

I hereby release the language I've been teasing!

```
0\
```

Goes to zero... which is the first byte... which executes the `\` goto again... which -- well, you get the idea. This is like `10 GOTO 10` in BASIC.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 14 bytes

```
repeat until a
```

or

```
while 1 do end
```

The first one works because a is nil (because it is undefined), so it will never be true. The second one works because anything that is not false or nil, when casted to a boolean, evaluates to true.

## Not boring version, 23 bytes

```
debug.getinfo(1).func()
```

debug.getinfo(1) returns the debug information of the current stack, and the func property represents a function that executes that stack. This will call the main stack an infinite amount of times.

Comment: Will any of these eventually overflow?

Comment: @cat I don't think they will. I tested all of them online on [this demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php) and it didn't overflow, or put anything in the output for that matter.

Comment: I just tested on `lua5.2.4` and the first two occupy 100% of a core but 0.0% memory and so will never overflow, while the last one crashes with a stackoverflow in a few seconds after eating 20% of memory each second.

Comment: Having said that, `debug.getinfo(1).func()` on `lua5.3` behaves exactly like the other two do.

Comment: That's good to know, I actually didn't know it overflows on earlier versions  of lua. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

## [2-ill](http://esolangs.org/wiki/2-ill), 7 bytes

```
@ @
@$@
```

The instruction pointer just loops counterclockwise forever.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 6 bytes

```
{redo}
```

See [redo](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) in perldoc.

Answer (score 2):

## Factor, 15 bytes

Yea, Factor is verbose.

```
[ t ] [ ] while
```

Do nothing forever. Hangs the Listener.

Comment: Here on PPCG we have such an interesting definition of verbose.

Answer (score 2):

## Subleq bytecode, 3 binary words

```
00 00 00
```

Equivalent to

```
*00 = *00 - *00
if(*00 <= 0) goto 00
```

Answer (score 2):

## [The Infamous Shakespeare Programming Language](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/), 122 bytes

```
.
Page,a cat.
Ford,.
Act I:
Scene I:z
[Enter Page and Ford]
Page:
Am I better than zero?
Ford:
If so, let us proceed to z.
```

Comment: Aren't the descriptions of the characters in the Dramatis Personae just comments? I'm pretty sure this would just terminate on the first iteration.

Comment: If they evaluate to a valid expression, then they will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

## V, 1 byte

```
ò
```

[V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) is a 2D string based golfing language that I <s>wrote</s> am in the process of writing, inspired by vim. In vim, recursive macros are a little bit of a pain to set up, so I tried to make them as easy as possible in V. The syntax for a recursive macro is:

```
ò<code>ò
```

This is equivalent to

```
qq<code>@qq@q
```

in vim.

V will automagically fill in the missing delimiter (in this case, the second ò) so we can leave it off, giving us a nice and simple one-byte solution.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 8 bytes

```
l:goto l
```

(Not to be confused with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59686) excellent answer from @MickyT    in Standard SQL)

Answer (score 2):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 11 bytes

```
lbla
GOTO a
```

Answer (score 2):

## Turtlèd, 3 bytes

any character but `*` works in the middle

```
[-]
```

alt:

```
{*}
```

Explanation:

```
[    ] Brackets make a while loop. The character after the opening bracket is taken, and
       the loop is executed while the current cell is not that character.
```

hence

```
[-]
```

Runs whilst the current cell is not -, but will never change it to that value, so infinitely runs, and never ouputs as it only outputs at the end.

---

```
{*}
```

works similarly, but it runs while the current cell IS that value. by default, the starting cell is *, so it runs forever, since it will never change its value

## (nontrivial) Polyglot, Turtlèd and Brainf*** 5 or 4 bytes, depending on implementation

doesn't make use of BF non instruction nops.

If you happen to have another cool esolang that might be able to be fitted in, tell me.

```
+[-+]
```

In wrapping implementations,

in non-wrapping:

```
+[+]
```

Explanation:

```
+    - essentially a nop in Turtlèd with no string, increments cell in BF
 [+] - loops while current cell is not: {BF:0, Turtlèd:"+"}. increments cell in BF
```

---

```
 [+-] - loops while current cell is not {BF:0, Turtlèd:"+"}. - is nop in Turtlèd with 
        no string, and `+-` together is nop (+1,-1) in BF
```

Answer (score 2):

## S.I.L.O.S, 9 bytes

```
:a
GOTO a
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=OmEKR09UTyBh&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), 7 Bytes

```rb
(-^:_)_
```

A more "readable" form would be `(- ^: _) 1`. The `_` can be any non-zero number and it will work the same (`_` represents infinity in J). `^:` is the "power" conjunction; it iterates a verb a specified number of times.  E.g. `(f ^: 3) 0` == `f(f(f(0)))`. When told to iterate `_` times, it keeps applying until it produces a constant output. Since negation never reaches a limit, this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>8</s> 26 bytes

```
set_time_limit(0);for(;;);
```

Almost forgot: default time limit is 30 seconds and script will exit with a Fatal Error if I don´t unset it.

Run with `-r`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
[[
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W1s&input=)

Explanation:

```
[     # Infinite loop start
 [    # Infinite loop start
      # Implicit infinite loop end
      # Implicit infinite loop end
```

You need something inside the infinite loop, or else it will just end

Comment: You don't need anything inside if you close it with `]`, but it's still 2 bytes (`[]`).

Answer (score 2):

## [DUP](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html), 6 bytes

DUP is a dialect of Wouter van Oortmerssen’s FALSE, invented by Ian Osgood.

```
[1][]#
```

Explanation:

This uses DUP’s while loop. the first block `[1]` is the condition block that checks if the condition is true/nonzero, and if it is, executes the second empty block `[]` that does nothing. The execution block is executed as long as the condition is nonzero.

```
 [1][]#
 instr.    data stack   return stack
 [        0                         push '[' location
    [     0,3                       push '[' location
      #   0            5,0,3        push '#' and '[' locations on return stack
 [                     
  1       1            5,0,3        push 1 (truthy)
   ][]    0            5,0,3,0      condition true → execute 2nd (empty) block
 [                                  jump to condition block (location 0, popped from the return stack)
  1       1            5,0,3
   ][]    0  ...       5,0,3,0             infinite loop
```

Just for the fun of it, here is a visually equally long solution that is 8 utf-8 bytes long, but unique to DUP because FALSE lacks this functionality:

```
[A]⇒AA
```

Explanation:

```
         data     return
         stack    stack    operator
[          0                                 push location of open bracket
   ⇒                                         operator assignment to
    A                      A => 0            new operator A (at address 0)
     A                                       execute operator A, push current IP location on return stack
[                 5                          move to operator A at location 0
 A                5,1                        execute operator A, push current IP location on return stack
[                                            move to operator A at location 0
 A                5,1,1                      execute operator A, push current IP location on return stack
...
[
 A                5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...
```

As you can see, the latter recursive solution quickly fills the return stack and sooner or later leads to a stack overflow, depending on the available RAM.

A full introduction and explanation of DUP instructions etc. can be found on [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/DUPEsolang.jl) or on the pages linked on the [online Javascript DUP interpreter webpage](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html).

P.S.: I just noticed that [someone already posted a FALSE version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104342/39407). I’m sorry for the duplicate. In this case both languages look the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Scala 12 bytes**

```
while(true)0
```

Avoid one character using 0 instead of `while(true){}`

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby w/[J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 5 bytes

```rb
:~!~0
```

J-uby is all about making procs (i.e., anonymous functions/lambdas) work more concisely in Ruby. It allows symbols to be called like procs without a call to `to_proc`. Additionally, it adds a lot of functionality to procs. The added functionality we are using here is `!~`, or "iterate until constant". Basically, it takes a proc and an initial argument, and applies that proc to the argument until the application stops changing the argument (`f.(x) == x`). So we are calling `~` (bitwise negation) on 0 until they are equal. But due to the nature of bitwise negation (`~x != x`, `~~x == x` for all `x`), this never occurs. Infinite loop.

### 7 bytes:

```rb
~:^^~:^
```

A more "readable" form would be `(~:^) ^ (~:^)`. In J-uby, `:^` is the call function; `f^x == f[x]`. The `~` operation turns a two-argument function into a one-argument function which applies the given argument to both sides. So `(~:^)^x == x^x`. Finally, we apply this to both sides by turning these into lambdas and we get: `->(x){ x ^ x } ^ ->(x){ x ^ x }`. This is analogous to `(x => x(x))(x => x(x))` in JavaScript, `(\x->x x)(\x->x x)` in Haskell, or `(λx.xx)(λx.xx)` in Lambda Calculus.

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@////9e8fN3kxOSMVAA)

The empty program in Alice does nothing... in particular it doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 15 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(;;)1}
```

The smallest code that doesn't look for input.

I tried without the `1` and `AWK` wasn't happy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9Iw9pa07D2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 4 bytes

```
[1+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/2lA79v9/AA)

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf) v2, 3 bytes

```
1[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Rxrc9s28rP0K2DXCUXrEdlp71o7ds5J005mmjRzmbkvilpBFGXTlkiWDyUZV/fXc7uLN0nZki@9meuHKgQWi8W@ASx8zVc8D7IoLfpxMgu/BEmcFyzNkiDMc3bGsvCPMsrCjiebPP@0LWDmTvecemTX7zmfh9Dr7XkK@vcsXIVZTq3/Nq15tAjjAhsPTONlFoazz9j42DQuk1k0jwAFtI9ogp5G2lOIemrwWI@TdL@O3xdZFF/iaO/DB6/HvH1vjBQvOCz0xc9vklnObtstGpaVQZFkHR8bWsVVlA9WfFEi8SMY01q32y0@m3WWAMCiOevsEcwVz6HJZ2bAIC3zK2g7Zet2KwvzsECcrIoRe8Vg6MzCosxilhe8CAc0hkh7bqON4mBRzkIaccLmfJGHiGRtlvO@4MFNdT1RHBURX/wLcTSsze5mf/5p1kqrAKi8h2RlhRiLCy8@p2Eypz6fnZ2ByHJisydAWouwYMUyBeQIcopN@A/FyFZrnmSsg1ARtA1P4ecZDhiANC@LK/judiUqGigYigDBFc9egsZeFJ3I9wkXcLG1ZiEwgzXSth@Xy2mY7ftM0YC/RIcetHeRZfzzIMrpVwxGiWbJR/Yqy4CJk5c89goG8gelvUWAtceKBDkT3Owxwb1lCbo3DZngRo9xxNZjsFhBQ49Ny4JdJgU7uLXpXE/QigRvJasdEREPQKQBLzqmw9dLcIAthZFDaA4l1CQVU/RYkJSxFCqKApSuXBRaRk0iohG2dLB/Bf2E0VXW/Cqao96fOIYBswupidmEYFfUhHKUViA6ieJWGoY3/xOKR9HYIXZk0S30st@Jukf@eCf6263LaBVKdVSEi8nPpLWDjxNeRDk2Qkez10xQ8KTgN2GHlgZIjnbDS3DCUVfBsJlgpB46ncLDglWoeWvsOTUMQEzIJcnfugyxUzK7ppG0RuDcimeCRJgMVjgLp@WldHs9@fk6noH/P2FDaMiTMgvCE1ZC2zyKwxm0RanoCz9FhRlKNpufgNrghwRZ8igm9yk@F0mSyk8CA1OagZ8EtyobkDMnLA4/yijSk67@DbWrqSIZgOzJxbfnIV15wNNwZnr5bMVjXAU4b/xOAbj4NX5F9Iu29algTZLmgjEY2E4YmNrZufbQe0J8anpfxhcUUTXEnMlI4shdEuZLV8a64ONhGu1xHChUBiAN5QYke98gNZFDTsS67IidK5UTopJqY9NG1skXrAJoe33EREq6It50Jm/DTwVDCBbl4FftgSOCHq9Zh1z22p/4hgNCC0byIx0PlKFaMFHa7apl7TtMvoeLNf7fMknv/ovwMopjZKrg7T7kCS604icmCCZGbRbMvpEL@Tg1k8QWJMsUGBue7AvXK7sVF0SoEjxt1QjRq7qTazYu34GWaDzParW5JhUHvRpx@R@u8qBCkFe4yASaHrtGn9fTbugIR3@8gkRQqNk1eP0GLWOPH7OaalyPB0teBFedJ6Nh/4fxE18GCT1j96xpEC3lmjSDvL4AkaZr80wpEWZZOFJph8KvaDtnQys8qZWlHHz2a5CUAhecRQRvKZ2AfOUtfyu6q@nKW0gyONpSNJPJxx4mLgrV2pvooCWNLjdWV5UxxRvjV42fllEng6FCYwbzLFm@lOY64Gm6@NyJy8Wix1QS0lLal/nKsn53LKvmAxqp0XEKQA0bj3w5dDISFj/@EE@0ccgu6hkNx@uJIUeaPZFzVvOmG2MhyUz6oZH2PUQwaBbEtbNzb@R1VZy8TqK44/U8v@uNPV99fog9fz2e@CaPvQOtxQfCSSv0bQs63dZPiS4rwlidhKmrMWVl/GsaZhy3E8fQ1TITKHfivY0WfBYFLF2UkK5g5oKmfzzUWfLA8@91JMdDsRaag9cmmbxJYmuSWVJOFzjLwS1fDyb3o@dghdyaQe4Szo3x6ZyScu4snJVB2OlwyNwJDhFMHTc6eSdXKnYFQqj7ALbvrwHNwa3AuDZs2IJOMUaJ1Udh9B8kjGUU29LoH@0kjf7RdtKQs@TltMh4UCiJMHQGLCrycDHfTjr9HaVDaW3Hb5JTfzs59b@2nA4fJidAE4GzNKI6Gg53Mx0csKW49GT5HyXPdjOgw//WgA63E8zh1xbMkwcJZhatolloxPLdTjL5bjuBqEnoV1vP9PNOtvPka9nOG15cDeawAcoI69TfRlxPvra4fnuQuMJPaRLTkaBtRw8xpa2tyUyZ8Sh/qPQOD/8S8R0ebim/3762/B49zA8ms9LJH452F92WTlDNRP9IHiq3R3@J2B5tKbVHX1tq59smjztk6YbzK70CRWhWsGTuUHxXsjsoY3GsaKfrz74ayc7B5Z2Uh/FsJ7rVOZ4metBANO0v8ILBHMQ9gMs/lukiCnhhEZzE21BqH38Qjb3atmyE2jq@h5pjvTXjdP6u9414uTB1m3zXC/yCt0/FFY/ZMRhhuMw16T0WXcYJpSqJ9CXKG5jTo7XFhvcfYfOpjZqDvA5up@v7GSCWqHkw1Dy4a9CQbOdoK9gjgj3eCvaYYJ9uBfuUYL/dCvZbgv1uK9jvCPZvW8H@jWD/vhXs3wn2@61gvyfYH7aC/YFgFzXdXYTxfZZvjrGrXlceMCiT74EyQdO6V3W3dxEGA7RazRqD49G9ueglbNLzMOUAHyWxiZK7xUgrQtLZTD1y3eMixOHGSoMTg4k6dLirQZGI0yCIczl4I1iCpMqYJzYrH7Vm0Jaw0cGtwIGHIQJcXieIZpp0hpPqk7GZugNs2gKq6y8IpU6M@7GmG7TQe7RDuWMQ1rIsiP@4WPFJJ6DBjW8F@By8MFo7kkeUpzijuC@gi4VO6td0pkKDWoE9p9ahfLMOiRO3ryRbLTLwwGgBQmB41E4pSw7NnZWvd49KZnanlJEjhex/RD4lYej/z@wUi/6JzckSiDhkq4p@/hzGSBEELQEkz1Ax0YJvyBLD4mMIHmUoQ8uqtn6Ea1r3v2raBzrxXiqgrR46ATA1FPfd60UQVz9RfYYY8RzoO3E1yvg4jNAKQZ21eKuqCBsrPbQBbDej787Mmbh1SyRnphxIoXRSlpdZSKzG1QtT5GotB7f06wZuOk/HZmUKqxpPt@cZTPpask2j72rOAAv7R8DDI53UaPhneGhfH22zmfXF9YQz7rwR1EE1PHUymagIyMsrHw9cUcB1xqgexZugxhtdaLPhWFvfYclvoRzmHBynOdOjleh91114FwuQKkwDGRzCqMAZJ/0k9RxT0VUcJt8Os0txQSZWq@aVgcLgkza3iw93tJzCU6Dvr1J9D@as9ll9rZWGfn9T0NUg5qZMar8ttArsaeUqQPFU8YUvFkyaaYUhnmGIxtbMFIswwxvNyFokQq/agd2yuJrrRGyvSQWeM1WHgrfk9wTl0w0@R3tAjdjyP@h5ZAnGZv4pE1JXIsvtb3SsDrkdtDXEaicH9OtcD1Wqs92W7ehO/9PkNnZwN87EakjDBu/N/xlbuv@FN92WJ//c7fZsg/USqndN15r5vccPxFc7@KvDI9ljckwrSngvk2XKRQ2eHTxGslZNZtQKGnKTGhygVWDOwVWHqthe/VECHlmLBKA@GjtGxmHTfmnjedR2x1HEvvSvTBCB3mX4E8f6yJxS9NYOG4hylxOn@7K7beKWrRRNVW6Cw/XiSWnS0KfMkr5G0diHURHWcsWwCZPOX1FqBSqEdKscqgSKZTl6P3JLOO7gj1KbX5IkFaeBkAVyrI6M1kYTZcEHVmS9lKURw@2KPuyiCra5lINKMkQd60iVsLb0dCKntUtMJexYw2KjIY@qOfSnTA2s8hx5HoFrPlMtLVr9CYt68juMZyeiaES2rAUal2d4DjmHWRTXEH6tNiKS87qSTWTg@KkAppCi3Yh/r3USZgpbSJrjXZR9HmV5sVmZqQ6QqtgqNVy0GKoqCWUZF2GSS0H2SszV80TR/OxMF9BUMIrKJ@cs3OKHqkZtyLUIAbgyK8OUEqtgGVWxmlhspylUBIRAA5K0zeHnrr2At3upig35ohP1LPaLU1jwCeNtjoTVVhTj7p7DucePqfFcpkna54a7krL9gbAihtdJmdab8OiYTV3iXu1IHFFDcf7CyiJO690vGpIM4zslyKZEw0UzbBh7obZLCk5VPOriN0PPRQMvFZqGYGAGvtg88EXTQE3ihVLYPUXki0phplUDqIPPtQg@1yr4XOjoc21K980co@uxhR@@GnCvLSXRVYFa@Cf1usAR1uQa5TMVuoN5tABHgn76nAUDsm0UQeSbAjw8EHJvIsxmVGVJP5FnxeGeM3IgMxV3c6aVkX3kuajVZflNJG4hiIZgwUuFy3YLhDMUx0VrKn4@bbfnZRwQNjv7IRcJmQ8eCOPNZYw/abL4zMVVypalfKJ@T7EppoNJ1waRRsqzcSY0yL0NWwPpSvQWBJmKGxUcR6qmoyZRuyuqI1@skjK30XCsMYpFq6cNa5dfFb@gNUPzCFG8SyCTBa7D72nbTjQQ3E40ts0z7kkzrMzhuYexS36E9scrT5egSiJkNK5lH396VpJnSKbkQ3/K5MPKPcSC7YJUOw1YN0514qFoLLacmXgrOWkjRCQiicDnD6Kilc5fZQKh8xwcC1atULgKCNsL1eHW9IvUSKyj11YvMU6MlDuQ0GO2VHMLlP/gN7220aeP2m6JtlwnoIC7yzrC4oklNQInPQYKLPhFozTsesKwxN8nHBM6JAaKcxsqnon0pk4HJUCWo1Gk7FltYnbtX2CbdXC7iVSA9ciLIU0hbv0UecQIOuur@bWaf2pCa3pObC@2dgxS15tnYG@fioyLVxtoXeC8MkD2SRaC08xW@Ty98bA8swgoWdVziwJkKjGX7/7A783CLBt8zKICtnRyEmDD6McXP4/PmWdJx2PwnwdrT0N9xG09LgGttoiWAsUjyWz9IQbBkPfRazXFzWop1YxZ16Fb727oFaNvLdRaRlIWchmiZNrmrL0zF9tWOSm3g/p0Uzxv2kry@jaSEOLrKEJGm8cKInrmaAVum0Z7p90xHhinPJZ@dy561UMu7W8PkSLYXxoyYvYIt62RcIrGrcXu7U7Mnshg35K4he1HulBaRjdRMu7A0CWtXh91VBYkb/ysSzkiEN/kqMhl3xJKhhpXheu0@2Vaho@KWoE8JhDvEKXcMFAvRJFBKxIx6gYs57TNmMWtZ8wORuS@UWi0zycm3ZCTfsSOyZtDHzEodanVzU5TBeamDnNDMNTc7WrkkXqg4byXa1h8bRsWiFmHEmNkBFd5Y@eIhtO5GElDvoH5Z0lvbQaDwb7lbPffi8didtvkQ@y@HkL77qGPIjW3IV@LJ7Py7IayqRNWKf8XwnBcPHlbKS/p4fBh2h3Zg3LCY3N2Zrumyk3R63eGiihdQyaD3wE9fwrsR1RD330K5eIkgREr8SFHJyBA@0KKVg1B6t6nCfSmwTjBCK9Shpjt6O9NT8IMd6zHZe1WeyMTzCz2gwbz6Oeuig/z/sbyzPLdtjrZWPC7DjbEntuqe3AON3CouBUBpnkHt4hLPcARMNhCWx1jAWpb8Q5/8BaNmDGLcj5dhOL0di3fB3Y8fEJiaferT2FQkkWoE5C9fb/BVKR8cb7qGybJ843nPTbH9XMxTO6rT@/Nq/XAt5ls3q8FZuGI07z5rw9VLL2YUZm0giQttxVal9IFlTo@ifnE6K65u5Cn35YMNj9Xw00GMa@ndVm9sG4I@ncolztC8t9n9vPD6uZGzivcOh1JJWk@CsbSCqClkqgmKUW@mvgvskvIG@B/OiqTYqu9z1MZnqM4LfHNmArQVuIAg7EkRONo5XRZjXcGl4O8nAohd8CHHuu3dRyY6/VX3knbnFGSPVvstfckckBuBhgSdSGQO9@xvFysv5Uzo6sP5l7H4rGc49PBWKuYleHaJAKnOe5BxJyKXSLYcfVuz8CvhdhlJGi6yHtmScJvLqMwNwkUVrSg7AvQqpw0aVZiB8uTbyB/w0eQbNw90O8greMEYoOo5WKePjrg4p5E5Sl4s8KdAi3ecM07MnR2u9bFTC0HaJ7@/tm5G@t2pcB@fk5RCR8Nfjkajb9MTtu6RQYsoxqQlbkvTvt0yG1srsz5ZSi0jfjbqH4onb32yyTLwqAQQ0CtDm7VjgAYsRrhk@Znc9w18GV4zkZJShvcMUwJ@U7OphkHipLFHPR4FtItD6cdWxRb4xrR9iGRxEE21g1oZxHSuPgsnnkVVzjRcglb3f4CJmv/KoYD9f1VaxVm0wT/ZAt54hz/joY8oGHC9mGbAyJheHIGiCK8CIBdG14HgMvLAUf@jXy3D/scfEEN224d5cDpXLFvZOXCgP0ozDHHXfFTjClxQn/cBh/ZzMh61bIxptKlM8gbrcFmh7HFp5RHOLI1RyC2VO/EA6nOU71Bc/h@PBZ/qKQ/3zeG2UzKtz5zJ1T3LovwLcgUXaKN@alIHJXOzjHy8NlPAP3@cxx01LAe88pi3v9eHE2a2ODQIDL1b33fDdfNK4nkSvTUDWTtNs8m/pspdMRzg/id04hIoYOwRFUvUXf/FExSLmakVMhNqRl7E/2HK@yMVnuK07bYnYgvgP3ypb/6Dw)

Answer (score 2):

## Triangular, 3 bytes

```
\/<
```

[Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular) is my first attempt at a two-dimensional esoteric language. Code is formatted into the smallest possible triangle - in this case, a triangle of size two. The IP starts moving Southeast from the top of the triangle.

The above code arranges into this triangle:

```
 \
/ <
```

Commands:

- `\` direct IP Southeast (towards the `<`)
- `<` direct IP West (towards the `/`)
- `/` direct IP Northeast (towards the `\`)

Comment: I think you mean a triangle of size **two**.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh... duh.

Comment: [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0f//38A "Triangular – Try It Online") with `,/`

Answer (score 2):

## [Thotpatrol](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thotpatrol), 78 bytes

```
JACKING IN
  a.txt
REPORT UNPATRIOTIC ACTIVITY
```

A simple self recursive program that points the interpreter to call itself recursively. The assumption is that the program is in a file called "a.txt" The call is embedded in a try statement to suppress stack overflow warning. The structure is as follows:

```
function a:
    try a
```

Link to implementation: https://github.com/MindyGalveston/thotpatrol-

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), 2 codels

[image]

Can be interpreted and executed using, for example, [PietDev](http://www.rapapaing.com/piet), by either

- setting the canvas' width to 2, height to 1 and coloring the codels yourself or
- clicking on "Open", setting the codel width to 25 and uploading the above image.

Click the step button repeatedly to see the program rotate and loop <s>or the run button to freeze the page</s>.

Edit: [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##lZK7bsMwDEX3fsVd2qGDIMl6WEGXFA6SoEnQBPmAyK@iW4Z2KfrvLmnZsTNWIARZMI/Ie3n9bL66Tqa1QB5gJUwD4yFryAgVeZdyjBomwOQwBlYD4v2wFsPaborTQw9ShJpS9Oys@s9suqEXTYXgCXW3diKhNKFUmBEMnIdRMDXv6bJUyFvIEm0FpwbUx3K/TKyYUBlXZSeUlnAZ90KNEC1d@gjtxtpkQqHanPZC/DzROaEMa2WG39qZPpTS5CPKIhvvm3jX4Le8oSyh3PhbFhHGdOXhJUKFMsIqZNX0Ci5CLJhzFeL4ckM5bjA5WMEaGIuaHKw4tEU0HG07RAiMJQd35xUhHlNlx4TyhGotdLzzzpFQJc8GuU8@Oseae9K8lwLimQnl27oQrfith6ryaRhiPzyGjaPyZI7aswVKTq8onVA0TsXyLESVykqowMNApreoKZccn2lCwXDbTy91SrtmYSfZt6tDIV4vCRXZQRrgfy3RdX8)

**Edit 2: Just saw that someone already [beat me to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60102/72779).**

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC V2 (Commodore 64/VIC-20), 6 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 0 GOTO
```

or to save some typing (not actual bytes):

```
 0G[shift]O
```

which uses the keyword abbreviation for `GOTO` (may also be typed as `GO TO`)

In Commodore BASIC V2, GOTO assumes GOTO 0. Byte count is determined from `PRINT FRE(0)` on VIC-20, default value is `3581`.

Answer (score 2):

## [beeswax](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), 3 bytes

```
O_O
```

or alternatively

```
j_j
```

or

```
>_<
```

All three create two bees that get reflected back and forth indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80 Machine Code](http://www.zilog.com/manage_directlink.php?filepath=docs/z80/um0080&extn=.pdf), 1 Byte

```
0x76
```

### Halt

When a software HALT instruction is executed, the CPU executes NOPs until an interrupt
is received (either a nonmaskable or a maskable interrupt while the interrupt flip-flop is
enabled)..

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Btw, if you want to improve existing answers, just leave a comment with your shorter version.

Comment: Thanks. I have not found answer with Halt for Z80. I'm not sure that [this answer with reset](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/59572#59572) is correct for this challange

Comment: Oh, I actually meant [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19791/64121) unrelated answer which you tried to edit

Answer (score 2):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 6 bytes

```
REEReE
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#FB)

Begin loop, end loop. No need to explain it much.

Also, for fun: `REE ReE reeE` makes the permalink [#FBI](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#FBI).

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

```
{
```

Auto completes the while loop and runs it infinitely

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 41 bytes

```
   ^
  / \
 /do \
^-----^
-^    -
/1\
---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsSszNTNEtTs5IzU39/19BQSGOS0FBXyGGS0E/JR9IxemCQByXbhxQTkGXS98whgso8P8/AA)

Almost a straight translation of [@JoshuaTaylor's Lisp ten-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/59378#comment143074_59375).

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 12 bytes

Different answers are posted for PHP which use loops or labels, but here is one which doesn't use any of them. Save the file with a single character name and then include itself. For example if you save the file as `1`:

```php
<?include 1;
```

Run with: `php -n 1`, this will go on until PHP goes out of memory or max execution time reaches.

Answer (score 2):

## [Plumber](https://github.com/Radvylf/plumber), 7 bytes

```
[]
[[]]
```

This is the shortest possible infinite loop in Plumber.

Plumber programs are divided into units, which are always two characters wide (and padded to two with spaces if shorter). This one consists of three units: `[]`, `[[`, and `]]`. When a Plumber program is run, a `0` packet is dropped from all `[]` on the top row. This packet can be picked up by a `][`, which pushes it to the sides.

A `[[` will push it to the right, but it continues down (and is destroyed upon leaving the 2d space). Likewise, when the `]]` is pushed into from either side (left in thus case), the packet is dropped and destroyed, and pushed back to the left. The `[[` pushes it back to the `]]`, and this continues indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

## [I like frog](http://esolangs.org/wiki/I_like_frog), 13 bytes

```
frog like i
```

`frog like` says that it is going to based off the parameters, go back 1 instruction (which is this instruction, creating a loop) `i` is the parameter saying how many instructions to go back.

Answer (score 2):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md), 8 bytes

```
@0
00
@0
```

Marbelous is a language based on marble machines

- `@n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) is a portal which teleport the marble to another portal with the same value
- `00`-`FF` initiate a marble with this value

[interpretor](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 15 bytes

```forth
[begin] [again]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//RyelpmfmxSpEJ6YnAun//wE)

Shortened nonForgivingJesus's answer using square brackets for looping directly.

My first Forth answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [C#9](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9), 8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

In C#9, they introduced Top-Level Statements which means one source file no longer needs any boilerplate.

Comment: Welcome to the site, nice first answer! This is the shortest C# code I've seen in a while :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 14 bytes

```python
{*iter(int,1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1orsyS1SCMzr0THULP2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

**C(gcc, platform-independent), 17 bytes**
Highschooler here, finally something I can do.

```
main(){for(;;){}}
```

I read somewhere that this is the least bytes for an infinite loop, although I'm not sure.

Comment: The least bytes is a 0-byte C program compiled with GCC-EFI.

Comment: I believe you can replace the `{}` for the loop body by a single semicolon `;`

Comment: @Makonede wait THAT was possible?

Answer (score 2):

## [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 5 bytes

```
\>1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P8/xs6Qy/D/fwA)

jellyfish doesn't have implicit output, so nothing is printed here.

### Explanation

given with positions.

```
(0,0) \ iterate the following function: 
(1,0)  >  increment 
(0,1) 1 on one
(2,0) till 1 is reached.
```

Answer (score 2):

### x86 machine code - 2 bytes

```
 6                                  .loop:
 7 00000000 EBFE                        jmp     .loop
```

This is a same code as :

```
 6 00000000 EBFE                        jmp     $
```

### x86_16 machine code - 2 bytes

```
 12 0005  EB FE              JMP     $
```

Tested on DOSBox

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: Typing this in Unicode yields `ëþ`. These letters (AFAIK) don't have a common language, but pronouncing them how they normally would be in their respective languages yields "yohth", which sounds sort of like a British person with a lisp trying to say "yours". :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Locksmith](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Locksmith), 4 bytes

```
0156
```

0 pushes the next digit (1) to the stack, 5 acts as a label, and 6 jumps to the most recent 5 if the top of the stack is non-zero

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 3 bytes

```c
W1N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCeS4Kq2bGSKZCFFHYEsJJcP4AtClkG1suyTZFiOcH89193zopFtcpe75YNlzTzd0/1MT3ePifu3cfz9VZrH2XKS7JXVJJ2/vhu1zZEsvWkMxdXjIlkBFWl@2xiq0pnATJJpmicsy1g2z2/po61HP51@/sD8@vXi0zkL6te/HZyz3fr16PQd@6V@Pf/M/Bp8dHJhYE8/nxjQz6cfDi7@apec2fjRZf/y/8L17MEFLCsm47uoYA6vBUwU2KpVjEZst547PfyCkzlMkkffGH7f21vB4DKEQTcBk2UcgQ3M27OzEwLhxz45OUDfDEPO3wsAyBu23kfZMuH8Mh/zdpv8gF25HIfnncOzI/v7F//0O4dvnaGYdGA2iWYsRNiw3QZdi6goE5uzp3YrzSuWDtstGCW9LnOmyzyGERKO4b2aLdxykV8G4/DJc71n0NFKQR3h4enhwJs3qD5dsIe7tErKRRQn7RZ8zxIbxkHcFma4rHNVXeVX06uCPT1fjm0@eNXhZEornTJbWxsy65XFmVChRrdg9CqH4V5PjICdrSQrE3PgWZgT3yXx72w6L1i@nN0kRSntYXZaTtLbtFJaYXV0x3e1R@LpMN9jPeZIy3s9zvrM8ixYAi1NOSuSalnkTEWCEKNgGK7acB8VaXSTJcoKMCKbPySFHcN6yhD27RtTxsX0FhMRXy0u6Uk3uJ6Gvgt7FOrhFevwbMkYBEg@WS5s3FImOe0zeFs3WJz0UmgTZlxZVm1TxxKbBsLggTaKgRLIDPAdLFtEZcWquwSURUUFYLkBjmIUNzTm6Iky1jgwLxoLnz6njW7VZJD5GLpVOs/BbIxYbwymxYqRcrlYIOFcRZUaMek34w9oN8hGHSqUFznEMWQpjFxpuWDlk6WPshg4wgHMWAPMVGimCjJKcsJVG@1GU6Msm8f2ruf6HB3EYe0EOZgvsywqHk1H6/05N7bno6UtowWl/DJfkaYlfFxCJoVNnh4cvn13/dvWya9nhsOm2pt0o95gXe9WQ/H744sXNFZJQSqjfML@sYzUK6q9N5fYWV9CEPDe0lwcb@CChHebwk3MM6XKYpnjDg1lpnWqeWmrXEkHAEK7SmNGszfL6WWwO5Z2iI3uUnrQBpQLOFbV1AYo@L@dZZOOyjtUaVxUsqoADoVWIGqYWL@B22P@TtNPdB5jcZ91qmKZdCAG9TiGJIxPI8ggONHByOrUJKCf6LssNkTH17fzeQYzN00GXvS1dutHDjk/75Fp5s2amRnamP@pNkLQVvMss01TXea5UCH@B5PzNZOxCn84@HjqYi0WgQavx5e@53kQTuAKvKq3Mv1n8rVi@BgaMWp4iwzAm4sfAX3uhL4q6ZjhsKrjgz4D8dgBwNHxyaHDppAchy0d2nI9TMNxtHCzJKcOwOBK9UKCMzh3L5GxKoi1CUsbFhw7pV4CavEecTGEopLipM4b8WyxsgNEUjquUwjSlI5xmfIhreI72wFm1lon4IjJvxjrlHVgDRiuIgAhEorNF2Rh3iWnpHrZ/jVClg@pCtcI6jGrAksXtZmXY/5Uhxk0UJTbxcLnsHBTdwEZz@Zd748p/NXAjwAEpYKi26TKoEG0u7SVXdwgrJCTNOfDdGrbtJ3YD8R3BZriQphyLnY59IYbTYUHpy5ArHco1hONIyYDycdQmYscydRZW/m2dkfg9cy7egYlTYY15howGAwQfuFivkhy21jY7RQd6hTAqnAmCiWEYxh4u7/QuOwtbNGQTMH0CToFHRxErIvtHcChdaA3XAOWVtFlwyDrhdQJ4YEFJJd0gx5ai6hGDU7IArNlqWmsPfkNPEn@gC4OD/uan1uNTad7wBYmsjXgyVp0wCpZkxcD/qs1kG3ihjjWiU8WoM4pdcU2liCuatBotMvrvnItGyrRC@oN7e0SBZtnYV0Y6ITOx1wXEinv1FA1gdUliXKp9qUKJkuWuQMytUgWzmoW8GCIew@SJvazQR3rduny1O8jdCy63CvqtlvKrO3XTgn22PDGmTpqhWH@sirV7uuYEK2eMKinDaI0CekSMzKGlrE9opluNXdb3EQRDW0/U7EUiD3H9pcOg9gAQuEwnvJQeRnwzaEaR5V6yKbT79U0cfUddXFoRl16VjJHSL/6a9FpRDt26k17hZBT784GFlar8wYenDUexL5uYmG2wTWHMKGphASgBNmUIUPrCu54CBr2@6RPEkUVc3WjBaNV4/S/@SExbzYTs/1Doe3NQn8nNhsOiZsDjQWml0NJu2A9ZH1fs0xYoN6Hc9b34Yz5Jjj4SfQepMcGNgwRSusO1IinKCeig5EnuQ44dStOSPy3Vw8ETZIrcEWgBIslBr7jjeEuKRKrZPkcWug0q9KcPUSPwBubzOFKWiW3SQEyi3me5FUa4SUCTvKcPSTsLrpPACgVIbxisyhfQvg8vsZR9O4GGQcqiIlymVX4mwEtrhOegvRNjFpyhTJTTkNW1KO@l5Hey4Zo2F4D5dH1PMqwNj6C1/kkSybsujb7Wmt5wm@iLzMWqZ0ZobJ@X71zgrck1DFMf9Z5cI@CdaXwYdJr5MWwmRX3mXn498xjgKID@RtblwnAPmv0iTToMiMbog5PSKqSG4g6gNitEKqN0QWN4FBiaM0n8wGbJbN4gWGWs9H1/v/ryuhPcGWkXNna4EsofZGu7L/Mvlh1g8k4vc8agEAjAlVAtzbZWb9o91TmMRVo87p1@kNfNtWGfVNSphIt/@2/kZc5yFCj5YfWwEQ32txVbFhn3eb0T99jVG9bX2QQ12pcZnQqJAxqHIcNaSNNogQiej0tJkz@Au6JH73MRrPhHTN7Fyl23OzaEWrI7weDHYOW9@LKEBodVs8sQOtXpFxePFx9FnYaDe2FIHpF6XC15AWbSt4O131AoKV3afA/NERoGD5xK2Ld/Ot2yOyNAvAQV@352CRRgyDiX0zSgxA9eRJg9UkyjSBJgmeqw0xzmEwn9BtSFFdQpqzt2MKeE0c4e@ESi8p0DYRuUP6OMIvSHJtVFhW3sUtKHQe@33P8tYqul/gvG9sja5rXuOfv/wY)

```php
# pretty straightforward
WHILE 1
    # The official name for this builtin is NULL.
    # Because builtins are determined by the
    # first character, I can call it NOP.
    NOP
```

Answer (score 2):

### h, 20 bytes

```
8,2,9,4,9,6,8,2,-1,0
```

Neither the language (by Nerdaxe) nor this answer (by VilgotanL) are my creations, but I want to publicize them here.

h ([link](https://esolangs.org/wiki/h)) is a programming language created by Nerdaxe which is quite limited.

Here's an explanation of how the program works through pseudocode similar to subleq assembler:

```
neg1 2 #acc is now -1
zero 4 #acc is now 1, the variable zero is 1
zero 6 #acc is now 0, the variable zero is 0
neg1 2 #acc is now -1, go back to 2
neg1:-1 zero:0 #variables
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Daoyu](https://github.com/Kaynato/DaoEsolang), 1 byte

```
><
```

Each instruction is one hex, so two instructions fit into one byte (0x69). The `<` increases the operating level (a number that affects certain commands) and moves the program reader to the beginning of the program, but only if the op level is less than 9. So, it's preceded by the `>` command, which decrements the op level (to a minimum of zero).

Answer (score 2):

## [Minim](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minim), 4 Bytes

```
C--.
```

Decrements the program counter, which is incremented back to 0 after the statement finishes.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KakkoiiChris/Minim)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
{
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'm surprised nobody thought of this answer already, so good job!

Answer (score 2):

## [KonamiCode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), 12 bytes

`v(^)L(>)B(>)`

`S(^)L(>)B(>)` does the same thing but isn't shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 1 byte

```
?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/3/7///@6jgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 6 bytes

```rust
loop{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZ/T8nP7@guvZ/7X8A)

That's one very fast loop

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 3 bytes

```
1><
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/9/Qzub/fwA)

### Explanation (because i can)

```
1    Creates a 1 bit, heading east by default
 >   Sets the direction to east
  <  Sets the direction to west
 >   Sets the direction to east again, creating a loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/blob/master/), 3 bytes

```
W1N
```

Epic W1N.

Comment: [this has already been posted btw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230258/92689)

Comment: @Steffan Should I delete it?

Comment: [No need to.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/92689)

Answer (score 2):

## [[min]mod](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(min)mod), 2 bytes

```
IS
```

Treats the instruction stack as an instruction and calls it recursively.

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/bYSVzEgnq)

[Try it step by step!](https://onlinegdb.com/XXb9u56MD)

Comment: No need to mark it as non-competing. :) That isn't a thing anymore [since 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges). This challenge also explicitly allows newer languages in the challenge description: "_Feel free to use a language (or language version) even if it's newer than this challenge._"

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Grass](https://github.com/TryItOnline/grass), 3 bytes

```
wWw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy9KLC7@/788vPz/fwA)

Essentially just a main function that calls itself recursively.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tsept v1.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Tsept), 5 bytes

Tsept is an esolang I created; it's not good at golfing since even basic tasks like storing numbers and printing strings require a lot of instructions.

This program is 5 bytes long because it has to calculate and repeatedly push the jump offset.

```
xDDPJ
```

Note: Due to a bug in the interpreter, the 'J' instruction jumps to the wrong offset (specifically the original offset plus one).

'x' clears the value in the accumulator since, at the start, it contains the interpreter's version.

'D' decrements the interpreter, and due to the aforementioned bug, it has to do it twice.

'P' pushes the accumulator onto the stack.

'J' pops a value from the stack and adds it to the instruction pointer, effectively performing a relative jump.

Answer (score 1):

## [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#loops), 6 bytes

```coffeescript
loop 0
```

Interesting fact thanks to Martin Büttner, not sure if there's any practical use to it though.

Previous attempt (8 bytes):

```
1while!0
```

There is only a `while` loop, no `for` (though there are `for..in` and `for..of`).

Comment: CoffeeScript actually has a keyword for infinite loops: `loop 1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 12 bytes

```
while(1>0){}
```

Comment: What about `while(1){}`?

Comment: The condition needs to be a `Bool`, so `while(1)` wouldn't compile. You probably can save 1 byte by removing the parens around the condition: `while 1>0{}`

Answer (score 1):

### Rust, 17 chars

```
fn main(){loop{}}
```

Nothing much interesting to see here.

Answer (score 1):

## [FlogScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FlogScript), 6 bytes

This creates a string containing code for duplicating the top value on the stack, then popping it and executing it as code. Then it is duplicated, popped, and executed as code.

```
{.~}.~
```

Answer (score 1):

## [HALT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HALT), 7 bytes

```
1 SET 1
```

This set's the pointer to 1, this is run forever because there is no `HALT;` command. This will bybass fail-safes to prevent infinite looping.

[Try This](http://vihanserver.tk/p/vpf/?code=1%20SET%201)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)), 11 bytes

In Lua, you can set labels that can be used with the `goto` statement!

```
::y::goto y
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Basilisk](https://github.com/IfElifElse/Basilisk-Beta), 5 bytes

```
:A1gA
```

Pretty simple.

## Explanation

- `:A`

Defines position A.

- `1gA`

Pushes one and goes to position A in code. Since the `gA` pops the top value in stack, if the loop were ever to end, it would not print anything.

Answer (score 1):

### STATA, 10 bytes

```
while 1{
}
```

Apparently for loops in STATA always halt, but while loops can be infinite.

Comment: Is the line break needed? I've never used STATA

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw The line break is required, and it will throw a syntax error if it is not there. See http://www.stata.com/manuals13/pwhile.pdf#pwhile for details.

Comment: What about `a: goto a`? :D 9 bytes —— http://www.stata.com/manuals14/m-2goto.pdf

Comment: In-fact, the space after `a:` might not be needed, I don't have STATA so I can't test but I'd imagine it's possible to omit the space and get it down to 8 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 17 bytes

```
do
loop while 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), 3 bytes

```
@%0
```

Comment: This produces output. Why not use `@%0`?

Comment: @Neil Thanks, I used your suggestion.

Comment: You forgot to update the number of bytes. (The editing restrictions suck, otherwise I would have suggested the edit.)

Comment: This is at least \$7\$ bytes, as for the file to be executed, its name needs to end in `.bat` or `.cmd`. Assuming the filename is just `.bat` or `.cmd`, that means a \$4\$ byte file name and so a \$3+4=7\$ byte answer.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 15 bytes

Same as C:

```
main(){main();}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2532922 says "The C++ Standard says that you may not call main() from your own code."

Comment: PPCG says "if your code works on some environment, it's fine", and it works for me. A standards-complying solution would be `int main(){for(;;);}`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 14 bytes

```
while 0<1 do()
```

Self-explanatory.

Comment: Also works in Standard ML

Comment: Nice one. I thought doing it via recursion would be shorter, but this beats it by a byte. =)

Answer (score 1):

### [AHK](http://ahkscript.org/), 4 bytes

```
loop
```

quick and simple

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this answer here as this won't execute persistently without a #persistent directive present or a Hotkey (which forces a #Persistent) defined in your script. . AHK is a bracket based language, your loop has no defined brackets and will simply exit after the first iteration, in fact your code won't even perform a single loop. This answer is just wrong.

Comment: @ahkcoder wrong,add a msgbox under it to see it does run forever

Comment: Exactly, you have to add code in order for it execute correctly. Your program is an incomplete implementation, therefore wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
W1x
```

Basically a `while 1: 0` answer.

---

A more interesting 2-byte solution that doesn't quite fit the rules:

```
Vf
```

`f` is the current function; `V` evaluates it. This theoretically goes on forever, but in actuality it ends up causing infinite recursion in the interpreter, which very quickly exits with

```
Fatal error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fourier](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier), 3 bytes

```
1()
```

Repeats until the result of the loop equals 1, which it never does.

Answer (score 1):

## [Aheui](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), 0 bytes

Aheui is a Befunge-like, and the empty program is an infinite loop for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 16 bytes

```
main(){for(;;);}
```

A simple C loop construct.
A `for` loop does not require curly brackets.

Comment: Is there a particular dialect of C that lets you omit the parenthesis after `main`?  GCC throws an error if I try to compile this.

Comment: @Mark Whoops, I missed that. Editing

Answer (score 1):

## [CFL 2 (ComeFrom 2)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ComeFrom2), 17 bytes

```
10 comefrom 20
20
```

[Try it here](https://ddr0.github.io/side%20projects/cfl/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Carriage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Carriage), 30 bytes

```
111-@11-~!$11111++++11-~@11-~!
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmallTalk – 18 bytes

```
[true]whileTrue:[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

This is an eternal loop (which also will not run out of memory or stack or something), 30 bytes:

```ceylon
shared void l(){while(true){}}
```

This can be golfed down one more byte to 29:

```ceylon
shared void l(){while(1<2){}}
```

In the [Ceylon web runner](http://try.ceylon-lang.org/) you have to remove the function wrapper, getting this 12 byte snipped:

```ceylon
while(1<2){}
```

(I had to kill my Chromium window when trying this.)

This eternal recursion will quickly run out of stack space (about 1024 calls on my JVM implementation, with a StackOverflowError), 22 bytes:

```ceylon
shared void r() {r();}
```

I wouldn't consider this a valid solution.

Note that the for-loop (which is the shortest endless loop in Java) in Ceylon can only loop over an iterable, and all ways of constructing an infinite iterable are longer. Here is one example (38 bytes):

```ceylon
shared void f(){for(x in{1}.cycled){}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Poslin](https://bitbucket.org/thomas_bartscher/poslin/downloads), 20 bytes

```
[ .true ! | ]while !
```

This does the part between `|` and `]` as long as the part between `[` and `|` returns the true value.

`.true !` creates the true value at compile time.

```
[ .true & | ]while !
```

works just the same, but here the operation `.true` is called on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 3 bytes

```
1()
```

Any other non-zero digit could replace the `1`. This is essentially the same as the Brainfuck solution (just adding it for completeness).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>10</strike> 8 bytes

The `for(;;)` solution has been posted enough, Time for this one:

```
while(1)
```

<strike>`while(1){}`</strike>

Comment: You're missing a trailing `;`. This will produce a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

## D , 21 bytes

```
void main(){for(;;);}
```

No language used with D in it name.

Answer (score 1):

## [GOTO++](http://www.gotopp.org/index.html.en), 19 bytes

```
§1 GOTOPASMALIN %1
```

`§1` is the label 1

`GOTOPASMALIN` is a deterministic `goto` instruction that goes to the label `X` specified with the argument `%X`.

`goto pas malin` literally means `Not-clever goto` in French. It is named this way because there are keywords in GOTO++ to do `goto` at random, on a random label in a list, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 10 bytes

1 byte shorter than [@flawr's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59367/17449) ...

```
do until 0
```

(Haven't tested it in Matlab though...)

Answer (score 1):

## HP48's [RPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPL_%28programming_language%29), 18 bytes

`« DO UNTIL 0 END »`

You may remove the spaces around the « and » but the calculator will add them again for you.

That's the source size; "binary" size when stored in the calculator is actually longer (25.5 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), 6 bytes

Encoded in UTF-16.

```
到終
```

This is a while-false loop with an empty body. This assumes that the program input is falsy, but I interpret the problem statement as saying that the input will be empty, so this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Emily](https://bitbucket.org/runhello/emily/wiki/Home), 12 bytes

```
while^(1)^()
```

I was a character short of 30 for the body of this post. :/

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi, 35 bytes

```
program P;begin while true do;end.
```

Managed to beat C# this time :)

Comment: Whoops just saw the pascal solution - more elegant  :(

Answer (score 1):

## Coffee Script, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
1while 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, <s>18</s> 15 characters

```
\A=@a{a};a:\P?=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@a{a};a:\P?='
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ShadyAsFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ShadyAsFuck), 2 bytes

```
a]
```

This starts a for loop that never increases or decreases. This can also be represented by

```
+(
```

As this is a substitution language for Brainfuck (and there is a more popular answer in that language for this already), please do not consider this for the winning code.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I suppose it's because of this: *If your language of choice is a trivial variant of another (potentially more popular) language which already has an answer (think BASIC or SQL dialects, Unix shells or trivial Brainfuck-derivatives like Alphuck), consider adding a note to the existing answer that the same or a very similar solution is also the shortest in the other language.*

Comment: No need for the giant header note. This challenge specifically says newer languages are allowed.

Comment: Oh, whoops... Missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## AppleScript, 10 Bytes

In Script Editor... it's 10 bytes, which is way better than I expected nonetheless.

```
repeat
end
```

Thanks to @Mark for pointing out that the 0 byte "loop" was no loop at all.

Comment: `osascript -e ""` doesn't loop forever.  A quick check with Instruments shows that it's simply performing a blocking read on standard input.

Comment: Hmm. I'll update, seems that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## MIPS, 6 bytes

I didn't use mips for ages, but if i remember correctly, it will be something like that : `a: j a`;

Comment: Actually 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Cardinal](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 2 bytes

```
%$
```

or

```
$%
```

In Cardinal each pointer carries exactly 2 unsigned 8 bit values, one active, one inactive. Both are initialized to **0**

`%` creates 4 pointers moving in the cardinal directions.

`$` moves the pointer to x,y = active,inactive value of the pointer

Answer (score 1):

## [Staq](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Staq), 2 bytes

```
()
```

`(` jump to corresponding `)` if the top stack value is greater than 0

`)` jump back to corresponding `(` if the top stack value is 0 (or if it does not exist)

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, 9 bytes

```
while(1,)
```

Or equivalently:

```
until(0,)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>100</s> 79 bytes

```
x=lambda x:x(x)
while x:
    try:x(x)
    except BaseException:pass
```

*Note: this doesn't freeze my IDLE or my machine, nor does it hog lots of memory: it just occupies (more than) a core on an eight-core processor.

Also note: pressing CTRL-C (or whatever you have KbInt bound to) a few times will eventually cause it to error and quit. I could write in protection for that but it's pointless in this case.*

Comment: You can't use `BaseException` to catch all exceptions?

Comment: @somebody I tend to forget BaseException catches KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: @somebody I couldn't quite tell you why I answered this way in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

## GOLF, 10 bytes

didn't see a golf response

```
lx:
jmp lx
```

`lx:` sets a goto marker, `jmp` sends you to the marker. Note that the marker name cannot be a single character (as far as I know) because the alphabet characters are reserved for registers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 17 Bytes

Calls the main() infinitely.

`func main()main()`

Run online and see [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=cadfd364d9a1cfb78d406a48679ef139)

Answer (score 1):

## [JacobFck](https://github.com/JacobMisirian/JacobFck)

`:A_A`

Expanded and commented [here](http://hassiumlang.com/Paste/get-paste.has?hash=3889287da86b748251bbd701a06cff44)

Answer (score 1):

## , 2 chars / 4 bytes

```
↻;
```

I won't add a <kbd>Try it here</kbd> because you probably don't want to try it.

Answer (score 1):

## [ಠ_ಠ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7390/41247), 31 bytes

```
ಠ4ಠ
ಠ4ಠ
ಠ1ಠ
ಠ?ಠ
```

### Explanation

```
ಠ4ಠ # Push 4 to the stack [4]
ಠ4ಠ # Push 4 to the stack [4,4]
ಠ1ಠ # Push 1 to the stack [4,4,1]
ಠ?ಠ # Essentially: go to line 4
```

Comment: This needs a special encoding.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: As in, a special encoding should be made for this so that it's not too long in bytes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any characters that ಠ_ಠ would never use?

Comment: Basically everything is within ASCII range except for 益 and ಠ.

Comment: I think you can do 9 bytes like this: `4\n4\n1\n?`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, as of 11/3/15: 1 byte

```
#
```

There is no trailing space in this version. The requirement that statements have a value has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), 2 bytes

```
v|
```

Haystack is a 2D-based grid language which starts executing in the upper left-hand corner. The characters `<>v^` tells the "pointer" in which direction to go. It continues in the same direction until it hits another direction identifier or the needle `|`.

Answer (score 1):

## [DStack](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DStack), 3 bytes

```
skt
```

Language created by my few days ago

Comment: Is there an online interpreter for this language?

Comment: No, the only interpreter that exists is [this](https://github.com/alejandrocoria/DStack), the language I created it a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

## Minecraft snap. Ver. 15w46a, 2 + 0 = 2 bytes

Note that this version of this "language" was created after the question was asked.

This is using [this version of byte counting](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7397/44713).

[image: the system]

Put inside of an always active repeating command block, it will, indeed, loop forever with no output.

Comment: might want to note that this is 1.9 only

Answer (score 1):

## [ShapeScript](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), 8 bytes

```
'0?!'0?!
```

This requires the latest version of ShapeScript, since I have just implemented tail call optimization.

The online interpreter will exit quietly after one minute. [Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=JzA_IScwPyE=&input=)

#### How it works

```
'       Push a string that, when evaluated, does the following:
  0?      Push a copy of the topmost item on the stack (i.e., this string).
  !       Evaluate the copy.
'
0?      Push a copy of the topmost item on the stack.
!       Evaluate the copy.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 11 bytes

```
0::=0
::=
0
```

(Silly 30 character minimum)

Answer (score 1):

## BASIC, 8 bytes

```
2 GOTO 1
```

A simple answer, but hey, it uses basic!

Also, for fun:

## Brainf*ck, 3 bytes

```
+[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 32 bytes

surprisingly long. surprisingly, *never* ends.

```
package main;func main(){for{}}
```

Fun fact: compiling this, due to the go tail-call and `03`- optimising compiler, this generates an executable with absent `.TEXT` and `.DATA` sections.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), 6 bytes

```
(@ 1 1
```

While 1: append 1. Note that this will blow the stack eventually, since it's slowly building a list of `1`s in memory.

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs Lisp, 9 bytes

```
(while t)
```

Pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

## [Samau](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Samau/tree/master/OldSamau), 3 bytes

```
`xx
```

#### Explanation

```
`x      push the quoted function [x]
  x     execute it without popping it
```

It works like the Mathematica program `#0[]&[]`, but Samau doesn't have an iteration limit.

Answer (score 1):

### [ResPlicate](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ResPlicate), 5 bytes

```
1 4 2
```

After 1 step, this expands to `2 2 2 2`, which is the smallest period 1 oscillator. That this is true was once the subject of a lengthy proof, which was thenceforth unceremoniously deleted when I pointed out that the fact was kind of a little bit obvious. I'm sure you can re-derive said proof yourself.

Comment: So it's a form of cellular automaton?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 It's closer to being a Post canonical system. It's nearest neighbor in automaton space is probably Self-BCT, though it is not clear if the latter is usable or even Turing-complete. ResPlicate is at least an automaton with only a single state.

Answer (score 1):

## [STXTRM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/STXTRM), 2 bytes

```
;;
```

Program execution in this language is... strange.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dirst](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dirst), 4 bytes

```
lpn_0
```

Loops as long as 0 is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [GOTO](http://www.eugenkiss.com/projects/lgw/), 9 bytes

```
M1:GOTOM1
```

Simply defines a label that goes to itself. GOTO seems to be Turing complete (by translation from a Minsky machine), so it should count as a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

## [Sally](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sally), 20 bytes

```
void a a
void main a
```

Why the extra four bytes? First, I pipe it to `sally2c`, which transpiles it to C:

```
#include "sally.h"

/* {void -> void}: */ void apply_a(void)
{
  apply_a();
}

/* {void -> void}: */ int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if(argc <= 0) { fprintf(stderr, "0 values needed"); exit(1); }
  apply_a();
  {
  }
  argv = argv;
  return 0;
}
```

Then, during compilation, I use the `-O2` flag for tail-recursion (otherwise it segfaults), which I believe is necessary for consideration as a language.

Answer (score 1):

### [RPG fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG#Example_code), 133 bytes

```
H dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*new)
H option(*srcstmt:*nodebugio)
H bnddir('QC2LE')
C     A             TAG
C                   GOTO      A
```

Basically it defines a few headers for it to compile (`h`-spec) and have to rows of `c`-specs. If it was written in free format it would have looked like this:

```
H dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*new)
H option(*srcstmt:*nodebugio)
H bnddir('QC2LE')
/free
tag a;
goto a;
/end-free
```

Or in Perl like this:

```
a:;     # This is a label
goto a; # Goto that label
```

Comment: For those uncommon languages you should always add a link to an interpreter and/or show an example run of it. Otherwise no one can really judge your answer. Also an explanation of your program would improve your answer a lot.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Link to an interpreter would be hard if not impossible, as `rpg` is compiled on an IBM mainframe. A link to a wiki could do though.

Comment: Thats fine. Looks a lot better now!

Answer (score 1):

## [Condit](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Condit), 2 bytes

```
a
```

Note the trailing space. Due to what I believe is a bug, the Python 3 interpreter loops infinitely on unrecognized tokens.

Comment: Unless we're using different interpreters, this won't work without a trailing linefeed.

Comment: All Unix/GNU utilities will, as their definition of line includes the linefeed.

Answer (score 1):

## [BSM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BSM), 1 byte

A single space character. Had to use some brute-forcing for this... After about 125 cycles, it loops between the states `55`, `EF`, `B1`, `5A`, `AD`, `B2`, `D9`, `DC`, `9C`, `13`, `19`, and `F9`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Puzzlang](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Puzzlang), 4 bytes

```
XX X
```

I have verified that this is, in fact, the shortest possible solution. Equivalent to `+[]` in BF.

Answer (score 1):

## [Carriage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Carriage), 7 bytes

```
#11-\@!
```

Smallest self-copying program that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 2 bytes

```
~!
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Found this completely by accident.

## Explanation

If the stack is empty, `~` (normally bitwise NOT) just pushes `-1` to the stack. `!`, which is normally lambda execute, pushes `1!` to the return stack, which then tells the IP to go back to `~`, and the loop goes on.

Comment: The quirkster implementation shows a few non-standard behaviors that appear to be implementation errors or maybe specific to Javascript behavior. Cool find, though. Your solution should fill up the return stack rather quickly, so it’s going to crash sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pancake Stack](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pancake_Stack), 71 bytes

```
Put this # pancake on top!
[a]
If the pancake is tasty, go over to "a".
```

Yay, self-GOTOs with [#pancake](https://twitter.com/hashtag/pancake)s...

Answer (score 1):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 4 bytes

```
|-
$
```

The `|-` rune is a synthetic rune that expands to `=<($ |.($))`, a macro that expands to a self-calling function. That function returns `$`, the name of a limb. Gates like `|.` are essentially "objects" in Hoon, called cores, with a list of limbs. `$` is the empty name of the limb containing the code to run to call the gate. The code creates a core with one limb, `$`, that returns the value at the limb `$` (itself) and calls it immediately.

Comment: You forgot to make the `Hoon, ...` a header.

Answer (score 1):

## Grond, 7 bytes

```
w(1){}
```

Compiler here https://github.com/epicTCK/Grond

Comment: This is a very short answer... Well done!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gogh](https://github.com/zachgates7/Gogh), 1 byte

Another Gogh answer!

```
Ø
```

The character `Ø` infinitely loops all code before it. (from the [wiki](https://github.com/zachgates7/Gogh/wiki/Frames#loops))

Answer (score 1):

## [MNNBFSL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MNNBFSL), 4 bytes

```
[[<]
```

A bit complicated. Read the Esolangs page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 10 bytes

`f(){ f;};f`
It does end up crashing the program `/bin/bash`, but I think that's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pylongolf2](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf2/), 2 bytes

```
><
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jumper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35029), 2 bytes

```
:0
```

Move along, nothing to see here but a simple self-GOTO...

Answer (score 1):

## Sh, 17 bytes

```
while :;do :;done
```

Probably the shortest one.
Ungolfed:

```
while [ : ]; do
:
done
```

`:` is a command that always returns `0` (a.k.a. the same as `true`).

---

## Sh+coreutils, 13 bytes

```
yes>/dev/null
```

`yes` is a program from the `coreutils` package, that, when not given an argument, continuously outputs `y`  (note the newline), while given an argument, outputs that argument plus a newline continuously. `--help` and `--version` display usage and version number, respectively.

Comment: Why did you post this as a new answer instead of an edit to [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71912)? Also, your "ungolfed" code doesn't do the same as the golfed code. `[ : ]` returns **0** because the string `:` is non-empty, not because it executes `:`.

Comment: @Dennis I thought that code between `[` `]` is actually executed.

Comment: No, that's not what happens. `[` is an alias for [`test`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/test-invocation.html#test-invocation). *If expression is a single argument, `test` returns false if the argument is null and true otherwise.*

Answer (score 1):

## Parallax Assembly, 0 bytes

The effect if set up correctly leaves the processor core initialized to zeros, which happens to be a nop. Running off the end executes the processor special registers, which also happen to be initialzed to zero except for ina, but the high bits are zero (for some reason this particular CPU floats low rather than high) so it's still a nop, and loops back to the beginning by overflowing the IP register.

Incidentally a blank CPU is already set up correctly so it's just a matter of loading the null program without disturbing the state.

Answer (score 1):

## [Codan](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Codan), 4 bytes

```
«»
```

All loops in Codan are infinite if they don't have breaks. This program is transpiled to C as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <termios.h>
int main(void)
{
    int mem[10000];
    int alpha, beta, t;
for (;;) {
}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PRINDEAL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54530/), 10 bytes

```
a t
 t
 t
 t
t
```

Creates a command named `t` that calls itself, then calls itself regardless of whether the first call suceeded. [An interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54538) was posted which does not use recursion, and thus will keep running forever (or until it runs out of memory)

Answer (score 1):

## [Revaver2pi](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Revaver2pi), 5 bytes

```
TEL 0
```

`TEL` searches (cyclically) for the next `TEL` with the same first argument and jumps to there.

Answer (score 1):

## [XRF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/XRF), 5 bytes

```
FFFFF
```

Only contains one chunk, which is a NOP. The instruction pointer is the top of the stack, so it never changes and just repeats the code infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

### Sonic Pi

```
loop do end
```

I think that's easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

## [ACIDIC](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ACIDIC), 1 byte

A single newline character. In the C# interpreter, the empty program (i.e., the second line) just loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

## [Enigma-2D](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Enigma-2D), 2 bytes

```
RL
```

The IP alternates between moving rightwards and leftwards.

Answer (score 1):

MarioLANG(4 Bytes)

```
><
==
```

Comment: There is already a [shorter solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59796/45941) in the same language.

Comment: This is 5 bytes, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org), 16 bytes

```
while on:discard
```

`on` is an alias for `true`. Nim disallows expressions that aren't explicitly `discard`ed, so we just discard nothing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Logicode](https://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode), 24 bytes

```
circ r(a)->r(a)
out r(1)
```

Logicode is a new language that I made recently. It only consists of the basic logic gates `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`.

It also contains some nifty stuff like conditionals, make-your-own circuits, and output.

Basically, the first line declares a new circuit, `r`, with an argument `a`, and declares the output of the circuit to be `r(a)`. This basically results in an infinite loop.

`out r(1)` outputs `r(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Ru](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/ru), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/ru/blob/master/lib/codepage.rb)

```
¿Ϟ{}
```

`¿` call a function while koppa is not 0/nil/false. But since `Ϟ` also return its argument, it's possible to chain `¿` and `Ϟ`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Emotinomicon](//conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/), (2 chars) 6 bytes

```
ℹ⏩
```

I cleverly chose the `ℹ` character for 3 bytes instead of 4. Explanation:

```
ℹ⏩ explanation
ℹ  push the imaginary unit to the stack
 ⏩ close loop
```

It works, because 1) `⏩` has got a value (`i`) 2) `⏩` can't find a `⏪`.

To test the code, do the following:

1. Open the [interpreter](//conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html).
2. Clean the box and then put a  in it (not part of the code, just in case you have a dirty output stream).
3. Paste the code after that one-big-toothed strange guy.
4. Click on "generate explanation". Watch the steps done there (also, no mono-spacing issues).
5. Click on "submit". **Warning: the code will run after this step!**

Comment: You're shown in the Leaderboard as 2 bytes. Also why non competing?

Comment: @RomanGräf The language was made in December 2015, this challenge is from October 2015.

Comment: WHY is this question still active????

Comment: @RomanGräf Because I just edited my answer. Dunno why I put non-competing in there, though...

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 18 bytes

```
(λ()(let g()(g)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### [D2](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/d2), 3 bytes

```
+[]
```

Same as Brainfuck

More interesting version using the preprocessor (the code is actually never executed because the infinite loop is in the preprocessor):

```
(@a)a@a
```

Simple recursive macro

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 40 bytes

```
((platform ext)(invoke (stdin) resume))
```

There are presently no loop constructs in my language. Instead, we tell NodeJS (in which Lithp is implemented) to resume the `process.stdin` stream. We haven't setup a handler, but the process will never exit.

In fact, you have to send a kill message to abort the application.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 9 bytes

back to basic:

```
L:goto L;
```

^_^

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>21</s> 10 bytes

```
(#(recur))
```

After posting a question of meta regarding what's considered a full program in Clojure, it seems that the above is acceptable. If you paste it in an empty source file, it will run.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-83 Hex Assembly, 3 bytes

```
PROGRAM:L
:AsmPrgm
:C3959D
```

Run it with `Asm(prgmL)`. Jumps to itself over and over. The only way to stop the program is to physically remove the batteries from the calculator. I count each pair of hex digits as one byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), <s>2</s> 1 byte<s>s</s>

```
[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x/9/z8A)

Hah, `[` is just an infinite loop, that's its only function if you see [here](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy/blob/master/pushy_interpreter.py#L324).

Answer (score 1):

## FALSE, 6 bytes

```
[1][]#
```

This is a while loop (`#`) with an empty body function (`[]`) and a condition function that always yields a truthy value. It runs forever without yielding output.

[Interpreter used.](http://morphett.info/false/false.html)

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 27 bytes

```
 ((def x #::((next x)))(x))
```

Define a function, `x`, which uses tail recursion (via `next`) to call itself. Then call function `x`.

This program will never finish. You can't even CTRL+C out of it since keyboard input isn't handled in Node.js whilst in a `while` loop.

If one were to provide the `-d` flag to `run.js`, they would see the function calling itself over and over, never finishing nor running out of stack space.

This was a neat feature to get working in my language. Typically one would use some sort of logic flow to determine whether to return a value or tail recurse back into the current function (using `next` or `recurse`.)

The implementation of such tail recursion was [fairly](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp/blob/master/lib/builtins.js#L814) simple, but its implications in my functional language are great. My feature set is getting nearer and nearer to Erlang's every week. And that's fun.

Answer (score 1):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 7 bytes

```
1GOTO1
```

Note trailing newline. Trivial BASIC variant.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ubasic#@2/o7h/ib8j1/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 7 Bytes

```
Do:Loop
```

*Note: the above freezes Excel - the shortest Excel VBA loop that does not do this is `Do:DoEvents:Loop` (16 Bytes)*

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Sed, 3 bytes

Unlike this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59363/61904) by @Digital Trauma (which relies on [bug #21250: sed: empty label for :/b/t commands](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21250)), does only use documented Sed commands, in the same byte count.

*Golfed*

```
G 
D
```

*Explained*

```
G       #Append a newline to the contents of the pattern 
        #space, and then append the contents of the hold
        #space to that of the pattern space.

D       #Delete text in the pattern space up to the 
        #first newline, and restart cycle with the 
        #resultant pattern space, without reading a new 
        #line of input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 7 bytes

```
vwait v
```

[Explanation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/vwait.htm)

Answer (score 1):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 3 bytes

```
>1<
```

Places a `1` bit on the playfield and infinitely moves it back and forth between the `> <` devices.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forte](https://github.com/judofyr/forter), 4 bytes

```
1REM
```

Without an `END` statement, Forte programs loop infinitely. The empty program is an error, so we leave a comment.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/forte#@28Y5Or7/z8A)

Comment: Nice job understanding Forte (even if all you did was write 4 characters in it)

Answer (score 1):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 1 byte

```
6
```

TIO does not currently support OIL.

Explanation:

```
6 // Jump to cell A.
0 // Implicit 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua and [RBX.Lua](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=RBX.Lua_Glossary), 14 bytes

```
while 1 do end
```

Pretty self explanatory. While 1 is true, it will iterate through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [ezfuck](https://github.com/carcigenicate/ezfuck), 2 bytes

```
+{
```

Basically equivalent to `+[]` in BrainFuck.

`+` increments the current cell to 1, then `{` jumps back a single command while the current cell is non-zero.

Comment: The "non-competing" rule has been lifted, which means that this is a competing submission.

Comment: @Challenger5 Oh, thanks. Are you sure? It doesn't say in the question that new languages are allowed.

Comment: Marking as NC was the default for newer languages, but it was changed after [a recent meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/61384)

Comment: @Challenger5 Awesome, thank you for pointing me to that page! That's certainly a welcome change

Answer (score 1):

## Decimal, 6 bytes

```
91D91D
```

Pretty simple:

```
91D   ; declare jump 1
91D   ; goto jump 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNzsxNzPn/39LQBYj@/wcA) I mean, not exactly *try* it, but... you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fission 2](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), 1 byte

```
R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7MzzP6/z/o/38A)

Spawns an atom moving right, wraps on the end of the line, `R` simply sets the atom's direction to right after the program has started

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 1 byte

```
O
```

`O` jumps to the origin of the script. Alternative solutions: Any of `v^<>NSEW;§j@`

Answer (score 1):

## [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), 173 bytes

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><xsl:template name="a" match="/"><xsl:call-template name="a"/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Requires a trivial XML file as input (`<root />` will suffice), since XSLT won't actually do anything unless given input. You can test it [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html). It's possible to remove some of the spaces or the `xmlns:xsl` attribute and still have it parse, but most XSLT lint programs will reject the shorter versions, so this is the shortest "correct" XSLT script I could come up with that loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lean Mean Bean Machine](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/lmbm), 3 bytes

```
O
~
```

Marble spawns at `O`, drops to `~`, which teleports it back up to the top of the column.

Answer (score 1):

## Newline, 3 bytes

```
i[]
```

Same as brainfuck answer. Adds one and loops

```
[i]
```

also works

```
{}
```

works only if `loops[0]=infinity`

Answer (score 1):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 28 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), <s>2</s> 1 byte

```
)
```

This should not work, but it does due to how the interpreter handles the number of loops. With no jump points, `)` jumps to the beginning of the file, which is `)`... cue infinite loop.

This is the proper version that will work if I fix the interpreter:

```
()
```

`(` can be jumped to if all provided arguments are truthy (none are provided so they all are). `)` can jump back to the most recent `(` if all provided arguments are truthy. Once again, none provided so it jumps regardless.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 23 bytes

```
enum L{L;L(){for(;;);}}
```

Works with Java 5 and 6. Not with later versions, not with earlier versions. Just another variation of  [my "Hello, World!" answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140175/16236).

### Proof of correctness

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
$ cat L.java
enum L{L;L(){for(;;);}}
$ javac L.java
$ java L
```

Then it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 9 bytes

```
while(1);
```

Infinite while loop using 1 as a true value

Comment: It seems I have been beaten by 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 50 bytes

```java
interface J{static void main(String[]a){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwau6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzOi2/SMPaWtO6tvb/fwA)

Since Java 8 interfaces can have method bodies. As they are always `public`, we save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
ƒI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9gkz///AQ)

#### Explanation

This is the [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) equivalent of the following

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = f $ fix f

fix id
```

where `ƒ` is `fix` and `I` the identity function (`id`).

Comment: `₀` achieves the same.

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 1 byte

```
O
```

O jumps back to the origin, which conveniently is where the O is!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//9///38A)

I didn't see [@L3viathan's post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/124851#124851) so...

#### Some  multi-byte solutions

- `@1$`
- `1§uu`
- `1§##`
- ```
  3§ _
  | |
  _
  ```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//9/40HKFeK4ahRouhfj//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 16 bytes

```
> 1
>> While 1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/99OwZDLzk4hPCMzJ1XBUMHw/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 10 bytes

```
L	:(L)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/34fTSsNHk8vVz@X/fwA)

Line L is just a `goto L`, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 11 bytes

```
while 0<1{}
```

Works both compiled and as a shell script.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks, @0                            '! I'm starting to explore CG-possibilities in Swift despite of its annoying "Expression is too complex" :)

Answer (score 1):

## FALSE, 5 bytes

```
[1]$#
```

Explanation:

```
[ {function start}
 1 {push 1}
] {push function}
$ {duplicate}
# {while loop: pop two functions, run them while the first returns true}
```

This will quickly use up memory since the body function of the while loop pushes a value which is never popped.

Here's one of the same size which doesn't cause a memory leak, but only works on certain interpreters/compilers:

```
[1]1#
```

The second 1 is read as a function pointer, which causes the while loop to jump to the `]`, skipping the other `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 9 bytes (old 15 bytes) thank to @Dennins

```
(while 1)
```

Comment: A simple `(while 1)` would work as well. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X6M8IzMnVcFQ8/9/AA "Clojure – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dennins, upvoted

Comment: That was intended as a golfing suggestion; feel free to edit it into your post.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

An empty for with no condition does the trick.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome. There already exists an existing answer with the same code, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59433/41805). You can check the leaderboard snippet out to see which languages already have answers.

Answer (score 1):

## mIRC v.7.49, <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
y while (1) y
```

This produces an infinite loop when no input is given.

The code is written in the mirc alias window, and to use it, just write /y in any chat window or status window. Also note that mIRC freezes when an infinite loop is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>2</s> 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
⁹
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMDc5,v=8)

---

`⁹` redirects execution to the main program. This means the program contains a call to itself, so it runs forever.

Answer (score 1):

## [ORK](https://github.com/TryItOnline/ork), 132 bytes

```
There is such a thing as a y.
A y can z.

When a y is to z:
I am to loop.

When this program starts:
I have a y called X.
X is to z.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDsMwDAN3v4Iv8AO6ZexeoFkFR4iCulYguQWSz7t2gWwEeUe1V2sPYWNsDv8kAaHKVlaQ93jEMOFAooIzhvAULqMdcFWct3AHvUfMqvsFdN@xm67WN69k1Qco9OW/nChnXjDHMF9HsbUf)

Defines a class `y` with a member function `z` that does nothing but loop. Then instantiates `y` and calls its `z` function.

Answer (score 1):

## [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-language-reference) 7 Bytes

```
Do
Loop
```

I like VBA; it does exactly what you tell it

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 9 bytes

```javascript
while(1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/PCMzJ1XDUNP6/38A)

Comment: The TIO link shows a syntax error.

Comment: Weird. I think it broke something in TIO since my code doesn't have any braces. The error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` <--- my code has no `}`

Comment: Where does this work then?

Comment: By itself, this does not work, it needs an ending semi-colon at the least. `while(1);` is already used by an existing answer if you look into the leaderboard snippet in the challenge.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman The reason the code doesn't work is because you are declaring a loop with no contents which is not valid syntax for JavaScript. The semicolon is required so that the loop contains a single empty statement.

Comment: Oh yeah , I forgot.

Comment: This is also still longer than the current answer of [for(;;);](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59512/64505) for JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvgPBAA)

Just for completeness. This works just like [zero-byte Befunge infinite loop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59357).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 16 bytes

```c
main(){for(;;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6Lb9Iw9pa07r2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 6 bytes

```
[1][]#                            {infinite while loop}
```

This is a proper and implementation independent solution.
[Mama Fun Roll’s 2 byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74513/39407) only works with the [quirkster Javascript implementation](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html) that behaves a bit strangely in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Q'Nial7](https://github.com/danlm/qnial7), 22 bytes

```
WHILE =1 DO 1 ENDWHILE
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 1 byte

```
l
```

`l` turns the head left 45 degrees. Since the board is 1x1, the head will keep trying to move but go nowhere. The head never stops until it encounters a `@`, so this "loops" forever.

I figured this would be more interesting than the alternative solution, one space character.

Answer (score 1):

## [HadesLang](https://github.com/Azer0s/HadesLang), 15 bytes

```
while[true]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLZ](https://github.com/cevatbarisyilmaz/lolz), 9 Characters

```
lolloolol
```

lol: creates the loop statement

loolol: returns the value "1"

Answer (score 1):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 1 byte

```
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/3@H/fwA)

`@` indicates the entry point of a program and evaluates the cell to its west. There is nothing to the west, meaning it wraps around and evaluates `@` again.

The language spec is unclear about whether it is legal for `@` to evaluate itself recursively. The linked interpreter supports it. It also does tail-call elimination, meaning that this is really an infinite loop and will not cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

## Piet, 0 bytes

An empty image will make Piet loop around forever...

Answer (score 1):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 16 bytes

```
(1)DOCOMEFROM(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/1/DUNPF39nf19UtyN8XyPn/HwA)

Probably the first time I've managed to get away with not `GIVING UP`. This program goes to line 1 after line 1 finishes executing. (The shorter `(1)DO(1)NEXT` very quickly maxes out the `NEXT` stack and [disappears into the black lagoon.](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/1/DUNPFH0j4uUaE/P8PAA))

Answer (score 1):

## [TIS-100](http://www.zachtronics.com/tis-100/), 0/5 bytes

Nonempty solution:

```
JRO 0
```

It's really hard to tell the difference between "halting" and "repeating infinitely" in TIS-100, since every program loops automatically. As such, I have done both an empty and nonempty solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), <s>27</s> 13 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8lNKi///99AAQQNwaTB//8A)

**Explanation:**

Rest of the number isn't necessary, as they are text-based and pointer commands.

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0-> do not halt
  |     | |
  |     | +-> do not print
  |     +--> go to state 0
  |
  +---------> if state 0
```

Comment: Just `0 0 0 1 0 1 0` would work, but that's a duplicate answer of mine

Answer (score 1):

## [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), 7 bytes

```
!{?
!{?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run./##SyrKTMzTTc4oTc7@/1@x2p4LiP//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Backshift](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Backshift), 1 byte

```
0
```

#### How it works

This tries to move 0 1-0=1 times backwards. This does not halt, as it tries to do this until it encounters a 1 (which is impossible).

### [Adar](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Adar), 7 bytes

```
[(0,1)]
```

#### How it works

This is a looping counter; that means it starts from 0 and counts up in 1s forever.

Comment: This should be split up into two answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Forth, 19 bytes

```
: b begin again ; \ compiles word that loops endlessly
b                 \ executes this word
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WykkKSSlpmfmKSSmJwJJa66k//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Malbolge](https://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge.shtml), 1787 bytes

This one doesn't rely on interpreter bug.

```
bP&A@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$T"!~}|;]yxwvutslUSRQ.yx+i)J9edFb4`_^]\yxwRQ)(TSRQ]m!G0KJIyxFvDa%_@?"=<5:98765.-2+*/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|utyrqvutsrqjonmPkjihgfedc\DDYAA\>>Y;;V886L5322G//D,,G))>&&A##!7~5:{y7xvuu,10/.-,+*)('&%$#"yb}|{zyxwvutmVqSohmOOjihafeHcEa`YAA\[ZYRW:U7SLKP3NMLK-I,GFED&%%@?>=6;|9y70/4u210/o-n+k)"!gg$#"!x}`{zyxZvYtsrqSoRmlkjLhKfedcEaD_^]\>Z=XWVU7S6QPON0LKDI,GFEDCBA#?"=};438y6543s1r/o-&%*k('&%e#d!~}|^z]xwvuWsVqponPlOjihgIeHcba`B^A\[ZY;W:UTSR4PI2MLKJ,,AFE(&B;:?"~<}{zz165v3s+*/pn,mk)jh&ge#db~a_{^\xwvoXsrqpRnmfkjMKg`_GG\aDB^A?[><X;9U86R53ONM0KJC,+FEDC&A@?!!6||3876w4-tr*/.-&+*)('&%$e"!~}|utyxwvutWlkponmlOjchg`edGba`_XW\?ZYRQVOT7RQPINML/JIHAFEDC&A@?>!<;{98yw5.-ss*/pn,+lj(!~ff{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnQOkNLhgfIdcFaZ_^A\[Z<XW:U8SRQPOHML/JIHG*ED=%%:?>=~;:{876w43210/(-,+*)('h%$d"ca}|_z\rqYYnsVTpoRPledLLafIGcbE`BXW??TY<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(DCB%@?"=<;|98765.3210p.-n+$)i'h%${"!~}|{zyxwvuXVlkpSQmlOjLbafIGcbE`BXW??TY<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A@?"=<}:98y6543,1r/.o,+*)j'&%eez!~a|^tsx[YutWUqjinQOkjMhJ`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;9U86R53O20LKJ-HG*ED'BA@?>7~;:{y7x5.3210q.-n+*)jh&%$#"c~}`{z]rwvutWrkpohmPkjihafI^cba`_^A\[>YXW:UTS5QP3NM0KJ-HGF?D'BA:?>=~;:z8765v32s0/.-nl$#(ig%fd"ca}|_]yrqvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgJHdGEa`_B]\?ZY<WVUTMR5PO20LK.IHA))>CB%#?87}}49zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!~}`{^yxwvotsrUponQlkMihKIe^]EEZ_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.J-+GFE(C&A@?8=<;:{876w43s10qo-&%kk"'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvYWsVTpSQmlkNiLgf_dcba`C^]\?ZY;WV97SLK33HM0.J-+G*(D'%A$">!};|z8yw543t1r/(-,+*)(i&%fd"!~}|_t]xwvutslqTonmPkjLhKIeHFbEC_^A?[TSX;9UT7R4JIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<}{987x/4ussr).o,+l)(h&ge#db~a_{^\x[YutWrTjinQOkNLhgJeG]\aDB^]@[=SRW:877LQP3N0FEJ-+**?DC&A#98=~|:98yx/4u21rp(',mk)(ig%|{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnQOkNLhKIedcFE`YB@@?ZYRW:UTS6QPO11F..CHGF)(CB;@#>!~;XzV7gwu-QrrqMoJIkZF'WC$#AbQ`_{^L9wI64"VDConzl+j);JJ%qGFEZ~}]{ygwRuc8aSq44"H1Y.iV,e*RQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZTnbuoIEEafhWKCaQFsqukdYzqhBbANmGbTDITOq@fOGKLdSHel/T3Sp09nzsxSVIZrZSp9fw8rpngsGgmHmGDA7/N6aMrtcr477DarhTS/mQhjQ6973G9M/3w6fh32O@WjXqs6zifrnGQD0jgzpAV@0O/BtFYlzQ0Y9pe6rLPA5s@nzFdKJPhYVB8OeZ7pDrvbavl3ukFLP@zP6hbT1e1ivVpW5MV8Np1I41EvlerE471IpMMwTb/fy3kotzv7/p6y2bIkGTGZ4gaDzvfwBK9n3@nrcLD97m7Qn4f32/Xy7L5sbuvr2bJchnRxIuVGaVHA9M9up9YKfvjqXKFClYpcwZ63ZTPplIkgkIyXuQXOPuc7fUAya/vKKpN63XSK3U93AdO7Xx3sXl/Xloq84GYF7J4WU0gm0g23W01I91Yr5ZKTK6Se6clE3ABk7gxN@c/IfedSId1EWGTsLhnGSGZw6WP31q653axXFQW7T/PQfSgKiYHWnYHuwJ2u5N3QnbXZ4pm02ZRgglH9I3S/Xi4ur@eL2gH3zcq2lMnFzDSF9OFD5K@DHqSv29B9U1stJ/KiWJgKfDbbE1OQHv2MhNpM4MPvrXmocqkIW03arNgdndHpvLcbBVs90va9ils1/XCXfraqcW8pMnRfQvfRbCpI4yx059utXhS4V5vlhq9WreSB@zubz8V/0iO6EHMN@M9HcGa307pblYVZ95hMrvqReBeAzOex2963PraN2qpalkscOJMfjzJil9fIhNpAxg9GVsq5Z3rWkk6FCSIIW30wwavWXfPd/HJmRhjHmH7jLz112@msds3GZl2rKNKY48RJPjsapoVEuxWNNjqhYDMAW6UrlKvodLB2a9Zihq0Smu/gjOY7pm8c4IyRnGP6VSPzMrLdBDL1KpLhhv8n/Y2Ia@l3uCbNGRs441hj9wU6I110D/E22O9On50DklnMkcyiOGMFfpxN/2WrbjCStWtk3hLI3Ydk4Jqe3bfY3YLO4DWNHuh7X9W2qsJWZ89bhe4DNFLjHum0NSM9Vbwmp5aeiWL6i/sFyXxR7h3e6koxGszzKTF5ce/jJ@i0kDuQqZTQSDaH3QU@0UdnQnBNjWLNU9G6O8AZ@ATA3RD1@@53OnA5eY8Haq86t3CrikUG7hOjNNJh9wFyX8OtfoCRVUUuzmeFvDTop9NdPhHrRcN/4Q7XpBnpxx/5cmbnwnQTIcv6V/pQwO697j/dFbk056YTfoxkkgOtO9PCdK5AUblfWzXqI7o7c7ug7zS1h62@jJybkAw6w@/7rw@8bTx/JIfdc5lhOsnjVht13CpcE83mS673gsOWs5L4CYCM9gnAyBN8sd1OJdEZhTT//gSaM2rj6QxeEytl@9on6Mc@w3X4kX6fj8OtOjNp6G6xRPFWDQF/@HFDI0/aj1Q35jf8M7jV23/fKnSHW00LnUQsFn1@4Ib2I12ujMORBGdIczLBxAwR3YNpX5q@6fFgr6rqtrhm83I389ZKGg3xYVWA7lzgmPfS@mYquV5dFOuCZFiW2MLmuo97/3qeHmuHkV@sb2lan3N1HPOmTbLUqt/ffwA)

Comment: [1317 bytes](https://pastebin.com/LMcy6Zpu)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -n, 9 + 3 = 12 bytes

```
def f:f;f
```

The `-n` option makes jq not consume any input, otherwise it waits for stdin before starting the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), 5 bytes

```
1##1#
```

**Explanation:**

```
1#    [Jump to 1st hash]
  #   [1st hash in program (counting starts from 0)]
   1# [Jump to 1st hash]
```

### Alternatively, 5 bytes

```
(|())
```

**Explanation:**

This program define and execute a function with an empty name. The function calls itself. Thus, it is infinite recursive.

Comment: Whew... Aww, counting starts from 0! I thought it starts from 1.

Answer (score 1):

### [Pizza Delivery](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pizza_Delivery), 2 bytes

```
(]
```

While L is zero, end while.

Answer (score 1):

### [Nandy](https://github.com/EdgyNerd/Nandy), 4 bytes

```
:#()
```

Never decrement: never end. (0 NAND 0 is 1. Thanks to @EdgyNerd for noting that.)

Comment: [This can be 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0vMS6n8/99KWUPz/38A) by just flipping to top of the stack then looping (since 0 NAND 0 is 1)

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 0 bytes

### Explanation

There's no `;` instruction to halt the program, so it runs forever.

Comment: It may not work on every interpreter (it doesn't work on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##S8sszvgPBAA)), but it seems to work on http://www.fishlanguage.com/

Comment: @mbomb007 yeah, I only tested it on [fishlanguage.com](http://www.fishlanguage.com)

Answer (score 1):

### Rust, 17 bytes

```rust
fn main(){loop{}}
```

Just for fun :P

Comment: What's "just for fun" about this answer?

Comment: @pppery I mean that it's not in order to win anything, I'm just submitting it for fun

Answer (score 1):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 1 byte

```
|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/v@b/fwA)

or (if my understanding is correct) any other one-byte program from `@/\!^?_$<>=~+-*:%().#`--that is, any instruction which depends on the return value of what's below it, either directly or to the left or right, since in the case of a one-byter all three of those wrap back around to the same command. I suspect that most if not all of these would run out of call stack given enough time, but I don't know Perl so I can't quite tell what the interpreter is actually doing.

Comment: Perl 6 doesn't have a hard recursive limit, so it would just recurse until it runs out of memory

Answer (score 1):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), <s>3</s> <s>7</s> 4 bytes

```
01ɑɒ
10   (loop bounds 0-1, set current IDX=0, LIM=1)
  ɑɒ (since IDX<LIM, infinite loop)
```

---

7 bytes. Labels are fun.

```
|a|ʟ|a|
```

Defines a label `a` and jumps to `a`.

---

3 bytes (WIP language) (OLD)

```
ɘ0e
```

What the code does is push `0`, then check if the stack is falsy, which `0` is. Then it jumps, without any output.

No TIO interpreter yet, but is runnable by cloning the repository above, and calling `python3 main.py "code here"`.

```
ɘ0e
ɘ   ; begin falsy jump
 0  ; push 0
  e ; pop, if falsy jump; else end falsy jump
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `i`, 1 byte

```
I
```

Forever, execute the input (which is then not printed to the console).

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `i`, 4 bytes

Pretty much a terrible language for looping.

```
i""E
```

### Explanation

````
i   E % Foreach the range from 0 to positive infinity:
 ""   % Push the null string

Flags:i  % Implicit print disabled
```
````

Comment: Foreaching to infinity? That sounds like an interesting approach. Reminds me of TRANSCRIPT, which has no while loop -> no infinite loop -> not interesting to me. If only variables can be infinity...

Comment: I feel glad that you find my language interesting! (I initially didn't think it as interesting...)

Comment: (Very off topic and self-promoting and attention-drawing and... but: Do you have prime detection in 1+?)

Comment: And also, if W have "implicit print disable command" just like Retina, it could be 3 bytes XD

Comment: Nope. The Foreach loop body has to be exist in W. If not this foreaches over the implicit input printing positive infinity on each iteration.

Comment: I mean I wish there is a command which makes the implicit printing "silent". For example, if it is `.`, then the program `i.E` would be 3 bytes.

Comment: (I have already made ```.``` an inclusive range but oh well.) Adding a flag might be nice, but I am too lazy to do this... Also I am trying to make W extremely simple as well as making it concise, so I will not create the ```.``` instruction just for this specific operation. (By the way an explicit ```p``` already disables the implicit input.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102434/discussion-between-highlyradioactive-and-a).

Answer (score 1):

## [Intcode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Intcode), 5 bytes

```
5,0,1
```

This is too short.

Comment: You can't even perform a request to this server. Evidently this throws a 501 server error.

Answer (score 1):

## [Taktentus](https://taktentus.herokuapp.com/), 4 bytes

```
_:=0
```

This is jump for line number 0 (first)

In English: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Taktentus

Answer (score 1):

**TI-BASIC, 4 Bytes**

Written in TI-BASIC for TI-83 or 84 series.

```
While 1:End
```

Previous version, 5 Bytes

`Lbl A:Goto A`

Comment: What about `prgmA` where your program is called `A`?

Answer (score 1):

### [vJASS](https://wc3modding.info/pages/vjass-documentation/) (Warcraft 3), 58 bytes

```c
//! inject main
loop
endloop
//! dovjassinit
//! endinject
```

Without `exitwhen` inside the loop, it loops infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```
fn main(){loop{}}
```

Thankfully loop exists :) , recursion causes a stack overflow plus its the same amount of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), 6 Bytes

```
⌡◙d⌡◙d
```

[Don't Try it! (it will screw up your browser)](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=9Qpk9Qpk&input=)

Comment: Wow, you mastered the mystery of Integral loops!

Comment: @petStorm infinite ones that is.

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP v1.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 2 bytes

```
[]
```

Stack starts with 1, brackets loop as long as top of stack isn't 0.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=%5B%5D&input=)

Comment: 1+ 5 vs 2 MAWP (J is 5 bytes!)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 Byte

```
[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@v9/AA)

```
[  # begin infinite loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), 3 bytes

```
:;b
```

Pretty simple. Make an unnamed label, then `b`ranch to it. Not all versions of sed support unnamed labels, in which case there is a 5 byte solution.

```
:a;ba
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 10 bytes

```
why i
o no
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?K8@oVMjkylfIy///PykxBQA)

Answer (score 1):

### [NDBall](https://esolangs.org/wiki/NDBall), 11 bytes

```
(0)>0
(1)<0
```

the ball bounces back and forth forever

the ball starts on (0) then is told to move forward along the 0th dimension making it go to (1)

then at (1) it is told to move backward along the 0th dimension, making it go back to (0)

the new line is mandatory, hence the extra byte

this was done in [NDBallSim V1.0.1](https://github.com/aspwil/NDBallSim/releases/tag/v1.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pixilang](https://www.warmplace.ru/soft/pixilang/index_ru.php), 8 bytes

```
a:goto a
```

A pixel based programming language.

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
1J
```

[Try it!](https://tio.run/##zVt5c9u2Ev9fnwK120qqJVvO0SR@lls7SV@dNnHGdqd943FZSIQkpiTBkKBlT4@vnrcLHiJISATj0zNtbBLY/e2JBbAMrsSM@4@fB@Enxwt4KEh0FfWIR8WsNQm5R4TjMZK9chkLksch9W34J32Bf8F/U9ZKH4iQjtmIjv9stcYujSJyENJoTF/i7zstAj9ra2snAgb0SMimTiRYGBGgQi5o6NCRyyIYIAfabEIsy/EdYVmdiLmT7k5LvsCfdUlDTszJ5C9x8GYkBwzJ2bn6nMKzgfpopDxa8NgPGZkzYEBtx58SdsFC0Br@SiMynlGQFfl@V2YcwhDL4zYDuj9QN2IF3O@dgNl9xyc2FTR/7EyIz6UJYDow23QiKsRVp7uTDynQhwEWTgfyixmIstM929npb58rkyY8JFaPWASYMj/2WEgF65RIlRhpmKG9otgVyFR9c4Yse5WnZRyqZTZpEDDf7vDQ7iSEu918OAOd1UkOXrLQ6o8UnSg1zogxnwRgBMFscsVEyT7URVVdWdmIqo1OZ05E5o7rkkhw8AEKv4kZIyMw@J9MkIBHjnC4X/K4@cxxmeVyHkRA9K9/FIqMjNEh0GGRVMCReagSwBFW@qbqpePEoYpyy@cQea4zhigB2@bC6EcIHqjirr@PoxmBiSPgKLiEJs2TR2AAA6xkgPSZHo4ueEvVovi@SP2CujEjfLKIGOSk4YLvUx7460om6DZyUHe5ICMuBKQq4LxSLCsZVyed40csFJ1BMqReQCMEOEPlv1zyBYCq8GBXmZ1LLHiQJc5yosnJqmEWMhGHfsHzqpGYDikAQzZJ7JbQ1KqAB0Xh7wDmINPYCYQxAsoWjxxTxISVPUxNkv2p4suekiHEJF3TpCuapcqFghKs5dkj3exRdXbB54rY21HqgtoAxmR3UxIpIZjI2NXLPWgqbpX0qKtXyiA14TGuxxHTiizflJ2qwCcb0c1pSW9BUi7zp2Kmd9jkXZlu6mrwsrNgUQjN2IUFV1KTKwTBFYK4oA/SKa8b3ZzVKHZcO3lY5ieYF6iFDT6xoO5Qag71JSyMLvsYc8EU62BxkC1nkHy45@EKVa0UcPEp1Qhg1grpPTKoFhKVUf0h2VZGSR@p4hwup1aStQwsEwTd7WwtWXWVeelEPfnMDTPFdKtgiwzOGzEA7wixiJKM1MywrJo4k3POYVKGqH5KNhJnyemrZWiv1Wr6NIxZvW2H5NFqTn80NkdxWAWEKX2cWE8@9aYW7kFOriBjeYSGU4gEX8D2JZB7JiwDYUuzGVyRCdmdgMp96rG96tsx2cWw2Wu1TjnEE25uILRH8bRHYshbE3trjKEGXKiN@WayNd7EoZHL58Tmc5/wWASxSIdHW@NIAnNwX4Q8LUtKbFkehbrYSk2YAABDFLZeqZOl2PJKcu3T9ptP6aYsSVfkAPNOkggxTXk0KM4sZqUsw5G3wF2Oln8nOa7AKa9od2WKLLwp5rTwSrVObtIiqTMN2fNy7KdjlG3YUv@qPFgncn3dhfS3p9apK1LMQBM9Ba0Va@hBNdwrLrxtTm7bgNwjc3KPDMg9Nif32IDcE3NyTwzIPTUn99SA3Lfm5L41IPfMnNwzA3LPzck9NyD3wpzcCwNybgM3NgmLnxvQM/E81iAuTIz7ukFgmASa3SAyTMz7qoEvm8TGrIG7mHjzj038xcRhfmpE0ITiX2s7ZP0VG4cMSwJT4tkjLPb6Jhn7H2Rz6F@DzYYJmxDZyOXuWJ7h6vjQxQqsL1YlGJNBuNVwcGshD4w7ox6hgFJvoSUSOt1WdcGWAiSrPZRIMxrWCt7@o73SMdQTXG3da1RAl6WQB1w15czG9nl3FSGlotrAjVRVI28pbmAD3L7xwrH4Uuwb6Af7tn3LDqBz2Q1q4Kd9xHcSj/ByQdwDyL4JyG8Q5NvYFU7gXt0DyG9MQG4liUWwKXiP7Vw4kW4zeftgt7ZM0H4lVcrt2OX3gPErE4i/I8TXlwH3lyXqW7a6kdkjGUAfw@sgrDLHu8LNCWz80l8jYNCh3a4uSR84Yu7ALrZBVvoXQb87Or1RzP@aqOtrmQ/fvboHe35tgu9vxHd0fA/w/jaBZyG83@4F3@@AT@N9J9pNfAU4ReCBPF7niyPr/ZWlQvG6AAgYqGek5XJgzmVkwmVfcsluYsyEUa8KzKQ50PM5aMDHSJ4e8kmP7ZccyigcsvP9WsI7SNiO8YZUHtODKHyygsPnZh56nZEV1P9RUS9u2UyBZxdvpqiy8fQGJlSk8VAaj1@o6sf4SIhoWSZ3Xp9ljAybJGGA722Or6RoeeWWHnzW42uqc2N8QY3@iC/beSK9X3g89oXpDs5f7OAGvWTqij2csY1uxk7va@z0gPSw2heu6Q/fyWSZdGqlPRGD/vajZ6Z@l7d1dWCfWT5X6BoA@CJf4xbXqbVJW3OWkV64mrD8EllGcxpIQ4s5J45gXkS4f@1kfusZf2Qg37G0KRfZIiVmIWN3K@P41hUxvo7KtPc5FT2eoB7H3Md108@VCe6SEI7u3k8wxiKBIm3gP9QowqZlMZY7QNovgGza7c0P3PElO7@7SGT5wRd2LixPemNMc5BMCqmvcKWXzq4/0WuiHARvoA4nVQeUfYIAEcfBlJ/mvk5fdz6uCNVLU7TS@aDItVwsgJJM3huSJ8/TZlb8e3dInj5bPk85cQQWZxIJXtjL6QC6Xu7DotyL9rdEA52NO5N7oIr94rOlBsiterEvZfnrAJHQri/ZV/pdhfZvRdomhbXJol7hEiOXX/z@iZakb1qGyF6dJJqbnaRDMrBN8swvKc7pUpzFnHKZ5JTLSk5p1bmB2tB002JqzgQOt44MHI3LoxbZhoFN3/snLw8P0@bGOq9btCJUOo6XtiOURKm2KmsvI/BHDumMZ@o1ULcHYW0P220DSx8tFdUkCO5f2jz4mgjtq0KnGfThGrho3AZivlsu5kM1rsawC4E18fyS@yLkLvnB5fN6heyiQn5mUQR1NL3tGxBU3y5tlLi29ZSYiaqbthvtoS7@C@aRnet3o469h6uOobzS@RiDW9@BIobDB6uJ9v/aoIkDJuaM@Q9ha4n6wupyjP97uA70PTrQKQs9BzdmrZtJivihF7t0hEltuY4AIB/asgOYuuRD7AU1iV1qHfU6qNVHtQWhFtEHRPQGUGA1N4fCOmrS46D2z9Rze5Nzwy8Rm7Hrq@w2DNidIbtfse21L3tmq@3WVXUnNe8XWPSu3GApO6X@9nmNhZZJlQtVbBGvbabVSntekhaW5NuSde9WRTXxpJeru3pKn96ZdQqdGtJMPtaTNFvqziX5NEVKEYRMHshE@Veq@CVk2g5VbZTX90bre@PXT/GrFkdAaTgh8xnzYYvPgXEoo0o4YFNgO4Hdu13TH92s30r9eiVHc4SsZQ@BPFd2RMs8mVeasFJwpU6F9bfyCiX7VrP8jaZRCmSXYxYI8hO7GnFIPNhrE4ZxIEqfPFWzeTrxtfwH0jYasiTO@gn3WPKN65z5gsxD7k97eBLM52AcApy4CjcppddeHx8fHe8Q3fTS3WsyIf@KexPStUeFBeDKh/AFEZLvAA5Tx02/Wmg13TgsxiohAD6m2WGsvOe9xlElHa6sQjQYMfT1GKubVVq3Z1tCXB@gC9q0SlZLLtVnldwKsRuLXC9uc1GXiok/n/4P)

### Explanation

```
1J - Move the pointer back one character.
```

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code, 2 bytes

```
e7fe
```

```
1:
        b.n     1b
```

It is an instruction that jumps to itself. There isn't much else to it.

Being a single narrow instruction, it is the shortest possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 4 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 4 bytes.

- Filename: `.w.a`
- Content: none

Answer (score 1):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 2 bytes

```
5]
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiNV0iLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiIn0=)

In convey, } is an output, and ] is a dummy output or sink. In convey, all static numbers and strings continuously output, so `5]` will continuously output 5 to a dummy output, looping forever.

Answer (score 1):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 2 bytes

```
2º
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP9Gh3b9Bxr9HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ABC](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ABC), 2 bytes

```
al
```

`l` is the actual infinite loop, `a` is just a placeholder to increment the accumulator at each iteration.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBTsMwDL3nK6wJaQ1sUyduQK7cuHFDHELqqpXSpPKCKF9fkqyjrEoq4UPi2M/2i@3@2zXW3I9j2/WWHHTSNWzSSZrKdoxVWENrHFJP6M9C2Qr5A2PgRSoFAsqonxy9eJd/P0t9wmgbojeqX02r0RueQKO5JIFJ2hqC5W14ByFgK7ez61LmTsAxh/9I4PcreLXAe/fE/toepCf/@UI1VPisnF/50f8zFxHQufpVgu@tgH2WMCUCRJzWodbWUnEe1iFcoXi5O/cMjjxLwiRzljn4zT96llqF9Z7NEa/0iTkOesFhWCP8uAD/jmUH8zTZnCos2Ph30TdSb/j4Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.4.0.2](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.4.0.2), 26 bytes

```
func main:
.lbl a
br a
ret
end
```

Endlessly jumps execution back to the label `a`, which just refers to the `br` instruction itself.
The `ret` instruction and `end` token are needed for the function to compile.

Answer (score 1):

## [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 5 bytes

```
A{A}A
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#QXtBfUE=)

Interpreter crasher. Defines A as itself, then calls A, with infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIXAL, 10 bytes

```
Main JMP @
```

Assembly language. Has jump-to-self. Done.
(This compiles down to four bytes of actual code, `F0000000`.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), 0 bytes.

Yes, a blank program:

### How it works

- The Dis language accepts an empty program.
- Begins with `c=0`.
- `mem[i]=0` for each `i`, so every cells stand for NOP.
- Unlike Malbolge, the Dis language does never modify the program by default.
- This goes forever.

Since TIO doesn't have Dis by native, I made the interpreter. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZtU@JIEP6eX9FGhERkw5veYhzrXPR2rWLVkt2rvRM2NSYDpAhJKhMUF/jtXk9ekCRYt6mCTDrdTz8z83Rnpnzyug@WzT@w2eMH3@P2wuYzibMQamwuzWeUT6FebzYltvC9IIRe17jo9UhXWkoAEL74DMYsND13BOXyxmR6sxl1LWkN55rFnjR37jjQPC83EqcE7O7i2xcil5TEHWr@Bky8UktLcaueruPBaW0tpzzubvvXP3r/GN3b@/ur7jfSSF98v7n@YfS/XZJmvd6SHkAuLT9d9L8Yf1/d969vbwQGDMvlaIYeRDOOn6qfYu9/i85sNndoyIBPIlfPD3H47AUW9x07LJepY1MOtTFUSstGVS79Ka8rpCLulXL55nuv1/16SU4jeEWksnQ@sUehHo1B@CUGZk48KO2rMhBoiMzKHkS2yp3DKGcwx5/LnlmABJjjVNTGeRn35ok6IO/BiDqcyavV70VFdCK/xYozCypcW2gvms7x75dWiUj8guFuuP73/lOrChiXoEn7MLJd5OHYLgNvBBNGLcz4yBzvWUKF8cCM9pqGZ2cVw2CucWlUdD@w3XAExutrYpJUOYIKeAjhsxfBcYE38rwQ8eij98QkacZmAk2IKYE44GL34kQHBm7cSrzEax8CNsMg4D41EYstTIY72PuLJw5hADWc/iAcPA1GgwAqW6FCmswNE4ggsUfLlYxPaWrUlIef6lD8DlVNGydmTdGWyRCv0uPb@OZt@JiCrLeThx7gZJLHkedghTw3Nu/HAfPhw@aRPk83nD5dfb6@2cpqenM3JHX9zeL5wYN8KA9Ju5m3/kRrp523nqP1pOC7QmujWXBeRuZW3ryOzMd5syESFqx7aG1tINbJvVQH2xUOW7OzR0o8QXLcqbc76tarVB4g264/D1FXDsNlRVl57hjZoxpByFfWMzFsYaN9y7aWcniCYqk@1HNrXK0WCRMiK/IyDyDP3RkNzQkqSXmHSJZFCrinbNZALaJuTRP7aEhtl6Mz9gfbAnNCA2piEfHfS4gtYFPWzgvCYKgfMPyXFGlTdYOBi4WH9Yi9WXQJhn3fQ6VegAu1J6iFME80K@qsy6GOymgfn/zxsSNCKw8D93CYqD6WtKTGT0LRiLAIkTUj9VjdGWnbiaajtdEw86bUKDGJ9ab4kRcour69Xl2ClB/M7R1EHcW5cgoyDWLqlkEsfZewsCzlI3pkHllH3SOBaQ13r@6WhvYBay@TuEuwEtUMvkWqMZyeCfxZCOy0s4Hm7sDzQuBJLiMlcRzBiSnxUGupCdhB67DROfnYyoKuCqDYDnLrZ2c6T7IbU9LQp2cCsa1PD0kry0REVYkieFBtqh60aluUxHO1hX@HU/0d/u8u@3IH31xuNNO4lXwskIoqJDcbhh/dvF9SHfIArwMP9ZFdtfUOFscFFngWij6m9IzUC0xozDCLa8innWMQRykvnGCdAw3wy@/5Gae9QvJWbgUKs3yvMpISwLNFWgJRURnDuBDwfnvf/99qMIliVhvqQX5CFlGsgn29qfeUikhlD0lpQ9hOunD6LU36iCMODOn58uL@s/H14sdqFfWsdr1zguedYoOhKF1O5A1xhzhas9ZovnUdh7njcKJwwrHVq@fESUPjteH6LqQo8urmcpdvynpBgzEeKq9hkapp8fof)

Answer (score 1):

## [yuno](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno), 2 bytes

```
1¿
```

This will freeze your browser window so I took the TIO link out.

```
 ¿    While
1     1
      (1)
```

The 1-byter `ɫ` (call this link) dies to recursion which unfortunately outputs to STDERR. I might add a flag to disable that in the future.

This will keep applying `1` to `1` until `1` is not true and then print the result after infinite time. Hopefully that's acceptable. If not, you can add the `d` flag to disable implicit output, or do `1¿ɳ“”` - evaluate `1¿`, then take ignore that and take the right argument to `ɳ`, which is `“”`, an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Mascarpone](https://github.com/catseye/Mascarpone), 8 bytes

```
[:!]v*:!
[  ]v*   // define and push a new operation
 :!   :! // duplicate and execute the operation on the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Maze](https://github.com/olls/maze-interpreter-v2), 7 Bytes

```
^^
%R%L
```

Maze is a 2D language where cars navigate through a maze and execute instructions in cells they visit.  This code starts a car `^^`, which by default moves downwards.  The next instruction redirects the car to the right `%R`.  That lands on a cell that redirects the car to the left `%L`, creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/), 0 bytes

An empty program in ErrLess is an infinite loop! This is because if the IP reaches the end of the program it loops back to the start, so programs have to be explicitly halted using `.`.

ErrLess is a stack-based language I made for fun over the last few months. You can read the docs [here](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/), and I also started a [tutorial](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/tutorial.md).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VvpdtvGFf7Pp5hIdQBIJEUqS1PadOp4q05sy7XVnjYUwwMCQxI2CCAzQ4uU4/zsA/QR@yLuvbMAg4WU7FhNqnNECYOZe7@7zp2F2UYs0uSLbzL2fp88oiJY0JDMWLokCyEyPjg6mkeiy1l3IY5@YSs/mWRHlLGYcj5hdMaPBKP0aOlHyVEk6PJoGs2jRExWSRSkIT3KFHkzpJttiC/IFz1yGoh0Shk57h33W9EyS5kgPptnPuPUPPMNN/@KaElbrSD2OSdRkg1aBH5COiOTSZREYjJxOY1nnmrHH3zshr7wyZA4TivvP6cijhJa7c6oWLHEGnWI3LtchFHSZdQP5SBvNOj0xyViklCb8OiSDjt9i2I0k43kDukNribvegUUQJx3HA2QyPh2SZ7iLb4cjKtSsDp57NiJaeIyzyvhj6qaSOgcWDzyY7BDDRIK3C@gXiyimBLWjTjP/AD0U5DZNQxUA6/ALh1noPmdsRW9fQWfJBWEjcAABT/iJ2HeFoLriTqGw2aatkIlBVSaaStJzpTVTZNgmwoLpXVwe9AuCodAUSwKOiQd1Z6PoOuAZoL83Y9X9CFjKWskNgIvAz8H7vAJztFCc8VZmrlxm0SFpwG3iEcJF34C@oB3ccSFd25IonpcNyJ3h6QnHyLwR3SD2PNIyoiLz@qN24k8cmdo3tZjI@4i@0hJYsFUyCh9/RtCG0XjRlgcbI6o2mT9P0SFcMByawuSwjOLfSFk9xwM@koDoDxljGItGRAcqX9ngIOCX5DYUkSXroFy6BoW1CsZiikAQZptbO5NnKvKHclB1LP4lpQdK9JhOlm5JpFIYSfuuk5tBo0Ncq81dxUzIxi7UQw3yHBdYjib5BzDGsc22VhM/TaZYgzVGbXtxo1utDOUL408bY5O4HTZJhcKIv6HKC@jTPEvcgWNkdIuGlrMS0vMfOB25sDm0hq4GTeoGWlX1aYm0GcU5J7GdGDc6cJnIajpbU7FuYTM7PzgtIuWt9jyzm5xscWzW5bY8lS3vJOfUz94XSe/wY7/tIe@w5a3douHLa7d8hRbljl56QT8dZRNgnS5pJBmM5bO2yQTrG2k4kOcWYzDJwHA6KN1zWudo/vyfbDwMcyQygiIKKUmoCyZhgP5yAWLEpyxsLOaSfXsBP0Ke8FwnHjMKNN0S6UL5FA4WyNbi9ehZmY5pxoylFYp@YhECwP6ZU/K@79r6t/B/raruADjELB7t3K0bY3G0rrWoa11JAedhrJ8aBNISMNnaWL0v1W/E/DH4DVmOOwyblC0lptiRgYHBpoD@TDMnbmr4WgSFcsoDjX79G/EOq5WA04YRvMFiFFvrOoW@QqitypB2UK7rK2Bt8kEC6fGSPBqAwrck9q7IE0A@IrWfERB7/pZhpMMAvLKHuai5oqeHvnM1m4xuVaFlWWZpRyotNrSvh5KLBkNtqHBeqQCo4piiPGeKxueAP4V9GqB0N8dBibD/V7iwOC5fiB0fm@BYETYHgnvPjwS2mpR87sNCCP0/3VEiFUGTD@4xsRh1DWD16q0WctaU4kjRSlTkmMa1gINtSlLhS/koDS7uvRuplgfkGamaAWwqA8gjguC/hYKYonruXyplGYYAHlFH6G0zE/m1O23DTkLDNRzigB8tktUonFhcrPikc246mlVWntjScdr0NKc@VOXA21LTaZ94uZNMmSM45slKWJVA3AZIEd4OETrf6WcZYC@IoNxgMtldB1MRlKLULKtEj4gYRSARjt3sYMuUFdJKe/Ixv198vLs3v3vyenzhy/unZ2cPnvZMnaSAyBJDKBe3Cf30yQA6yfwW6wLpCEAugqKvH26pV3msrL1fW18tSysvJyal@XIKuWMEXTyx3a0cjood5mSQ@J7VbHWUqx7ssuVEsXbJbrS/@uQ4wbIpe6x6ep728nENZFuS5Fe0oyy65ipDt5vBI/jR749UyEKvVL2rcxicHwmcTxPs0J/Ffal7n@W3R9g2gps3LhgUEttGaZquNdqVIZooDuXdB9DFOVj0myngQs2@QsVzthmQrrO6HHOSO35yu5X87RJ6z@N5GNJ/glN5mJR2j@r@ANuidiaqu2WnW0yvVlWHtnpN3B9YnEl6awiVI2zbZ0SHSbpvJBzR1kn@T5OoZst1jUzT9HRypUlbi8sbk122MlTs9lli7akj9VGa0tsF4THDeP/oEL0ws8@OouWwg9Ddmo2oyGbP4kEBH/MW2XWMCk6vf7xF19@9fUfv/mTPw1gPlGSrJZTynizMLjnCqPbpP91k67PHTUzQAXkB8KmYtaFt7fXwSVGqa775czUxOqlUtvZi5Nnj1ulSpWbSrVhHa3XDTB6C98RMg5UnRSgkvioj7vUVnLWkzvQy3V8j23EYumLKGjVkR6qaSUMf6V9NUK5Oxf7y2noY@0CMb8@3Hg4M/pNeuooPa2mAk1yYxA6OyBMdITM7XivElzlBAeks/ZK4dhA80DSfLqKRZTFmxsT62CHWEdqkoreROHHF0BytevPaBi9qe6x5jldO9z66GhTeqlz@A@UpYiCR2mic7ke0dshp2a6XbxbSsNpuIrTXy3eMg2vFO/WJ5YOeG6X7vzcWA@6fQrrXUNCu9cHitq@ji1tgU1mup8uM59FPE0aMtNQ6uDhTys/jsSNBVGnf@Cuh8ONt90ad3RlwTkRCz@5USR3dgG5q@s2CqmK3TyWuxYWY7HvInERcUqOyJN0DuVvTE5l9Q5OwRts@ItKrqdn18qsv1ydWT9X09WzBzeWVD/fkVR/ltxPX9wY8593MP9RMv/HDXL/cVOz96lYUNZgWKFiIhIipuTsphBhQbc@6PcODnaFxZnE8l00J9dzM6SKNNfele6W2WI@v1kxj3dL@TyX8vm1pTxuErJIvolgaUwexelFg4W7kt9f/FhUa0t9blbqfSl7PzLna49TkZaq6@1FrzypG/XGTRVsjc1GKUHvmW7n07Q7/0GM3kpGZxdp58LfkPkWNvVzl@vSH6nCF4jkSsvHvVpuW4FnuMVQ3oa3rf4KMAwzMSBZdzLhVODVrMnEhfnZxS3AzitrAxfc4pXZECykysR1BRgXAuTmuHEJDn@FBMbtn7M0oOGKUU4@J0/9gKVNE5ertoRM3/IaDtgHVy3jCly4wTnKd8itUByr/c1AreGupfWlhGUzLiNb@p8KmItH7kBOgfOuhW5PbWbAU664I6nhguUWt5CFKEIvYZrZdypUFfo93ejiMzAgIVMVhJa1W2zlE4SgfoIgD3xw625kGcHQwqRhkyq2jlBidSUINyWXlS2qkaUyvm2vrr6hyc3ZQkF3175sbe/mSpYYl73KDbtM3nsqM8J@uH8P@spw00JDXaqbE3rHCY3lgcWXMopIqvZxSZpAbWp2s0zYnZw2RNm3Ospgrsq571fmsQzfusGC6StE6@LEpLfu93vwo@8POec9R526Ok5l1iuokzOANktjmPTw@M8PFhF9Q7lC7C8p5Ho/bmvNTCn2mfkc6m3r8FQicpzuqzRKro2sONxq2tPzcuAW1BMSLcFXcYqhISCMuPqAKakN2AJ/BbQlGoRJQRYgH@KSH9ZMFp3A7HgR4b8GWX9aQV4lcZpAYpiuhEXiDcW9IqkYAXYMKJ43L1fBwqKm1NEFdAdBuorDgwIl4SlokOPV3XQGpGcztU4ReOdUsUFBUosaF2EKEFg0XwiQCZSEl80yaEqZNArmL@YvUT1cwT2BKSNxBOoieY19LHJ0NkPuqCT4C/oQUu9ICCSEmdyHWAPsM7JJV6BIwCxS8GRKYzJjlJbBFYIBHRjA8KroZ3U/3i/8GHcoW9Y58huMROXMXB6EudzbFfjKX1yHHBKHGBcDMuVtPw9fe07FJWU/26vKTlWC/FcJ@QQ1XeR2CHiIyTau6EvJRYf6NTclwXxdc@G6cVP5p4J3SV0fx1@zi9ymqjmyWN237ynU9nM1GbffuBA4qdDhjeXLenA91UDCGFczlEmUTyPetE/7QO0I0elq/pu6lznOmEF@HOrr5pSxK64L6KNmkHyWQJLVsy9Tt/TlTBThqQ0oTXVo4zkMzIJc8hmULmZji3173tyyB9lZcfI8Qb4ufhuhcvyME2DpCBpv0aQJtU@i86YQ9a3u82jMxaV0RTvDq5Uwq6SgJEifmE8WmMEgRUID5lx5xBYwn8u8CpPjJWUp3srHgyqZ6rg5GFUXgfIrPvm9oLF1csqL9/JpSN6@U8o/efboVJaUKCV0luCVxbWLHEza5OBgMhlIAsUo1zkXEHZQSekPXTVUO8gqktGMScWq0w9VIOYngs5//vVvp5x3dJUB5Xm5zlAFu6wygJqmbpcWeU8FoYJLq0RKOZBfFenymNLM7fb61aEfiV46E37LRSOE6XGacmoueNW9Y19@kwXFMt9q6d5j8xVOIc/lG3OvRnfs@mE48XUPd6/zZq9N9jodzQceFjTOhnv5sxpLGn5gfo/SZLjHBcygEwFl6563i1OoOEkRcj40wTtJ2nGWIPKn4@hg2DqakSOLMPQKvGkF@pXFh/qykIwrx6gJxqOLa4ryD9LkRo/gAFo5tfqs0@lA4iT3Tx88JJBC4dGxlzFcntaH4DSw2IDu54n1Or/0Dv0qhbEiDg4FOZKOBl8eV0pvCnTp6MvjQXkxoYIglnf0Gy6xKaoE3O9cELKN9hb6JYFfPHz5tydnJYFL6dC4rfwELUr3Zo7jvH8PH3q59/6r1n8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Binary Pi Calculus](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Binary_pi-calculus), 6 bytes

```
0x73 0xB8 0x1B 0xDB 0xB0 0x00
```

Unfortunately, I could find no existing BPC interpreter. If one does exist, please let me know.

#### Explanation

```
0x73     0xB8     0x1B     0xDB     0xB0     0x00
01110011 10111000 00011011 11011011 10110000 00000000
01110011101110000001101111011011101100000 0000000
011                                       Run the following two processes in parallel
   100    1110                            Write the free variable 0...
      1110                                ...to the free channel 0
              000                         End first process
                 001                      Run the following on an infinite number of threads:
                    1011110               Read from the free channel 0 to the bound variable 0
                           110    1100    Write the bound variable 0...
                              1110        ...to the free channel 0
                                      000 End second process
```

The corresponding pi-calculus program is

```
a<a>|!a(a).a<a>
```

Reads and writes are blocking, so each thread will be executed sequentially.  As there are an infinite number of them, the program will therefore never halt.

Answer (score 1):

## [Exceptionally](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Exceptionally), 1 byte

```
=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m702tSI5taAkMz8vMSencsGCpaUlaboWC20hNJQLEwYA)

All programs in Exceptionally run as infinite loops. (Unfortunately, the empty program exits immediately instead of looping.) All we need is a no-op to execute each time.

Here, we're using `=`, which (given no arguments) asserts that the register is equal to itself. In fact, any of the characters `+-*^=IF{}!` should work. Several others (`&UDSW`) would also work, except that they will eventually run out of memory and print something to stderr.

Answer (score 1):

## [makina](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/makina), 2 bytes

```
><
```

That's it, that's the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 0.823 bytes

```
(
```

Beats all y'alls' one-byters mwahahaha

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 3 bytes

```
[]0
```

[Try it Online!](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%5B%5D0&inputs=)

Answer (score 1):

## [TacO](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO), 2 bytes

```
@"
```

TacO sees the source code as an infinite plane. When it encounters a `"`, it searches forever for the matching quote, idling forever. `@` is required as a program root.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0lMzv//30Hp/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 9 bytes

```arturo
whileø[]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?oJ9qHD)

This also works and is the same length:

```
f:$[][f]f
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), 1 byte

Actually \$ 1 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ **0.82 bytes** but the leaderboard doesn't take decimals.

```
[
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYLoyE0lAsTBgA)

Just a simple infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 12 bytes

```swift
while true{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/PCMzJ1WhpKg0tbr2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/in-parens-comma/) 8 Chars or 1.585 Bytes

```
(,,,,())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language) Assembly, 0 Bytes

It's an infinite loop no matter what (at least until I implement a halt instruction (which I might not even do))

Answer (score 0):

## C++ Template Meta-Programming, 48 bytes

```cpp
template<int n>class S{enum{v=S<n-1>::v}}S<1>::v
```

There is an infinite loop in the template, so this doesn't compile. Other stuff that doesn't compile, but doesn't need to for the template to recurse (S being private, S<1>::v being free floating)

Can be run at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/
for error `g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault`

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -ftemplate-depth=162345 main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Comment: Not sure if that is compliant with the rules as it doesn't run out of memory when it stops. If you want to do that, there is the `-ftemplate-depth` compiler option in gcc that allows you to set the recursion depth to something very high so you'll at least get a segfault out of it.

Comment: @iFreilicht  Yeah, I suppose you're right. I couldn't (be bothered to...) find a online complier that supported that.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com

Answer (score 0):

## [HPPPL](http://www.hp-prime.de/en/category/6-downloads), 16 bytes

```
while 0=0 do end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Univar](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Univar), 8 bytes

```
($,,)$,,
```

Self-calling function.

Comment: Seems too recursive to me... is there any tail-call optimization?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Not at my computer right now, but I believe that the interpreter internally uses a variable-length list for the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

## x86 Machine code, 2 bytes

**Machine Code**

```
     00 01
0000 73 FE
```

**Asm source**

```
[SECTION .text]
[bits 16]
[org 0x100]

EntryPoint:
    jnc     EntryPoint
```

Both the `jmp` and the `call` instructions use a 1 byte op-code followed by a 2 byte absolute offset. Conditional jumps on the other hand, are limited to a destination within [+127, -128] bytes of the branch. This is because they are encoded with a 1 byte op-code and a 1 byte relative offset. Dos already cleared the flags before invoking our program, so we know the carry flag will be clear and facilitate an endless (non-crashing) loop. We wont run out of stack-space, which would result in a stack-overflow error, or overwriting and ultimately crashing, our program. Approaches using `call` will suffer this after about 32,638 iterations. (stack is initally 0xFFFE, (3 byte) program begins at 0x100, each iteration decrements the SP by 2.)

Answer (score 0):

### [ROOP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ROOP), 1 byte

```
1
```

At the beginning, the number 1 is converted to an object that contains the number. As there is no operator and the object has nowhere to move, it always happens the same: nothing. The program does not end because there is an existing object.

Comment: An explanation would make this a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befalse](http://quirkster.com/iano/js/befalse.html), 7 bytes

A two dimensional language.

Extremely straightforward; the `!` unconditionally skips the next instruction and the `/` and `\` reflect intuitively.

```
!/\
 \/
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Etre](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Etre), 2 bytes

```
()
```

The program sets the first cell to 1, then loops while it isn't zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [Skull](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Skull), 8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

Uses a bug in the Skull2C transpiler, where unrecognized expressions are converted directly into C.

Answer (score 0):

## [KimL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KimL), 14 bytes

```
A:
ctrl.goto A
```

For whatever reason, labels must come before the lines that they label.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 7 bytes

```
loop {}
```

but...

```
> loop{}
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <unknown file>
Whitespace required after keyword 'loop'
at <unknown file>:1
------> loop⏏{;}
```

k.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 9 bytes

```
while(){}
```

boooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooring.

Answer (score 0):

## Postscript, 6 bytes

```
{}loop
```

Infinite loop that does nothing. Ties up 1 core at 100% when run under ghostscript. Interestingly, the ghostscript interpreter keeps accepting input, so it must be running a separate thread. Not sure what would happen if this was sent to a printer, though.

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle PL/SQL 11.2, 30 bytes

```
BEGIN LOOP NULL;END LOOP;END;/
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Magic](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Magic), 7 bytes

```
skip -1
```

A simple self-GOTO.

Answer (score 0):

## NTFJ, 2 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/NTFJ/)

```
~^
```

This is stiflingly simple. `~` pushes a `0` to the stack, and `^` pops N and goes that position in the source code. The simplest unconditional loop in NTFJ is this.

Answer (score 0):

### GNU Make, 16 bytes

```
f=$(call f)
$(f)
```

The loop is in make itself, not a program it invokes.

Answer (score 0):

## [ForceLang](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang), 9 bytes

Works by abusing the new `def` instruction.

```
def a a
a
```

Original 14-byte answer:

```
label l
goto l
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pylons, 4 bytes.

```
w,1}
```

Loops while 1 is true.

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way 1.6.5](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 3 bytes

```
&{}
```

[See the docs.](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathcad, 4 "bytes"

[image]

In Mathcad the user enters programming language commands using keyboard shortcuts (or picking them from the Programming Toolbar) rather than writing them in text.  For example, typing ctl-] creates a while-loop operator that has two "placeholders" for entering the condition and a single line of the body, respectively.   Typing = at the end of a Mathcad expressions causes Mathcad to evaluate the expression.

So to enter the above while loop, the user enters "ctl-]11=".  Mathcad will then eternally evaluate 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Come Here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Come_Here), 11 bytes

```
1COME FROM1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [WhoScript](http://www.esolangs.org/wiki/WhoScript), 4 bytes

`1v;d`

The `1` tells the interpreter to use one-line mode, `v` starts an infinite loop, and `d` loops back to the `v`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy), <s>8 bytes</s> 6 bytes

```js
{1} do
```

Explanation:

`{1}` is a block (procedure) that pushes 1 to the stack (truthy). `do` will continue to execute that block until it pushes something falsy to the stack, which will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

## [tinyBF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/TinyBF), 5 bytes

```
+|= |
```

Similar to `+[]` in BF. The space is required here, as `|=|` (meaning `[]`) is converted to `,`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Braille](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Braille), 6 bytes

```
⠁⡀
```

Self-GOTO with a NOP. If it isn't displayed properly (and/or you want to test it):

```
0000000: e2a0 81e2 a180                           ......
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Grocery List](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Grocery_List), 6 bytes

```
W
L
E
```

Note the preceding newline. `W` pushes 100 to the stack, and `L` and `E` loop while the top of stack isn't 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dumbfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Dumbf*ck), 2 bytes

```
.?
```

`.` sets the current cell to 1, and `?` jumps to itself (due to the cell being an odd number).

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 1 byte

```
r
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=r)

The `r` node sets the counter to 0, resetting the program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tellurium](http://m654z.github.io/Tellurium), 5 bytes

```
[i|p]
```

This is pretty simple to explain.
 It runs the command `p` (Does nothing, which is why it's good for this challenge) forever (`i` = infinity).

Answer (score 0):

## [Glypho](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Glypho), 3 bytes

```
1[]
```

Pushes 1 to the stack, then loops while the top of the stack isn't 0. Uses the Java interpreter. This is shorthand for the following "real" Glypho program:

```
  !" ! " !"!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Churro](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Churro), 20 bytes

```
{o}=}{==={*}{===={*}
```

Consists of three churros. `{o}=}` pushes 1 to the stack, and `{==={*}` and `{===={*}` loop while the top of stack is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [niblet](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Niblet), 2 bytes

```
 [
```

The space is just a no-op, and the `[` moves the IP to the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

## [0815](https://esolangs.org/wiki/0815), 7 bytes

```
}: :#:
```

(trailing space)

```
}:0:#:0
```

Explained:

```
}:0:    :Create a label 0
    #:0 :Go to the label 0 if Z is 0h
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Trigger](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Trigger), 5 bytes

```
 !  !
```

Generally, any program with an `"ABAAB"` pattern should work.   toggles the `' '` trigger to 1, `!` toggles the `'!'` trigger, and   `!` jumps to the nearest `!` if the `' '` trigger is 1 (which it is).

Answer (score 0):

## [Benul](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Benul), 0 bytes

In Benul, programs are placed in an implicit infinite loop and require special conditions to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

## [AlphaBeta](http://esolangs.org/wiki/AlphaBeta), 2 bytes

```
 N
```

is a no-op, and `N` moves the IP to the value stored in the position register (initially 0) if the third register is 0 (which it is).

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 50 bytes

```
interface D{static void main(String[]a){for(;;);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Copy](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/copy), 10 bytes

```
copy 0 0 1
```

Copy the current instruction at the next location.

Basically a Core war imp.

Answer (score 0):

## [LI](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/LI/blob/master/Interpreter.py), 2 bytes

```
R0
```

Usually, LI programs (under the current interpreter) always take in input.   No input is commonly represented as falsy input, i.e. 0; however, in order to truly accept "no" input, I need to provide my own input to the `R`ecurse function.

Explanation:

```
R   Recurse with input:
 0  Literal 0
```

LI, 1 byte

If we're a bit more lax with the input requirements, simply `R` will work.  It doesn't error if you don't give it an input, but that's simply because, while it interprets the input as invalid (empty), it doesn't try to use its value.

Answer (score 0):

## [ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 2 bytes

```
5x
```

Explanation:  `5` loops while the front member of queue `B` resolves to a truthy value.  The default value for queue `B` is `1`, so the loop continues until it finds its matching `x`; since there are no operations in the loop, it continues ad infinitum with no output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lolo](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/lolo), 20 bytes

```
lOLolo loLOlo loloLO
```

You can also put in `l` at the end, but it won't ever get called.

Answer (score 0):

## [Sinclair ZX-81 Basic](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/ZX81BasicProgramming/), 6 bytes

```
1 RUN
```

This would take 6 bytes in RAM (2 bytes for the line number, 2 bytes for the line length, 1 byte for the `RUN` token and 1 byte for a newline).

The way it works is (essentially) the same as the `10 GOTO 10`, the first line in the program causes the program to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

## [dotsplit](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/dotsplit), 4 bytes

```
jump
```

`jump`: pops number from stack, moves back that many commands

When the stack is empty, popping results in zero. Hence, it will jump on to the jump command.

In keeping with design principles, the problems this has will not be addressed, but perhaps a new command will be added, called `loop-safe` or something

Answer (score 0):

## CMD, 2 bytes

Must be in a file named a.bat or a.cmd

```
@a
```

Must be in a bat or cmd file

```
@%0
```

Comment: The first answer counts as 3 bytes: 2 for the code, and 1 for the restriction on the filename

Comment: Why? He's being punished for a restriction imposed on him by the system, which only recognises specific suffices as executable code. This seems extremely unfair, because it's completely out of his control. 


He would not be punished if he used a simple batchfile-editor which would execute the code for him, and thus this punishment is undeserved.

Answer (score 0):

## Visity, 0 bytes

```
(no code)
```

As [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69990/56341) answer points out Visity wraps around producing an infinite loop.

Or more conventional (2 bytes):

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Unary, 695 bytes

695 zeros. Program that prints the actual code can be found [here](http://ideone.com/B64O9u).

Answer (score 0):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 3 bits, represented as 1 byte on disk (language postdates challenge)

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/7#@2/4/z8A)

This is fairly simple. The program starts by pushing `7` onto the stack (which is what `1` does); then when the end of the program is reached, the top nonempty stack element is executed, without removing it from the stack (although any empty elements above it *are* removed). `7` just pushes an empty stack element to the stack, which immediately gets removed as it's the end of the program, and so nothing has changed and the same stack element just gets run again, repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 5 bytes

```
EXEC.
```

`.` is the same as `0.0`, so it runs `EXEC 0`, which executes the program stored in slot 0, which is the default slot.

Example use:

```
PRINT TIME$
WAIT 1
EXEC.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pari/GP , 9 Bytes

```
while(1,)
```

*(dummy text such that SE accepts the answer)*

Answer (score 0):

### [PKod](https://github.com/PKTINOS/PKod) - 1 byte

*Version 1.1 was released very recently as I still update this, which implements this new function/command*

```
<
Explanation: Jumps back to first byte in code. So it jumps back to itself. Normally meant to be used with test cases (e.g.: if prime, jump back to start - iterate all code again, but since thread asks for infinite loop, why not)
```

Alternative version, 4 bytes:

```
-+ia
Explanation: -+ , remove then add 1 to value. Thus value keeps jumping from 0 and 1. "i" jumps two blocks back in code until value is next char after "i". Thus until char is 1. Thus until value reaches ascii code of a which is 97. Which never happens
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 5 bytes

```
*S
```

+3 for `-w` on the command line, which allows the program to run without reading from stdin. Instead, it uses an internal source (generating `0x00` repeatedly by default).

---

`*` is a constant high signal; this turns on adjacent elements.
`S` when powered, suppresses output for the current cycle.

Comment: I believe the first flag (`-w`) is considered 3 bytes (but the following flags will be considered 1 byte each)

Comment: You are right! I wasn't certain to start with, and your comment forced me to do research on the accepted norms.

Comment: Do you need the `-w` flag? The [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7172/61384) is that you can assume STDIN is empty.

Comment: @Challenger5 The problem here is that, by default, Chip terminates when it has processed all of stdin. Empty stdin means that Chip will terminate immediately.

Answer (score 0):

## [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable), 25 bytes

```
'"""""'"""'""""""'"""'"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X10JBNShGIn5/z8A)

### Explanation

```
'"""""                       While X is true, do Y
      '"""                   [X] - Return 1
          '""""""            [Y] - Set variable X to value Y
                 '"""           [X] - Return 1
                     '"""       [Y] - Return 1
```

Comment: Explanation? Also, you haven't formatted it correctly, it should be '"""""'"""'""""""'"""'""".

Answer (score 0):

## MOO, <s>30 28</s> 26 bytes

```
while(!suspend(0))endwhile
```

The `suspend(0)` is necessary to avoid "task ran out of ticks'

Comment: Do you need the spaces?

Comment: No. I don't. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//github.com/aaronryank/SimpleStack), 1 byte

```
(
```

Creates a jump point. When the interpreter hits EOF and there is an open jump point, it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nhohnhehr](https://github.com/catseye/Nhohnhehr), 11 bytes

```
+-+
|$|
+-+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vIz8jLSM0o@v9fW1ebq0alhgtI//8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 13 bytes

```
until(null;1)
```

this also works but is no shorter:

```
repeat(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Chip-8, 1 byte

```
0x12
```

Instructions in Chip-8 are 2 bytes, so `0x12` is interpreted as `0x1200` (assuming the unused parts of the program are filled with zeros)

Instruction `0x1...` jumps to the address stored in the lower 1.5 bytes, which is `0x200`, the start of program memory.

Answer (score 0):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 12 bytes

```
3.6147281494
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M/n/31jPzNDE3MjC0MTS5P9/AA) (Note: The interpreter used by TiO raises an error with this code. This is caused by the interpreter, not the program itself)

Explanation (According to the [wiki](http://esolangs.org/wiki/4) specifications):

```
3.         Start program
6 14 72    Set memory cell 14 to 72
8 14       While cell 14 != 0
9          End while
4          End program
```

Comment: Do you have an interpreter on which this program works?

Comment: @FlipTack I think [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aa4265242185f4bb41c9) should work, but I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

## [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 22 bytes

```
hodor............(1){}
```

[Hodor!](https://tio.run/##y8hPyS/6/z8DROkhAQ1Dzera//8B)

Or, (44 bytes)

```
hodor............(hodor. rhodor!? hodor? ){}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk-80, 8 bytes

(or more)

First there is no such thing as a program in Smalltalk-80, just write a snippet anywhere in a text pane and press the doIt! pop up menu. But we can eventually write snippets that don't stop.

```
[]repeat
```

is the obvious infinite loop

```
thisContext restart
```

is our kind of goto solution

```
|x|
x:=[:b|b value: b].
x value:x
```

is a block closure evaluating itself recursively, but since a closure close over local variables, we can do it shorter:

```
|b|(b:=[b value])value
```

Since Smalltalk-80 don't do recursive tail elimination, this infinite loop will starve memory and won't really be infinite.

We also may retry code that raised an exception, if ever the exception was temporary...

(a costly variant of repeat)

```
[0halt]on:Halt do:[:e|e retry]
```

We can also play with recursive structures, modulo recursive tail elimination problems:

```
|x|(x:=1->0)key:x;hash
```

We can also exploit weaknesses of the interpreter itself - this is in latest Squeak 6.x (you'll have to kill the image):

```
|c|c:=Class new.c superclass:c.c new
```

Since new will invoke `self basicNew initialize`, the interpreter will loop in #initialize method lookup. This time no memory growth, the loop is solid.

There must be some shorter exploit, but I'll stop here, Smalltalk is more talk than small for golfing...

In a certain sense, the interpreter performs an infinite loop itself, so doing nothing is already doing an infinite loop, but that's cheating.

In the case of Smalltalk though, since we save the state of the interpreter in an image, and later resume an image at each restart, we're just running the infinite loop for more than 20 years now (or one of its avatars). Since it's ran over a virtual machine, it even perpetuates across different machines, OS, architectures, so it's a quite robust loop!

Answer (score 0):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) [scripting language](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQS_syntax), 4 bytes

```
@0>1
```

`@` waits until the condition (`0>1`) is true, which obviously never happens, so it keeps looping and checking the condition forever.

**Alternative solution (10 bytes):**

```
#l
goto"l"
```

This usually freezes the game.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 10 bytes

```
s:signal s
```

Of course, the canonical way is a whopping 14 bytes:

```
do forever
end
```

Or, depending on implementation:

```
do forever
nop
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 21 bytes

```
Count i while i+1 {
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPbUKGaq/b/fwA)

In [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), looping is *costly*. Whitespace between brackets is required and the statement is a bit wordy. This is pretty self-explanatory, but just in case, it increments `i` until `i - (i + 1) = 0`, which is never.

Comment: This is super late, but `Count i while 1` works for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
1`ł
```

Explanation:

```
1             Pushes 1 onto the stack
 `ł           Loops while the top of the stack is not zero
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fMOFo0///AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Forked](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Forked), 0 bytes

Same as the top two answers. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svyk5N@Q8EAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/g8EAA)

Another 0 byte 2D entry. In Wumpus, <s>the first cell is implicitly created,</s> the pointer is always out of bounds, so it reflects forever.

Comment: I'd have to double check the code, but I think the first cell isn't actually created. Instead the grid has dimensions 0x1 so that the IP is always out of bounds (and then still bounces around the edges of its current OOB cell forever).

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 4 bytes

```
j0j1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P8/yyDL8P9/AA)

### Explanation

```
j  0  #  label j0: jump past label j0 (no-op)
j  1  #  label j1: jump past label j0 (re-execute this instruction)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 [byte](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
W
```

[Try it online!](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#c=W&i=&a=1)

Just an unconditional loop without body.

Answer (score 0):

## [axo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Axo), 1 byte

```
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S6zI//8//v9/AA)

```
_  goes to the command at 0,0, which happens to be _
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 7,  8 bytes

```
for(;;);
```

This is the shortest I could think of, it's one shorter then

```
while(1);
//and
a:goto a;
```

Try it [online](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bo)

it's 5 more if you count the `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 7 bytes

```
1Goto1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/f0D2/JN/Q6v9/AA) Version that produces output may be seen [Here](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/f0N6Qy8g9vyTfkOv/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 7 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window that takes no input and loops forever

```vb
Do:Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 7 bytes

Anonymous Function that takes no input and loops forever.

```vb
Do:Loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3yXfyic/v@D/fwA) A version that infinitely outputs `1` may be seen [here.](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3yXfyt7Qyic/v@D/fwA)

Comment: You might as well combine this answer with your VBA answer, given that they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 12 bytes

Anonymous `While` loop that loops forever.

```vb
While 1
Wend
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z88IzMnVcGQKzw1L@X/fwA) A version that prints `1` infinitely may be seen [here.](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z88IzMnVcGQK6AoM68ESIen5qX8/w8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Visual Basic .NET (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 44 bytes

Declare `Sub`routine that takes no input and loops forever.

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Do
Loop
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0vSTc4vSv3/3zc/pTQnVcGXK7g0ScE3MTOPyyWfyyc/v4DLNS9FASgIpiGq/v8HAA) A version that outputs `1` infinitely may be seen [here.](https://tio.run/##K0vSTc4vSv3/3zc/pTQnVcGXK7g0ScE3MTOPyyWfyzk/rzg/J1UvvCizJNUnMy9Vw1CTyyc/v4DLNS9FAagSTEO0/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pain-Flak](https://github.com/Cis112233/Pain-Flak), 8 bytes

```
))((})({
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0jMzNNNy0nM/v9fU1NDo1ZTo/r/fwA)

## Explanation:

```
))(( pushes 1 on stack
})({ the }...{ loops until TOS = 0 and the )( makes it run as a loop because without the )( the }...{ would eval as }{ and not loop
The code is flipped and added to the end during Pain-Flak interpreting and the code does a infinite loop again.
```

Comment: Note I found the Brain-Flak answer after I wrote this. This was not just a cheap port :P

Answer (score 0):

*So I suppose I can create a new language and develop its intepreter for this answer, can't I?*

> Feel free to use a language (or language version) even if it's newer than this challenge. -Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed (and even encouraged) to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language. **:D**

## Ghrvy...!, 3 bytes

```
grv
```

[Intepreter written in Python 3](https://tio.run/##zVh/b9vIEf1fn2KswyHkRVIlWXJcwjLQBhc3h@Ia1Lk7FKogr6iVtA21JHZJybqin92d2V2KFMn4HMf94QSiRO6@eTP7ZmaXySHdxPL8QWyTWKWgD7oDisllvO1AFK/XQq5brQ2PEphAu91ufQPdr/9DlM/93WzU7tDr9c7gvUx5onjK1YsZLcC9RMUyzmTIl8A03Kg43h18EBoYLBQTcpWFn7qR@MRhK6TYskjoVISIgRPXim0hYnKdsTWHJd/xKE64gsUBPnx4e9O7/T7INFdvBuPRRe/FyH/c8MJoLKMDoBENbyCNP3GpA7hb33XgbkMfij529HGgjx59nN11EEUnLMRZ3h3c@YDrDJLvIyG5fjmi7@WSy5SlIpYahFyKkKUc4xrGSw6LKA4/dWC/EeGGwm11x2QKbIVLDSl6iRiKJ5yl1jVy52XDqNNYURRpuSVkUou1RCFcdhcCeSjFDhCvIOJynW5g0OmPLjvjNxc9@GOMv0kDsZBEluK3Y1GGImFSJFnknGZRFO9hr1iSYP6gF8YtnIxzuFy@nDO3Bwz0fUD5hKsfALthKgPoYthDxZnmxnBO93eOrJAQZkrhIkHIo4h0O@jVc/IPqxUPU20g7EQcuOQrlkVpw3DvB5YwFBKHVazg1Tom17PklW/YbZDdnziRQ3ZL/r9mt@BhvCWCEdfaUVRI8a9Wd92jABFd8vu0JF7w7GUvUAzCaB3q9tbooNUzKoxQ3EjUFf2ilMMk4MrGAG03YFj1o0hjiaVpBYq@m9lME6PtlgToEDXb8gYMMtQBdJlH6HvJK8W3WOYoBMa1WP42CvKVpXhXFwrJyVh2f@UqNguABSiAn81QDKjGeGHK0/SUqTW3oTCli7RrcglVAgue7rm1U@dRTryCiPPIPbS2D2j7b5yD0dstTx/hjenJXM8DmW0XiC9kw2pQ0LD@cpj2OwWUVQfizCjpokyLHbcUekjhvUyylCjcIAVsLQeshCuFhqhB4AR6Ss7oCsO6@SplFFZq8HpwmyVURDX89PFd99IaP0Pjf8lSwu/mX5rdZzonhk8sQoMCqGzmrW8vcNqeYa2kXGKEK5Z2asNMRV1c5x2BqMeGjuF5a9qR7UZd@DGGLWdGlEZruRac1CkR0JwVIwsxcrpuThTdx4I4dSw47mUMNOrOghgGP7r@55SSRKKc7LgbkkdSL1e3P@B@Y0VEPmaKKL2Nt0mEWx3koU01L3YqhkvIKBiQov50IiLsVRjG4z7FjjHNSISoIa40M75Nj0Nm8Bom1zA94s5gDd4veUK75KR@6GTiV@dfP3m@y8MaQreKsPkyBldPnv85Bp0qQi1KveqIs@qIaXWEqo6YVUd4ucY6dt9GWaNx2SPXBx7ZDhc5hHVbUx0/FmHXUNBj6mE46Ldhjs1IYwlOSXgWpOe/kLLxhPCAPRiotXhY5Xd@0IJ1FC9YBHSIaKGED3jLKnYCNGQ6mOENd9bocaVi5bXf0nO7AQvgn/1/mQKl2z0M3ZalHj7xCML3fZyLrdHi0RGF0NFHFe/xC1Wsua2yE5iSHWffrAG1b1uDPd/cBIHDYrX0Nr79ucI71xO4GI/PL@yIMuRrxByO@phaHg67hsGl34HB8LK4MfThW7gYnd69OL0pzK@ZQedRbnKIm87PWByOygaegY3PmqEHvx@WkJpBNG@eK2gAvw95kpoBCdO6hV9MLqPyd/MkVR0I7UW4i5EfnjR3Uce1hflipY7fcZ07dEKZu5pv9nxzl944fS1jxefH9oA0@jP4DgYYPNywd6Bf@j@dmcugAx9VhmDvGPriLsgTTySYj4YeVpqjwIwv@VZrYnQ2NYNMPIzy3LMJ7nlf2djkjHFCDm/GyjitcnbBxIenzgU2YIjg2S@vYUBr61yzs8xquAhPzbCZmXByw00cjs0ko4Iy581/kHP3uZy7j3NWz@acOoJhHlN3m2@TeaEz8zPXZn57ztLcjhFS1821wkmrwjH92MgltT4ZUhLaa9MYztqOUV698mHk39/lq@ALOFk9IyUD4WAtIczMQWHnBLJGkCxDbth1l2I@TbfBm5ScxCrq1VHLCFcTl@V@7nCCW57Ua39PlT7APV@6cYdk2@XO2n7ugqvidADZRabKTF39eCw49jqbHXlXxDaBftBQOiiKjWrbYUyeKbfT/MB5NPT0ZqPJw/NNVjPLHmx6dKGw50cXPW2sKzO/kU/v2QlXpVN0jamw96grlZKnGODbM2vfreOJnmsMz76mjFGfQ52ecr0CbIe5Zot@BN0ipYqORfuG4sd32C8xsKd41ESLVCwBGkG2oJwc4UZ5BR52Ym66T/uYGqem@6XSWjNBQ86M5gts2tCcN8A2OWQo5ibq6XRlthMl7JPHDTbM0p1i0H5nVMTghEW1MeDAyjhL8Pxx@OHoifDDUSP88FH4klIeh8eBjfBFkaU92NWJmkiII6q0w9G49ghb5Gld/YrlrSWV6UNFlXUV/dhwGufgP/da2cwKoNxJGvZMaMNMwApvHYniOJlb5pS0eH/aHczsKcHMLu48oakfOff/C926aiyPzlN7bK1p5z0776VH34ezoByovHeZ8OS3zTJ8tuyFLmg5Yj/vl7kP@YPz2s4/PGVZshkU3doCBN1BjltruMf6XECXkHOpmDvXk8pSHdXyaGn/Uh@rxFv2zafJofoZ9Z1QOsXGiecxepGmA5NndLAUJB3zrtCjx3bnY05f38L50O1AcuT@fRs1u@H3nvCnw2DWU//IdOqNO/io7eOjdgBk3U7A2NBQV1fErDxlWEyxM05Mng@CigcE6Nf9@jN7ilujN@MxGnT7hv93F3E3VZxNbaGk9xF@q4UA87lkWz6fmxcI8zm9vJjPkZJ5i6EPumfeZDw8PKzV7t8)

**Explanation first (Syntax and functions please see below)**

```
g            # Add 1 to the 1st cell
 r           # Loop when 1st cell != 0
  v          # Switch between cell manipulation and pointer manipulation
             # Implicit end of loop. Since 1st cell is still 1, voilà, infinite loop.
```

Ghrvy...! is a new programming language developed just after I finished golfing my answer in the challenge [Non discriminating programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156967/non-discriminating-programming/) that I at first typed a lot of `ghrvy`s in the code to meet the requirements. Since it is inspired by brainfuck, it is also the type of cell-pointer esolang. All programs in brainfuck can be transpiled to this language.

Syntax:

```
`g`: aGaru  - increase the pointer / value in current cell by 1.
              Affects the value by default.
              (Japanese for 'going up')
`h`: Heru   - decrease the pointer / value in current cell by 1.
              Affects the value by default.
              (Japanese for 'becoming less')
`r`: Repeat - repeat the next code block (block with indent 
              greater than the indent of the line where the `r` 
              token is on) if r is the last command of the same 
              line, or else repeat the remaining code on the same 
              line, when the value in current cell is non-zero.
`v`: Value  - switch the target of tokens `g` and `h` between the
              pointer and the value at the pointer.
`y`: Yee    - Set the value in current cell to a random number in
              the range [0, value in next cell] inclusive.
`.`: Input  - Get a byte from user input and set the value in
              current cell to that byte. Supports UTF-8.
`!`: Output - Output value in current cell as a byte in UTF-8. 
              The program will wait for a valid UTF-8 
              representation to output.
Spaces(` `) - No meaning when between commands on a line, act as
              indentation when at the beginning of a line.
Newlines    - Split code blocks, no meaning.
```

Since there must be something after the token `r` and token `v` does no pointer , cell and I/O manipulations, the program `grv` can be transpiled to brainfuck as `+[]`.

Messages in the STDERR generated are those generated by the intepreter. **No actual output is generated by the Ghrvy...! program itself.**

*Well, I came up the idea of the language first, and found this challenge may be a good place to show the features ;)*

Answer (score 0):

## [Sceql](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Sceql), 3 bytes

Make the current byte non-zero, then loop forever. I use [this implementation](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/sceql) to verify it.

```
-\/
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](http://python.org), 37 bytes

Hope I did this correctly

```
try:
    while 1:pass
except:pass
```

Try/Except will end program when memory runs out.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dreaderef](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/Dreaderef), 5 bytes

```
1 9-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SylKTUxJLUpN@//fUMFS1/D/fwA)

### Explanation

```
deref 9 -1 ; put value of cell 9 (initially 0) into cell -1, the instruction pointer
```

The `9` could have been replaced with any integer except `-1`, `0`, or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

### [Reflections](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/), 5 bytes

```
v\
\/
```

[Test it!](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##dlwKXC//Mf81MP8w/w==)

Explanation:

- `v` reflects the IP down
- `\` reflects the IP right
- `/` reflects the IP up
- `\` reflects the IP left
- `v` reflects the IP down into the loop again

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 byte

Assumes an unlimited call stack.

```
ß
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=3w==&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## [MachineCode](//github.com/aaronryank/MachineCode), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ebfe
```

This executes the machine code `EB FE` (`JMP -2`); `-2` (0xFE) is the length of the instruction.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y01MzsjMS03OT0n9/z81KQ1IAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tamsin](https://github.com/catseye/Tamsin), 10 bytes

```
main={''}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nMLc7M@/8/NzEzz7ZaXb1W7/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Idris](https://idris-lang.org), 19 bytes

```
main:IO()
main=main
```

Haskell solution + type signature.

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 7 bytes

```
-(i)->i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNTU9cu8////wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/), **6 bytes**

```crystal
loop{}
```

The `loop` keyword takes a block, which is here denoted by the curly brackets. I'm not sure I've seen any "real" (intended for use) Crystal code that uses `loop` instead of `while`, but I'd expect it to be used in the expanded form:

```crystal
loop do
  # do something here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Aheui, 0 byte.

Since Aheui is befunge-like, this is infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

## VTL-2, 7 bytes

```
2 #=1
```

`#` is the system variable in VTL-2 for line numbers, and it works to retrieve a line number *or* as a GOTO if given an assignment. So this is a trivial GOTO loop. The one interesting thing about it is that VTL-2 doesn't actually let you GOTO the current line number. It does GOTO the next largest line number when given a nonexistent line, however, so a one-line infinite loop will always work given that `y` is less than `x` for the program `x #=y`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Forget](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Forget), 37 bytes

```
const 0x0 1;cleanse 0x0;while 0x0;end
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S8svSk8t@f8/OT@vuETBoMJAwdA6OSc1Ma84FcSzLs/IzIGwUvNS/v8HAA)

Comment: What makes this non-competing? Languages created after the challenge are allowed.

Comment: @TheOnlyMrCat I guess things have changed

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 4 bytes

Yes, this is a very simple answer:

```
1a[]
```

Nothing short of outright hardware failure will stop this from running. Or, y'know, stopping the program.

Answer (score 0):

**GOLANG : 32 Bytes**

```
package main;func main(){main()}
```

One more solution :

```
package main;func main(){for{}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can eliminate two of the spaces. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8///78gMTk7MT1VITcxM886rTQvGczS0KyGULX//wMA "Go – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 2 bytes

```
1b
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/98w6f///wA)

#### Explanation

```
1  Starting from a(1)
 b Recurse all the way down (i.e. do a(n-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 bytes

```
G
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=G&i=P)

`G` goes to the beginning of the program...

Answer (score 0):

### [ABC (Esoteric)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ABC), 1 byte

```
l
```

Loops back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

### [And](https://esolangs.org/wiki/And), 0 bytes

No `&& exit`, therefore loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

### [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), 2 bytes

```
G0
```

Goes 0 lines below the current line.

Comment: A0A0 consumes the instructions it has executed. So once it has jumped to the same line, the instruction will be gone and the program will halt.

Answer (score 0):

### [Fastlane](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fastlane), 0 bytes

The pointer speed defaults to 1 and wraps around; there isn't a `$` instruction to halt the pointer in this program.

Answer (score 0):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 2 bytes

```
¤
```

Loops forever, takes arbitary input and has no output.

Answer (score 0):

## ///, 3 bytes

```
///
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19f//9/AA)

### Explanation

This replaces nothing with nothing. It runs forever because when it replaces nothing with nothing, it has to replace *that* nothing with *another* nothing, and it does this indefinitely.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59578/

Comment: ah, didn't see a /// submission, thx

Answer (score 0):

## QWOP, 2 bytes

```
OO
```

### Explanation

The command O `return[s] the pointer to the last O, if one exists.` So this will run indefinitely without producing output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kipple (cipple)](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/kipple), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
1>a(a
```

Pretty simple, just pushes 1 to stack A, and then begins a loop that only ends if stack A is empty

-1 byte, since the ending bracket isn't necessary in cipple for some reason

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84sKMhJ1U0GU///G9olaiT@/5@YlJwCAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 3 bytes

```
!{]
```

Negates top of stack & executes while.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S81JzU3NK/n/X7E69v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Whenever](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/whenever.html): 4 bytes

```
1 1;
```

Is actually an example from the specification. The instruction causes line 1 to put itself back on the to-do list.

Answer (score 0):

## [NULL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/NULL), 2 bytes

```
41
```

Code in the NULL language is a number.

The interpreter sets X = 41 and Y = 1. Afterwards, it divides X by its smallest prime factor (41) and multiplies Y by that, so then X = 1 and Y = 41.

Afterwards, it performs an action which corresponds to that prime factor. The action for `41` is to swap X and Y, so X = 41 and Y = 1.

The program ends when X = 1, which will never happen with this code.

Answer (score 0):

### [tq](https://github.com/A-ee/tq), 3 bytes

```
"")
```

### Explanation

```
"",  # Define an empty string
   ) # Extend the list forever
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 14 bytes

```
{while(1>0){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQk59fYKWgoamga6cQmpdZomD7v7o8IzMnVcPQzkCzurb2f1ppnkJuYmYeUE01lwIQgLRoaHLV/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
LN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/38fv/38A)

## Explanation

```
 N   The natural number list       . [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
L    Try to find the length of that. ???

     Weirdly, Husk isn't lazy in this case.
     So it will loop forever as the
     counter approaches positive infinity.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
<^:_[1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/3ybOKj7a8P9/AA)

### Explanation

```
<      # A monad
 ^:_   # Done infinity times
    [1 # To an argument
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NydHNKE0v/v8/NzEzzxZE/P8PAA), 9 bytes

```
main=main
```

Defines the main function (required to run) recurring on itself, resulting in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

```
-^:]_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/XzfOKjb@/38A)

```
-        Negate the given number
 ^:]     Repeat (right arg) times
    _    The right arg: infinity
         Repeat (infinity) times means to find the fixed point,
         but there is none since it alternates between _ (inf) and __ (-inf)
```

---

```
0&-~_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/30BNty7@/38A)

```
0&-~_    `~` gives the argument `_` to both sides of `0&-`
         so it is equivalent to `_ (0&-) _`
_ (0&-) _
  (0&-)      Negate the given number
_            If you give left arg to a `&`-function, it becomes repeat count
             so it acts exactly like `^:_` (find the fixed point)
        _    The initial value
```

This one works with any other single-digit integer in the place of 0.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 6 bytes

The `loop` construct produces an infinite loop. Thanks, [Yukihiro Matsumoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto).

```
loop{}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://github.com/python), 15 bytes

```python
def f():f()
f()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNQ9MKiLmA@P9/AA)

A function calling itself (till maximum recursion depth exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>17</s> 9 bytes

```
while 1
1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 5 bytes

```
Dx,+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9@lQkfb8P9/AA)

Very basic, this simply executes the following pseudocode:

```
x = 0
Do
  x = x + 1
While x > 0
```

For 1 extra byte, we can remove any possibility of running out of memory if `x` becomes too big:

```
Dx,x:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9@lQqfCyvD/fwA)

which simply sets `x` equal to 1 each time, rather than `x+1`

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), 3 bytes

```
[[{
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=W1t7&input=&flags=)

Takes advantage of Arn's pretty printing of matrices combined with an infinite, empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 6 bytes

```perl
{redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@6KDUlv/b/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org), <s>38</s> 18 bytes

```erl
l=&[&1.(&1)];l.(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/x1YtWs1QT0PNUDPWOkdPI0fz/38A)

```erl
l=&[&1.(&1)];l.(l)  # full program
 =          ;       # set...
l                   # variable...
 =          ;       # to...
  &[       ]        # function taking one argument that...
      .(  )         # calls...
    &1              # first argument...
      .(  )         # with argument...
        &1          # first argument
              .( )  # call...
             l      # variable...
              .( )  # with argument...
                l   # variable
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uselesslang](https://github.com/Fmbalbuena/Uselesslang), 0 bytes

Explanation:

```
<empty>
<EOF>   goto first char
```

Answer (score 0):

## Arm/Thumb/MIPS/SPARC/PowerPC assembly, 3 bytes

```
b 0
```

Which produces on my machine:

## AArch64 machine code, 4 bytes

```
0: 14000000  b 0
```

Or with `--target=armv7m-none-eabi` gives @EasyasPi's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219341).

Try compiling (not running) it online to several different machine languages [here](https://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?inst=b+0&arch=arm64&as_format=hex)!

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
⁽
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?code=%E2%81%BD&input=&flags=) (Note: it will probably crash your browser)

Answer (score 0):

### [ELVM IR](https://github.com/shinh/elvm), 5 bytes

```
jmp 0
```

Explanation: Jump to the first basic block unconditionally, in this case, it is the start of program.

Answer (score 0):

## YASEPL, 2 bytes

```
?1
```

goes back to the first instruction, which is itself